# The Bowlers-Golfers Fraction War

Tags: code-challenge, math, code-bowling, rational-numbers, cops-and-robbers

## Introduction

Let's start by arranging all fractions from 0 to 1 in order of lowest denominator, then lowest numerator:

1/2, 1/3, 2/3, 1/4, 3/4, 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1/6, 5/6, 1/7...

Note that duplicates aren't counted, so I haven't listed 2/4, 2/6, 3/6, or 4/6, since they already appeared in their simplified forms (1/2, 1/3, and 2/3).

Your task is now simple: given a positive integer `n`as a command line argument, print to standard output the `n`th fraction in the list. Thus, an input of `5` should yield an output of `3/4` (**not** 0.75).

## Bowlers

Your goal is to solve this in the longest program possible. Your score is the number of characters.

## Golfers

Your goal is to take existing answers, and golf them. When golfing those answers, remove one or more characters from the code, and optionally rearrange the remaining characters, in such a way that the resulting code is still a valid solution in the same language. Your score is the product of all the reductions. (So if you remove 10 characters from one answer, and 15 from another, your score is 150.)

## Rules

1. A valid program must have at least three unique characters.
2. Only ASCII characters may be used.
3. If your program's size is reduced, your score is reduced accordingly.
4. When golfing a program...

   1. Edit the code in the text of the answer
   2. Change the character count listed
   3. Leave the following comment: `**Removed X characters (from Y to Z)**` (in bold)
5. You may not golf a valid program into an invalid one.
6. The golfed program must work in some version of the language listed. So if the original answer is marked as Python, and the code only works in Python 2, you may golf it to a program that only works in Python 3.

   1. Therefore, it is recommended (but not required) that you be specific in titling your answer, mentioning the version and/or compiler used.
7. If you already golfed an answer, you may golf it again.
8. If you golf the same answer multiple times, your score for that answer is the *sum* of your reductions.

   1. For example, if you reduce 10 characters from a program, and later remove another 15, and also golf 7 characters from another answer, your total score is (10+15)*7=175.
   2. This applies regardless of whether someone else golfed the program in between your golfings.
9. You may golf your own answer, but you do not receive any points for doing so.

## Winners

I will try to keep this leaderboard periodically updated. If I make a mistake, please let me know, or else you can edit this post yourself.

### Top bowlers

1. Dennis (CJam): 1.17 × 10<sup>678</sup>
2. Pppery (CPython 3.6.2): 25984
3. OldCurmudgeon (Java): 278

### Top golfers

1. jimmy23013: 10<sup>5.2 * 10<sup>152</sup></sup>
2. Martin Ender: 2.8 * 10<sup>14484</sup>
3. Pppery: 2 * 10<sup>4111</sup>

Comment: What if 2 persons want to golf the same answer ?

Comment: @Optimizer Whoever does it first.

Comment: Did you address the problem Dennis found in the sandbox at all?

Comment: @MartinBüttner I don't see any feasible way of actually preventing it (disallowing string literals is insufficient). However, I don't think implementing his idea is trivial, so if he manages to do it, good for him.

Comment: Any thoughts on requiring people to provide compiled versions of their submissions for this one?

Comment: Why the extreme strictness on IO?

Answer (score 24):

## CJam, 1.17 × 10<sup>678</sup> bytes

```
",,,",KK#b:c~
```

Well, the string should actually contain 1,167,015,602,222,203,651,546,923,533,233,456,645,527,427,020,625,754,322,603,554,937,551,735,592,092,356,520,085,507,613,447,896,812,875,213,856,544,974,386,642,866,232,121,069,637,599,975,236,272,634,227,913,998,493,360,693,139,149,236,571,503,883,331,020,249,908,672,008,574,221,022,612,893,546,658,640,986,973,481,700,267,591,531,514,666,040,606,217,610,439,998,612,592,897,511,421,801,308,639,396,208,196,301,077,376,577,788,009,239,468,384,204,073,426,482,794,344,190,683,235,393,373,061,689,668,389,239,477,158,591,879,792,606,717,529,814,802,500,558,822,508,662,266,027,694,882,649,391,373,447,012,817,270,871,840,254,480,631,579,732,459,294,193,158,457,158,597,836,239,348,386,288,579,699,763,150,579,966,400,972,286,547,196,034,472,447,664,813,466,769,145,983,290,696,497,053,781,354,086,441,505,174,165,846,491,136,000,001,121,501,860,331,520,000,000,000,004,508,876,800,000,000,000,000,000,126 commas, but the editor didn't let me post the entire code... :(

Comment: Explain this unholy code-fu.

Comment: Forgot input didn't come from STDIN. That adds a couple of yottabytes...

Comment: @SohamChowdhury: Just a sec.

Comment: @Dennis don't spoil the fun! :D

Comment: On second thought, @MartinBüttner is right. This is cops-and-robbers, so I kinda benefit from people not knowing immediately how my code works. Yay for ninja edits!

Comment: **Removed 6.42 × 10^1016 (from 6.42 × 10^1016 to 6.13 × 10^990)** (@Dennis, please double check the new version, but I think you don't need to sort the filtered results)

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Good catch and nice golfer score. I started with fractions in their "natural" order. The sort was a leftover.

Comment: I'm already starting to think OP should use logarithmic scales for the highscore, seeing how the first scores are in magnitudes of ten o-O

Comment: **Removed 6.13 × 10^990 (from 6.13 × 10^990 to 5.84 × 10^964)**

Comment: @IngoBürk: Not sure if it would help. The base 10 logarithm of my latest answer's length is 5.212243085422315e152...

Comment: **Removed 5.84*10^964 characters (from 5.84*10^964 to 2.05*10^912)** I don't feel like I deserve credit for any of this blind copy-pasting of code (this is me literally stealing one of jimmy23013's golfs to a later answer), but that's what being a robber in a [tag:cops-and-robbers] challenge with many answers that use the same code but encode it differently means ...

Comment: **Removed 2.05 × 10^912 characters (from 2.05 × 10^912 to 1.70*10^808)**

Comment: **Removed 1.70 × 10^808 characters (from 1.70 × 10^808 to 1.17 × 10^678)**

Comment: +1 for the fact htat you wrote the number out in full

Answer (score 15):

## Python, 176 bytes

Not a bowler, but...

```
import sys,fractions
def f(t):
 c=0
 for i in range(t+10):
  for j in range(1,i):
   if fractions.gcd(j,i)==1:c+=1
   if c==t:return str(j)+'/'+str(i)
print f(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: +1 for not a CJam answer.

Comment: **Removed 38 characters (from 227 to 189)**

Comment: @Vincent Your edit introduces new characters such as `9`, which as far as I can tell is against the rules.

Comment: @flornquake whoa I thought that the previous `t+10` came out of the blue, didn't realize that it was actually made with the 't' of 'list', the '10' of 'n=100' and so on. Now I understand what makes that kind of challenge really interesting!

Comment: **Removed 13 characters (from 189 to 176)**

Comment: Suggested edit to `import fractions as x` and do `x.gcd`

Comment: So close, just whitespace prohibits that golf ...

Comment: Whoops, turns out my past golf to 146 wasn't valid; it made it not use command line arguments

Comment: **Removed 4 characters (suggested) (from 176 to 172)

Comment: @VFDan That golf is not valid because it adds the character `b`

Answer (score 12):

## CJam, 9.44 × 10<sup>284</sup>

```
"ddd",'iib:c~
```

The string actually contains 943,611,762,745,112,544,157,801,937,289,871,933,621,396,073,807,297,328,579,826,246,436,861,144,651,900,144,172,793,266,430,374,467,343,433,363,000,182,294,622,535,895,774,344,720,689,882,873,880,571,351,234,260,849,874,055,687,224,065,790,608,381,303,357,434,711,286,607,328,858,338,155,948,406,237,564,203,055,794,077,541,968,210,416,550,049,644,382,519,576,532,604,460,863,849 d's.

Note that the decoded program is slow in the online interpreter.

Comment: inb4 @MartinBuettner gets another few orders-of-magnitudes'-worth of points!

Comment: **Removed 2.2 × 10^6049 characters** (negligible compared to total number). I didn't shorten the decoded code, but I found a version with the same amount of characters, which uses a smaller character code at the first differing position.

Comment: If I'm understanding your method, couldn't you intertwine your three entries?

Comment: **Removed 6.92 × 10^6831 characters (from 1.5 × 10^7222 to 1.5 × 10^7222)**

Comment: @AndoDaan No, because you can always reduce the string to the shortest possible program that is a valid solution.

Comment: **Removed another 1.9 × 10^6050 characters** which adds to **2.1 × 10^6050** with my previous golfing.

Comment: @MartinBüttner ah, right. How about some kind of Ouroboros... by having mirroring (partial) quines at both ends. Hmmm, I should make an entry.

Comment: **Removed 9.5 × 10^7221 characters (from 1.5 × 10^7222 to 5.98 × 10^7221)**

Comment: @user23013 How does that work? How does `o` print `['/ "" [2 1]]` as `1/2`?

Comment: @MartinBüttner It should be `['/ 2 1]`. `o` prints `1` and leaves others unchanged.

Comment: @user23013 ah that makes sense. there's an empty string there for reason, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: WTF, this code challenge is so broken...

Comment: that's enough ds for today

Comment: **Removed 5.98 × 10^7221 characters (from 5.98 × 10^7221 to 4.33 × 10^7026)** (credited to Dennis himself in the latest answer.)

Comment: **Removed 4.33 × 10^7026 characters (from 4.33 × 10^7026 to 3.14 × 10^6831)**

Comment: **Removed 3.14 × 10^6831 characters (from 3.14 × 10^6831 to 1.09 × 10^291)**. Why didn't I think of this... This is a proof of concept, which obviously can be golfed better.

Comment: How do all if these work?

Comment: @Pavel Converting a very large number written in unary to a very large base, then interpreting the result as CJam code. For this specific answer, the base is only 105, but pre-golfing it was as high as `1380878341261486750656911803252309726876604105686729638072729543243701479670593033211008001443536626310535980077544691196522513327846303307992442770355560270350429006522588433404602387992091295744` (the character code of `b` raised to the power of itself)

Comment: Abuse of numeric casting allows me to do: **Removed 1.09*10^291 characters (from 1.09*10^291 to 9.44*10^284)** (and this, by the way, is my first golf that isn't copy-pasting someone else's code)

Answer (score 10):

## CJam, 3.8 × 10<sup>87</sup> bytes

```
"ddd",'#i,(;(bb:c~
```

The string contains 3,795,999,425,660,798,101,493,706,445,244,921,058,557,321,207,441,420,808,131,205,973,714,113,789,081,612,593,756,565 d's.

The generator script for the previous version of this answer, which might be useful later:

```
"'/ea(i(_)),:)_m*{_~{_@\%}h!=\~>&},=~o"
"'bi,(;(;{#}*b":B~'d*`',B":c~"
```

Comment: **Removed 39 × 2^(18 × 97!) ≈ 10^(5.2 × 10^152) characters (from 10^(5.2 × 10^152) to 2.8 × 10^101)**

Comment: I think I lost.

Comment: @user23013: Dang! Serves me right for using `'b`...

Comment: **Removed 2.8*10^101 bytes (from 2.8*10^101 to 4.7*10^98)** (more of the same copy-paste golfing of dubious score value, but on the plus side, this is down to only two digits in the exponent!)

Comment: @jimmy23013 Wait, your first version had a 520000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 **digits** long number of characters?

Comment: @FabianRöling Yes. The numbers on this challenge got really excessive.

Comment: **Removed 4.7 × 10^98 characters (from 4.7 × 10^98 to 3.8 × 10^87)**

Comment: **Removed 1.46 × 10^82 characters (from 3.8 × 10^87 to 3.8 × 10^87)** (A small change that doesn't matter much.)

Answer (score 7):

## CJam, 9.44 × 10<sup>284</sup>

```
",,,",'iib:c~
```

The string actually contains 943,611,762,745,112,544,157,801,937,289,871,933,621,396,073,807,297,328,579,826,246,436,861,144,651,900,144,172,793,266,430,374,467,343,433,363,000,182,294,622,535,895,774,344,720,689,882,873,880,571,351,234,260,849,874,055,687,224,065,790,608,381,303,357,434,711,286,607,328,858,338,155,948,406,237,564,203,055,794,077,541,968,210,416,550,049,644,382,519,576,532,604,460,863,849 commas.

Comment: Editing an answer after somebody already golfed it didn't seem right, so here's my second attempt.

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Made a mistake. It wasn't even a valid submission.

Comment: **Removed 2.1 × 10^7417 characters (from 2.1 × 10^7417 to 7.2 × 10^2749)** (by using two commas from the string as the base)

Comment: ^ You already finished learning CJam?

Comment: @SohamChowdhury No, but I've learned enough to figure out what he's doing. ;)

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Well, you got me there. I should have used d's in the string...

Comment: @MartinBüttner I bet you have a tab open with the "Operators" wiki page. :P

Comment: @SohamChowdhury I did for the Dennis's first answer. Not for this one ;).

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Not that it matters, but you could have left just commas in the string. Its not like there's a shortage... :P

Comment: @Dennis yeah, no clue what I was thinking :D. feel free to change it for readability.

Comment: @Dennis How exactly did you count the number of commas?

Comment: @Hankrecords The string literal is followd by `,`, so we're only interested in its length. The actual code I want to execute is `ea~i_),1f+_m*{_~{_@\%}h;1=\~>&},\(=~'/@`, and [this](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/Xyk1sS4zXlPHME07PlerOr6uOt4hRrU2w9rQNqbOTq1WJ0bDtk5d30GJS10nE4iUk/7/BwA) converts the program to base `44 44#`.

Comment: I didn't know CJam has a Lenguage builtin...

Comment: **Removed 7.2*10^2749 characters (from 7.2*10^2749 to 1.09*10^291)** Credit to jimmy23013 for doing this to your previous answer. I'm surprised this wasn't thought and done long long ago.

Comment: Interesting that the first CJam answer ended up being the least golfable, while all the others were golfed down to nothing ...

Comment: **Removed 1.09*10^291 characters (from 1.09*10^291 to 9.44*10^284)**

Answer (score 2):

## Java - 278

```
import java.math.*;void m(String a){BigInteger i=null;BigInteger n=i.ONE;BigInteger d=n.add(n);BigInteger e=n;for(i=e;i.compareTo(i.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(a[0])))<0;i=i.add(e))do if((n=n.add(e)).compareTo(d)>=0)d=d.add(n=e);while(!n.gcd(d).equals(e));System.out.print(n+"/"+d);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
import java.math.*;
void m(String args[]){
        BigInteger i=null;
        BigInteger n=i.ONE;
        BigInteger d=n.add(n);
        BigInteger e=n;
        for(i=e; i.compareTo(i.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(args[0])))<0; i=i.add(e))
            do
                if((n=n.add(e)).compareTo(d)>=0)
                    d=d.add(n=e);
            while(!n.gcd(d).equals(e));
        System.out.println(n +"/"+d);
    }
}
```

#### Original version

I have made no attempt to arbitrarily extend this solution. Not sure if that will gain me or lose me points. It is, however, a correct solution that will work for very large numbers.

```
public class Test {

    static class Fractions implements Iterator<String> {

        // Start at 1.
        BigInteger numerator = BigInteger.ONE;
        // Start at 2.
        BigInteger denominator = BigInteger.ONE.add(BigInteger.ONE);

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // Never ending!
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            String next = numerator + "/" + denominator;
            do {
                // Keep selecting the next one.
                step1();
                // Until they are relatively prime.
            } while (!numerator.gcd(denominator).equals(BigInteger.ONE));
            return next;
        }

        private void step1() {
            // Take a single step.
            numerator = numerator.add(BigInteger.ONE);

            if (numerator.compareTo(denominator) >= 0) {
                // num >= den - step denom up and num rewinds to 1.
                numerator = BigInteger.ONE;
                denominator = denominator.add(BigInteger.ONE);
            }
        }

    }

    // Returns the nth fraction.
    public String nthFraction(BigInteger n) {
        Iterator<String> f = new Fractions();
        for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.ONE; i.compareTo(n) < 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
            f.next();
        }
        return f.next();
    }

    // Returns the nth fraction.
    public String nthFraction(long n) {
        return nthFraction(BigInteger.valueOf(n));
    }

    public void test() {
        Iterator<String> f = new Fractions();
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "=" + f.next());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            //new Test().test();
            if (args.length >= 1) {
                System.out.println(new Test().nthFraction(Integer.parseInt(args[0])));
            } else {
                System.out.println(new Test().nthFraction(5));
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `1/2` should be the 1st, not the 0th fraction, and the 5th fraction should be `3/4` according to the question.

Comment: @user23013 - Good call - fixed now - thanks.

Comment: And while I'm going to golf this answer, is there any way to compile this program without those `import` lines?

Comment: **Removed 1779 characters (from 2102 to 323)** (without reusing those characters in comments and the test function). Also note that it doesn't work for too large numbers since the input is parsed as an integer.

Comment: **Removed 45 characters (from 323 to 278)**. Yes, I know this is a terrible hack, but functions may output to stdout, and "program" includes functions per the applicable meta posts, so this should be a valid golf

Answer (score 1):

## CPython 3.6.2, 25984 bytes

```
t=int().__sub__(int()==int())
t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=t.__sub__(int().__sub__(t));t=int().__sub__(t).__sub__(int()==int())
d=__builtins__.__dict__;l=list(d);
c=d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))
_=d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))\ndd=d[    l[_]].__dict__
ll=list(dd)
d[l[d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))]](dd[ll[d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))]](d[l[_]](),(d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))),d[l[c]](d[l[t]]((d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d,d))))))
```

This answer was created by porting the code of Soham Chowdhury's Python answer through the cracker I wrote for wizzwizz4's cop answers to [restricted mini challengs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136150/restricted-mini-challenges-cops-thread).

I hope I'm not violating some rule against posts to old [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenges.

Comment: All I can say is `d`

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>488 412 377 347 341</s> 214 bytes

Starting with a more "regular-looking" program; Curious to see what awful things you can do to it.

```rb
require 'set' 
g=Enumerator.new do|y|
v=Set.new
d=2
loop do
(1...d).each do|n|
x=n.to_f/d
if v.include?(x)==false
v.add(x)
y.yield(n.to_s+'/'+d.to_s)
end
end
d+=1
end
end
i=0
$*[0].to_i.times do
i=g.next
end
puts i
```

Comment: **Removed 76 bytes (from 487 to 411)**. Remember to remove unnecessary whitespace from your code ...

Comment: Also, why did you name your variable `denumerator` rather than `denominator`

Comment: @ppperry Haha! Probably a copy/paste or renaming gone wrong :D

Comment: **Removed another 35 bytes (from 411 to 376)**, which adds (coincedentally) to 111 bytes with my previous golf.

Comment: **Removed another 30 bytes (from 376 to 346)** (by inlining variables only used once)

Comment: **Removed another 6 bytes (from 346 to 340)** adding up to 147 bytes removed.

Comment: **Removed another 120 bytes (from 340 to 213)** I was hoping to come up with more algorithmic golfs before doing this, but I can't think of any, so here goes the one-char variable names ...

Comment: Answers are explicitly required to use command line arguments by the challenge. This one doesn't

Comment: I've edited this answer to replace `gets` with `$*[0]` to fix the issue @pppery pointed out, retroactively adding one to all of the bytecounts.