# Restricted mini challenges Cop's Thread

Tags: sequence, restricted-source, cops-and-robbers

> [Robber's thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread)

Your task as cops is to select three things:

- A programming language
- An OEIS sequence
- A byte set

You are then to secretly write a program in that language that computes the nth term sequence using only the bytes in the set.  You will reveal the three pieces of information so that robbers can try to figure out the program.

Answers will be scored by the number of bytes in the byte set with more score being good. Cracked answers have an automatic score of 0.  If your answer is uncracked after one week you may reveal the intended program and mark your answer as "safe".

Answers must be capable of calculating every term in the b-files of the sequence, but are not required to calculate any terms after.

Sequences can be either 1 or 0 indexed for both cops and robbers.

Here is a [Python Script](https://tio.run/##RYxBDoMwDATvvMLyKVGPvVUtr@ADFIwSCezIMVLz@kARtMed3Z1ULAjfa30Xo0wGL0DEpwWCiwRSanfYNIOMdA6KrApH/tdJI5vDbv8OsqReYxYGJVuVaXwA3rKp6@fZfSDyzz@JwgG@Ou99rRs) that checks if your code matches the given byte set.

Comment: Lower score is better? Or higher? So in essence we're trying to find a restricted character set that makes it difficult for someone else to make a program in the chosen language, after we've already worked out a solution?

Comment: Do we need to use all the bytes in our set? I would guess yes but it should probably be specified in the challenge.

Comment: @Shaggy generally no, you can includes others for red herrings, but robbers can use everything

Comment: Do we count newlines as a separate byte or as \n?

Comment: @StepHen does that mean that you can include bytes that aren't even part of your language to get a higher score?

Comment: @H.PWiz you'd have to ask WheatWizard about no-ops

Comment: Can robbers use the same byte twice or more?

Comment: @mrxcoder I would think so, else we are just finding anagrams.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder `You are then to secretly write a program in that language that computes the nth term sequence using only the bytes in the set.` only the bytes in that set, so dupes are allowed

Comment: Do I understand right that the robber could (if characters allow) hardcode an enormous table of values corresponding to the b file? This could be hard for cops to avoid.

Comment: @xnor Yes that would be possible.  The problem is OEIS sequence do not have rigorous specifications, so we can only confirm via test battery.

Comment: What do you mean by "b-list"? Is that the list of terms shown on the page that has the "list", i.e. http://oeis.org/A000004/list ?

Comment: @Azulflame The b-files are files that are associated with each sequence the can be accessed by replacing the `A` with a `b` and appending a `.txt`.  For example https://oeis.org/b4.txt would access the b-files for that sequence.

Comment: Can the byteset contain non-printable-ASCII? (i.e. can I inflate my score by including 0x00-0x1f and 0x7f-0xff?)

Comment: @Doorknob Yes it can, the question is about chiefly about bytes and is agnostic to characters.

Comment: Is input of the number necessary, or can we just print all of the sequence?

Answer (score 12):

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), [A209229](https://oeis.org/A209229), ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136257/20260))

11 characters (including newline):

```haskell
s<=[ ]
how!
```

Outputs True/False as an indicator function for powers of 2:

```haskell
1 => True
2 => True
3 => False
4 => True
5 => False
6 => False
7 => False
8 => True
9 => False
...
```

Inputs are positive integers.

Comment: Does 0 give False?

Comment: @H.PWiz My code doesn't work for 0, your crack can do whatever you want for it.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136257/3852) Very clever~

Comment: @Lynn Nicely done!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136173))

```
ml:= input(as,forge)
```

<sup>it contains a whitespace and a newline</sup>
[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/#python2)
[Intended solution](https://tio.run/##Dci7CoAwDEbhvU/R8Q9kUEehD@PgJaBpqOng08cuh49jn19VlwgroOQjnI7asmTR3DY9d4hadxCtxl6c3/4Ag8TjJWuijntXGFHEPP0)

Comment: +1 I am surprised this doesn't use `+` at all

Comment: Congrats on 10k btw :)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136173/34388)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Don't know python that well, but would `plus` work?

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam No, `sum` would

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder yep, saw that just now... Derp :)

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136279/71256))

I made up my mind, I think I like `t` more than `s`.

So let's use these 30 bytes (including newline) instead:

```
abcdeFgh|jklmnopqrtTuvwxyz
=()
```

Please note that the general challenge description demands that

> Answers must be capable of calculating every term in the b-files of the sequence [...].

In this case, the [b-file](https://oeis.org/A000045/b000045.txt) goes up to the 2000th number, which is way beyond what can be computed using `Int`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136418/3852)!

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136279/71256)

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, [A000290](https://oeis.org/A000290), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136202/31516)!

The sequence is the square numbers: **0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49 ...** (so that you don't have to check the link).

```
'()/@^_
```

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136202/31957)

Comment: That was indeed the intended solution :)

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136260/20260))

Everyone likes Fibonacci numbers, I like Haskell...

I have carefully selected 30 bytes for you: the lowercase letters except `f`, `i` and `t`, you get the uppercase letters `F` and `T` and the pipe symbol `|` instead, and the three symbols `=()`, and newline. Here they are again:

```
abcdeFgh|jklmnopqrsTuvwxyz
=()
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136260/20260)

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, [A034262](https://web.archive.org/web/20170610111339/http://oeis.org/A034262), 43 bytes, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136363/56433)

`!"#%',.=?ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]_{|}~`

Computes `a(n) = n³ + n`.

Comment: Can't get the b-file now. Is returning an `Int` good enough?

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136363/56725)?

Comment: @ChristianSievers Yes, that's exactly my solution.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, [A009056](https://oeis.org/A009056) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137762/34531))

Another simple one, now again with enough letters to make it look like ordinary Haskell and maybe for you to amaze me by finding a solution completely different from mine.

The sequence is *Numbers >=3* and the charset consists of these 30 bytes:

```
{[abcdefghijklmnopqr uvwxyz]}.
```

---

The crack has some nice techniques. I was just thinking of this:

> `head . flip drop [ floor pi .. ]`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137762/34531).

Answer (score 3):

## C (C99), [A000005](https://oeis.org/A000005), 25 Bytes#, [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/136209#136209)

These are the bytes for a full problem, takes n as a command line argument and outputs answer to stdout.(Space is included in bytecount).

```
<=>,;!"()*%+acdfhimnoprt
```

Comment: ok I was wondering lol. as a command line argument?

Comment: Yes, I'll make that clearer

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136209/31957) this was fun :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary), [A002275](https://oeis.org/A002275), 1 Byte

Byte set:

```
0
```

I had to at least try it :3

(I don't think it will be particularly hard seeing as every command in the language is available)

Comment: Why not include all of the bytes to maximize your score?  You have scored the lowest amount possible, when it would make no difference to include all of the bytes.

Comment: I thought we were going for a low score (sorry, I'm new here).

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136215/32686)

Comment: @muddyfish Is input as a character allowed for brainfuck?

Comment: @sonar235 In general we do allow input as character for brainfuck.  Although since values here exceed 255, I don't think an answer that uses them can be valid.

Comment: @muddyfish Good to know. Would certainly have simplified my solution lol

Comment: muddyfish's solution is still not valid though see my edited comment.

Comment: @WheatWizard Didn't catch that, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## Cubix, [A000027](http://oeis.org/A000027) (SAFE) 17 points

```
!&')-/0;@Oiru.NSQ
```

My solution:

```
!O!;i)!/u&!!r-)0'u;;!@
```

watch it online [here](http://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=IU8hO2kpIS91JiEhci0pMCd1OzshQA==&input=NTU=&speed=20)

I originally did this without `.NSQ` but I figured I could add them safely.

Explanation:

This sequence is just "The Positive Integers". However, Cubix has three input commands, `i`, which reads in a single char (pushing `-1` if input is empty), `A`, which reads in the rest of the input as chars (pushing a `-1` to the bettom of the stack), and `I`, which reads the next number off the input (pushing `0` if there isn't a match). So naturally, I only provided `i` which reads in digits as their ascii value. uh-oh. Additionally, `-1` is the usual marker for end of input, in conjunction with `?` so I got rid of `?`, forcing me to use `!` (skip next instruction if TOS is not zero) for control flow. Finally, I thought I needed `&` to concatenate digits for printing with `O` (which outputs the top of stack as a number), but I realize now that that wasn't necessary either!

Another part of the challenge was originally to not have `.` the no-op character, but you can use pairs of `!` instead if you're careful:

```
    ! O
    ! ;
i ) ! / u & ! !
r - ) 0 ' u ; ;
    ! @
    . .
```

`i)` : read input, increment.

`!/` : if top of stack is zero (end of input), turn left

left: `;O.@` : pop top of stack, output as number, halt.

otherwise:

`u'0`: push char code of `0` to top of stack

`)-r`: increment, subtract, and rotate

`;;` : pop top of stack twice

`u&` : concatenate digits

`!!` : net zero effect, now we are at `i)` again.

Comment: Cubix has some noop characters right? Why don't you add those to increase your score?  Or is part of the challenge that there are no noops.

Comment: @WheatWizard I decided to be merciful and add `.` but it can be done without it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), [A057077](https://oeis.org/A057077), 77 bytes

Periodic sequence `1, 1, -1, -1`. As a list:

```
a(0) = 1
a(1) = 1
a(2) = -1
a(3) = -1
a(4) = 1
a(5) = 1
a(6) = -1
   ...
```

Character set (edited), which includes a newline and a space character:

```
!%&(),0123456789;?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz[]#.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/19BQVNBkwtIKCo4cCko6Cno/f8PAA)

Comment: Any reason you modified the character set?

Comment: @Poke apparently the higher the byte count the better, so I just added a bunch of non-useful commands.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5, [A000030](https://oeis.org/A000030) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136232/9365))

Byte set:

```
imnprt7 $;()<>=~.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#perl5)

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136232/9365)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 17 bytes, [A000290](https://oeis.org/A000290) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136266/58563))

Again, this is the simple square sequence a(n) = n<sup>2</sup>.

Byte set:

```
$()=>CI`abelotv{}
```

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136266/53513)

Answer (score 3):

## [Seed](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Seed), [A005408](https://oeis.org/A005408) (Odd Numbers) - Safe

Here's a slightly more challenging one. You may use any characters valid in Seed:

```
[0-9 ]
```

You shouldn't be able to brute force this one in a week unless you have a monster of a computer. Good luck! It's crackable.

#### Hint

> This is the Befunge-98 program used in my solution: `9&2*1-.@` (the `9` can be removed, but my solution just happens to have one)

#### Solution

```
8 47142938850356537668025719950342285215695875470457212766920093958965599014291682211474803930206233718243166021324700185443274842742744297183042397910454208210130742260519105651032450664856693714718759816232968955289663444878636053035645231246428917992493766505872029989544065894418166685284738859999912471659057565000392419689361271972485444731284404987238803115210428572945108908191097214978382112218242627719651728712577306652405452922782307249485947045215982784790396555726144526602778473387279897334709142853151393812930171163300904436548870603006549005515709074682843356844201220668045057407146751793470423217099467145255174198241606814578351260769359571053755888106818197239116973006365593563235361647743411341624822052103816968153274122434280200888824954875622811325064255818154979564925710534165572852442761249176778416688044630942040966271963723430245979221181930857841829694362184653939393940015797332978459794253176110314873994228261888801228999293570329618551223457182420746927212801550646743152754821640064626761542582557138452651970009253770914346130172884305622027370793496993281847017017643506435562229916984107083951938286577012273222191422054315198157936674247934699496471202544270325061352014830137178245082445717253260177560449757186762445707057028987371278573629077370632470496186218574320801798046510846708620502139560277546345198686675095078255875594169064796673074708822106659920187882062247609587560174781170641367430722951002242213604709887062481149928551745163110045572994991844223216663621203042075294195007458339984527333125093390189721042315604498435269143549420166732177200370228527273606218617171975362431824163269672003982537382982066136613799403024924018145511099557720492305303748099327810811511080314262364010281851651151072957475365629128068033597559560186625877942054704386175359499573139930378099420149452745731809033737756051947913924265484582800618244473333957173960222243311738522875022546610298627492222587971756897328087719407454153248557203886421828643453889090192355970705084245312184441674098515659253482621260617211786550204852895652236768886852209506535523414991099331857674826373947830587028494510697603296607361093480842935154672353288419699354739650168309017848485131553416956405911683526896232046773861961911767319373432460217755874481607587604361758089936007730253450733375831228127106295259261723611771334468553746160739548375950046831923765023329346333968732796413192682936767133122325481273354810124729664400173367781325488656859581438769940474229394692089519981810909719628263357284973442177568041416363386891516725592952892168077523560584005586276794967492051823290615767599202657060820223928678900774601616908031321346819422162123048834532926372862962159255934240435694566497798544870186550219886342379298214007368081326725550763589917206162393892085506551547475259270513853987294911388226039365971184089828739349642347312302559286882065147953715607221387657413593069535573044067517274676745306396611760657091792151803798859781616126637075577936361782593546481811651450365118155866449850474140044293772144065341051900055416408240857348697564252386403719942197789892382627153382011984996644288495699209129097948405810551134169739499539470610790009272281731894550593600643079188663110695127017324336488487580799309995227054576681630676222848231145106058050452439356753552872060820230589152143268436210090733908507724084889788244157692417246691477400856716677564609725979550100138132944851304473466485128295568194188600539248624248078558656162635444219199062786468487219220160009464328883337821175254405764395407405891483810757405446047244460754827113527540703326714751461178900155717130399854358953609995319006890674085682111514072508440632941090209366005504352890092326935445829213294943731517698438648298921337375443947066950275955144209037675013663600062205168551851984361951824731229113379464426979717688372371011461890139087487634586087688796134318950140718824105959727161482389914414206768064990410615468858520426399188835467970981786227122743162945627167772066100574532803061925537235491026486409948728571706557098859331941260622260924660292578136091523126589085799981416326395824628987154802653126685882440760385315869346960183809644486238810912663304360284449610976505715001267334297285036791711464142665122000857666018757370925847113798258537503747803972255591351740843663253694303946089997282812556281486820325652814785261116697261899511762129550421005941055852897451832731304151488058522478260009347144486599715629242208891126238083949281490804191584238425634093683587199278186505945727829025071885767559828670803412582690901456978557379916793144695491189633486065077294485660840922713748873840986104486221528464294334436081663106336911265802650605150347413103936140565054608396116572669757269475369570465915381045895991937087068526458273755454602799814909213983801968791431574508976448235055061998715636460946550584682626461010298101802277643570201189324102499951196290880892383380284543173390448406975616650185808619832614403133944687275834716343817926764699295672501869876060896683204343897481630037607159476461359111190545646447421653872016775582115425356868533678655969328210255235050133718364831289991244684695035034122861927276046255405376531096051541299607470934463981741370397268760811035606321455156217990078359217247117349544774085111287345436916077577032709684005131011429476229617901273007027774182864475737502587896225475248267937497254066190335088823904767397814233350286976811901982274477445433872253983823904938249655089770642137858608313524715533520654523880832056453080193644871440738737277389718589793074725139142291918837706550037934799585495183374639955887618135803388399608755212147742199481865453122900714456703147150994585431640652462593333773031385396586933380738103697887063571042512186708015948688088011290197524699274772775288900864690592106393483764109837848793374117655194139018455509931621247697015323332300969105814058088442693320033876473960017819576425062784644138417943454576404265382986995583045527928832
```

Comment: How did you generate this?

Comment: @2EZ4RTZ Painfully, and with [Python's source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_randommodule.c) as a reference. It can probably be golfed a lot though.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136560/34531))

It's cracked, and I won't start a new version, but if you want to play more: it's possible without `y`, and it's possible to be efficient.

---

I apologize for leading you in wrong directions by giving a `g`.
Let's do the same without!

Here are the 29 remaining bytes (including newline):

```
abcdeFh|jklmnopqrtTuvwxyz
=()
```

Again, remember that `Int` won't be enough to compute the 2000th Fibonacci number which is needed because it is in the b-file.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136560/34531)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136650/34531))

This is kindof (as announced) not a new version, but completely different. (Right?)

I still hope I can make you rediscover my nice little observation.

This time you are asked to implement the Fibonacci sequence using a charset of size 17, which (as far as I know) contains only <s>one</s> two unneeded chars:

```
eilnt=(,).[ ]_:0!
```

Note that there is no newline (but feel free to show a version which has them for readability) and remember that you have to be able to compute the 2000th Fibonacci number.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136650/34531).

Answer (score 2):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), [A010701](https://oeis.org/A010701) Score: 9 [SAFE]

Byte set:

```
0x21, 0x24, 0x2F, 0x3A, 0x3F, 0x5B, 0x5D, 0x5F, 0x7C
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/#braingolf)

The code:

```
$_/[!?:]|[!?:]|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fJV4/WtHeKrYGQv7//98cAA)

### Explanation

```
$_/[!?:]|[!?:]|  Implicit input from commandline args
$_               Remove top of stack
  /              Niladic division, push 5
   [...]         While loop, decrements bottom of stack at start of loop
                 then decrements each time loop reaches end
                 Exits when bottom of stack is 0
    !?:.|        If conditional without popping, runs contained code if top of stack is 0
                 This is the sneaky trick here. The conditional skips the end of the loop
                 As a result, this whole block from [ to | effectively acts as a decrement.
         [!?:]|  We do this twice to lower the 5 we pushed down to 3
                 Implicit output of top of stack.
```

Comment: So, I was wondering why nobody had solved this yet, and I realised it relies on an undocumented feature of while loops. Whoops! Try experimenting around a little with while loops and conditionals, and you should find the answer fairly easily ;)

Comment: This is now safe.

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), [A000217](https://oeis.org/A000217), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136320/63641)

Byteset:

```
$:=1;
\-
```

<s>Note that this uses a feature that I haven't pushed the documentation for yet, so I'll push that tonight, if you wait until then. (Or you can slop through my source code... have fun).</s> Documentation pushed. Would be a byte less if a recent bugfix was on TIO.

Intended solution:

> `=1-1:--\1$
>  ;$`

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#cquents)

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136320/63641)

Answer (score 2):

## R, [A000142](http://oeis.org/A000142), ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136186/67312))

Byte set:

```
-()*,`=cfinotu
```

Intended solution:

> `f=function(n,c=n==n)'if'(n,f(n-(n==n),c*n),c*(n==n))`

Comment: [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136186/67312)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136183/53880))

```
l:= input(a,forge)[]
```

<sup>it contains a whitespace and a newline</sup>
[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/#python2)
[Intended solution](https://tio.run/##HYoxCoAwDAD3viJjAh3UUehLxMEhakDSUOLg66N1Objj7PGz6hRhBSn5h5z22kBAFNqmB6Oo3Y5Es2UvnheGPmgf8Ev0K3fVNVkTdbxY0YgixuEF)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136183/53880)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), [A000012](https://oeis.org/A000012), 19 bytes, SAFE

```powershell
$.0=[]acefilnorstv
```

Includes a newline and 18 other bytes. Good luck.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/n0tFz8A2OjYxOTUtMycvv6i4pOz/fwA)

---

#### Intended Solution:

```powershell
$a=$a[0]
$error[0].invocationinfo.offsetinline
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXRViUx2iCWSyW1qCi/CMjSy8wry09OLMnMz8vMS8vXy09LK04tyczLycxL/f8fAA)

This sets `$a` to be the value of an uninitialized variable `$a` indexed at `[0]`. Since that won't work, you get an error stating the following:

```powershell
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:1
+ $a=$a[0]
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

The second line then pulls the `.InvocationInfo` and `.OffsetInLine` (i.e., where the error occurred), which in this case is always `1`, and hence the A000012 sequence.

Answer (score 2):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), [A000027](https://oeis.org/A000027), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136192/34388)

```
 !"#%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

That's right! You get all of ASCII! Wait... there's no `$`... what's `$` again in cQuents? Oh, yeah, the index builtin. Well, tough luck :/

Intended Solution:

> `#|A:A`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf4PBAA)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136192/34388)?

Comment: @Adnan yup that works, I guess I shouldn't have opened it up as much as I did :P I couldn't think of any different ways to do it, good job. Added intended solution.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, [A000042](https://oeis.org/A000042), [cracked by Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136236/53880)

Byte set:

```
{})_%si
```

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136236/3852) Cute~

Answer (score 2):

## R, [A000290](http://oeis.org/A000290), ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136213/67312))

Byte set:

```
()%cfinotu
```

Comment: no `c`, but everything else for `function`? That's horrifying. I know how to do this except for reading in input...

Comment: @Giuseppe woops, the `a` shouldve been  a `c`. sorry.

Comment: This is what I get for doing this shit manually...

Comment: No worries; this is tough enough!

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136213/67312)

Comment: plus it's way easier to be a robber than a cop...

Comment: I'll try to come up with something for you in R

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), [A000004](http://oeis.org/A000004), 5 bytes, Cracked

Just messing around to start off. Should be easy for anyone familiar with Ruby. It's a low score, but whatever.

```
/np.$
```

---

[Cracked, unintended exploit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/136227#136227)

[Cracked (intended answer using `n` flag)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136255/6828)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136227/34388)?

Comment: @Adnan Eh, I'll accept it. Should've required the `n` flag (which is the reason it's in the byte sequence, and would make `$.` equal 1)

Comment: [Think I have your intended solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136255/6828)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, [A007504](http://oeis.org/A007504) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136288/72043))

This byteset, including newline:

```
bfuwo)nm1h[=(t+;0a
sig%pr, le:]
```

My code does not provide infinite output, but can compute the entire b-list.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136288/53748)

Comment: Jonathan, put it in python 3 and I'll test it when I get to my pc.

Comment: Scrap that I used a `.` :(

Comment: I've fixed the crack.

Comment: ...and migrated to Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>13</s> 10 bytes, [A000045](http://oeis.org/A000045), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/136371#136371)

This should be easy.

This is the Fibonacci sequence: F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) with F(0) = 0 and F(1) = 1.

Byte set:

```
$()-:<=>?[]_~
```

**Edit:**

It can be even done with the following 10 bytes:

```
$()-:=>?_~
```

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136371/41805)

Comment: This isn't [code-golf]: "Answers will be scored by the number of bytes in the byte set with score being good." More bytes are better.

Comment: @LarsW on the other hand, more bytes also makes it easier to crack :)

Answer (score 2):

### [Snowman](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/snowman-lang), 212 bytes, [A000042](http://oeis.org/A000042)

```
#$%&*01:;=?@CEFGHIJLMOQUVXYZbcdefghijlmnopqsuvxyz~
```

... plus space, [0x00-0x1f inclusive, and 0x7f-0xff inclusive](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136150/restricted-mini-challenges-cops-thread/136316#comment333426_136150).

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, [A008615](http://oeis.org/A008615), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136335/72043)

Bytemap (with newline):

```
n)ir=-
(u0*pt
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136335/20260)

Answer (score 2):

## R, [A105311](http://oeis.org/A105311), ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136409/67312))

Byte set:

```
'%(),:=acdegilnopstx
```

Comment: [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136409/67312)

Answer (score 2):

## R, [A105311](http://oeis.org/A105311), ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136457/67312))

```
'%(),:=acdeginpstx
```

Let's try this without the `l` or `o`.

Since this has been cracked, the intended solution:

> `cat(diag(diag((a=scan()))%x%diag((a==a):a)),sep='')`. `diag` is an interesting function, that can be used in three different ways. When presented with a single integer (`diag(n)`), it creates a NxN matrix with 1 on the diagonal. When presented with a vector (`diag(1:n)`), it creates an NxN matrix with the vector on the diagonal. When presented with a matrix (`diag(diag(n))`), it returns the diagonal as a vector. `%x%` computed the Kronecker product of two matrices, where each element in matrix 1 is multiplied with each element in matrix 2 separately. Doing this with a length `n` identity matrix and a `1:n` diagonal matrix, creates a length `n^2` diagonal matrix with `1:n` repeated `n` times. `diag` extracts that again, and `cat` prints.

Comment: this'll be even more fun :)

Comment: does this include a newline?

Comment: @Giuseppe No newlines

Comment: @Giuseppe and I just double double checked, this byteset is correct

Comment: [cracked! ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136457/67312) -- I (incorrectly) used `%o%` before I realized that `%x%` existed. I guess I could have done `'i'=='i'` for `1` but either way works, so.

Comment: @Giuseppe to be honest, I noticed the function and searched a sequence to match it :p

Comment: @Giuseppe Added intended solution and explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), [A000142](https://oeis.org/A000142), 29 Bytes, ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/136454#136454))

```
Byte Set: @.$_ ^*:\v>-1&
```

If you can't tell, that Byte set includes a space.

This should be *moderately* easy to solve.

Edit: Forgot the "A" before the OEIS

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136454/69481)

Answer (score 2):

## R, [A057077](http://oeis.org/A057077), ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136829/48198))

```
1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, etc
```

Byte set:

```
()*/=2abcinopst
```

0-indexed.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136829/48198).

Answer (score 2):

## C, [A027868](http://oeis.org/A027868) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/136514#136514))

I don't expect this to last too long...

Byte set: `int (){reu<5?-:/;}`

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136514/56725)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), [A000142](https://oeis.org/A000142), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137820/70424)

Probably not too difficult, but since I really enjoyed solving these I thought I'll be a cop for once. Here's the byteset (first one is a space):

```
 ()*-:=abcdfghijklmoqruwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

#### Intended solution

LyricLy's solution is much cleaner, but here's the one I had in mind:

> Basically it's the same but instead of using `bool(r)` for `1` I used `(r-r)**(r-r)`: `f = lambda r: (r==r-r or r==(r-r)**(r-r))*(r-r)**(r-r) or r*blam(r-(r-r)**(r-r))`

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137820/70424)

Answer (score 2):

## CPython 3.6.2, [A000002](https://oeis.org/A000002) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137576/43394))

I don't want anybody running out of single-character variables, so I'm giving you 70 pseudo-random characters courtesy of Latin-1.

```
·èõÉÀ]ýÜâô¾×l¡¿Ós¦Í½²uÊi´#¬©Åñ[);?ò
à¢ådêøóÎÐþÒÏ®,(Öß.=Õc_ö\§éºún$tÞb¨
```

This is evil. You can't make a `for` loop. You can't make a `while` loop. You can't even `try` to do anything, much less `except`. I have given a new line so that you can use more than one statement, but there aren't any spaces, tabs or even colons to let you use any sort of flow control. There are no numbers. There are no strings. There is nothing of any use.

You do have `\` and `#`, though, so you can write clear code with soft breaks and comments.

That is, if you speak Jelly.

Comment: [cracked with over 28kb of code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/137576#137576)

Comment: @ppperry Congratulations. It is possible to get much smaller than that, though.

Comment: I knew I was posting an unnecessarily long crack, but cracked is cracked, and it's only one day away from being safe.

Comment: @ppperry Fair point. Nobody else is probably going to attempt it, so there's no point saying that it's suboptimal.

Comment: @ppperry That's not supposed to be there... Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), [A000035](http://oeis.org/A000035), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137177/9365)

A000035 is **n mod 2**, in case the site goes down or you're too lazy to check yourself. Charset:

```
023456789\`efu
```

Taking the "somehow still Turing-complete" route. I suppose I could've added 51 or so non-ASCII chars to improve my score, but that feels kind of like cheating.

Takes input through `prompt` and outputs through `alert`, and can be run in any modern browser.

---

Intended solution:

````
\u0046\u0075\u006e\u0063\u0074\u0069\u006f\u006e`\u0046\u0075\u006e\u0063\u0074\u0069\u006f\u006e\u0028\u0046\u0075\u006e\u0063\u0074\u0069\u006f\u006e\u0028\u0022\u0072\u0065\u0074\u0075\u0072\u006e\u0028\u0034\u0038\u0032\u002f\u0032\u0029\u002e\u0074\u006f\u0053\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067\u0028\u0032\u0032\u0029\\u002\u0062\u0027\u0065\u0072\u0074\u0028\u0070\u0072\u006f\\u006\u0064\u0070\u0074\u0028\u0029\u0025\u0032\u0029\u0027\u0022\u0029\u0028\u0029\u0029\u0028\u0029```
````

which, when the escapes are removed, translates to

````
Function`Function(Function("return(482/2).toString(22)\u002b'ert(pro\u006dpt()%2)'")())()```
````

which simplifies again to

````
Function`Function(Function("return(482/2).toString(22)+'ert(prompt()%2)'")())()```
````

This works because JavaScript allows `\uXXXX` escapes in variable names (though not in arbitrary code, as Java does). The outer ```` Function`code``` ```` is necessary to run the code at all, since the entire thing needs to be escaped.

(If you're confused about how this works: JavaScript has something called [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals), which for our purposes is just a function call on a string; it just uses `` f`string` `` instead of `f("code")`. So ```` Function`code``` ```` is about the same as `Function("code")()`.)

Now, because of the lack of the hexadecimal chars `1abcd`, we'll have to double-encode certain necessary characters such as the `m` in `prompt()`. So instead of `\u006d`, it becomes `\\u006\u0064`. But now we need to evaluate this as a string twice to make sure this gets fully decoded. (`pro\u006dpt()` would work just fine, but using `\u002b` as `+` would not.) This is what the second `Function(code)()` is for.

One further obstacle exists: there's no `1` in the charset, necessary to create an `a` from `\u0061`. So there's no way to generate an `a` by unescaping a string (I checked, the octal representation is `\141`). Instead, we can generate it with e.g. `(20/2).toString(20)`. I went ahead and generated `al` in this manner because `l` would require double-escaping like `m`.

But the problem now is that the innermost `Function` call is now just generating a string. In order to actually *execute* it, we need to return it from the function and pass it to a *third* `Function` call. This we do, and finally our journey is complete.

<sup>*I am aware of using `${}` within template literals, but those aren't in the charset, alright?</sup>

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137177/9365)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubically](//git.io/Cubically), [A016742](https://oeis.org/A016742) (Cracked)

This sequence is even square numbers: `0, 4, 16, 36, 64, ...`

**Byte set:**

- Any letter except `[UuDdLlRrFfBb]`
- The digits `[6789]`
- Any symbol except `[-^:@/]`
- Anything not mentioned in the ASCII character set, including whitespace.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/#cubically)

Comment: You don't need to include that last note; languages (and language versions) made after the challenge are perfectly valid as of a new consensus.

Comment: @MDXF I wanted to specify which version to use. It was created before loops, but after input. Future language changes may warrant changes to the answer.

Comment: I suggest *not* changing the answer after this has already been posted. People may be working on a crack.

Comment: @MDXF I know, I won't. I was just saying why I specified the version. I guess if anyone wants to crack it with future language versions, they're welcome to.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137953/71434)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org), [A000002](https://oeis.org/A000002), [Cracked with the intended solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/136174#136174)

These are the bytes of a full program, 0-indexed solution for the Kolakoski sequence: [OEIS A000002](https://oeis.org/A000002).

```python
pg*rn:e+%2a tu]
(=foi[)1l,
```

This contains a space, a newline, and all the other characters in the snippet above. <s>[Hopefully this won't be too easy to crack :)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/136174#136174)</s>

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136174/63641)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://tio.run/#python2/%22Python%202%22), [A000042](https://oeis.org/A000042), 11 Bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/136185#136185))

Byte set:

```
int(pru*1)'
```

Answer:

> print '1'*input()

*Note: This is my first ever answer on PPCG, and I may have made a mistake...*

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136185/63641) This doesn't work for the `0` term, but it seems that this was the intended program.

Comment: @notjagan also what I just got - Bobawob, does yours work for `0`?

Comment: Could it be `1` indexed instead?

Comment: Yes, it was the intended program. Sorry, did I need to include the 0th term? Like I said, this is my first ever challenge.

Comment: @Bobawob just switch it to [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A000042), which is the same just without a leading 0

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), [A033307](https://oeis.org/A033307), Safe

```
Fe_pz:"/`'-2;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf4PBAA)

Explanation:

> `":z--F_p-2`
>  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X8mqSlfXLb5A1@j/fwA)
>  `":` means a char sequence; basically, the output needed. Now, we need to just get the current index, which would usually be `$`. `z` starts out as `0` and is the previous number from then on, so we need just to add one to it. `--` is the equivalent of `+`, and `F_p-2` means `Floor(Pi-2)`, which works.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 4 bytes, [A005408](http://oeis.org/A005408) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136258/58563))

This should be an easy one. Odd numbers: a(n) = 2n+1

Byte set:

```
$+=>
```

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136258/53513) (I hope, it's my first Cops & Robbers answer)

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, [A000142](http://oeis.org/A000142), 8 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/136414#136414)

Byteset: `{}*+)%1\`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136414/53880)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), [A006577](https://oeis.org/A006577), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136523/72137)

Byte set:

```
+s-t,n u
r)i1(d>]f[:e&
```

Shouldn't be too hard, but still fun.

EDIT: Cracked by @BruceForte.  The crack looks just about identical to my crack, but here's mine for reference.

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##LYyxDoMwDAXn8hVvqhIBUt1uDPxIxFCJGLwYZIeBr09Bqm655W4/y7rpu9Y5Mzh4HBoIwyEOGiyXwxTeU4O/c0g@jtR5e0NT8idNsaXKm0EgCvvqkgN1n9c1e@wmWq5KYv0B)

Comment: Did you mean to include a `p`, or was that intentionally left out?

Comment: @Azulflame `p` isn't needed since it seems that printing is not required as long as the value is somehow returned.  See [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136240/72137) for a non-contested, and valid, crack.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136523/48198).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://tio.run/#python2), [A001146](https://oeis.org/A001146), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136407/3852)

Byte set:

```
print(2*u)
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136407/3852)

Answer (score 1):

## [Unreadable](https://tio.run/#unreadable), [A000027](https://oeis.org/A000027), 92 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136436/72043)

Byte Set:

```
!"#%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Also add space and newline

Comment: Why not include all of the bytes for maximum score?  There is no loss to adding more bytes if they can't be used.

Comment: There are no other bytes in unreadable that I used. I don't even think that there are other bytes in the language... Could I add all of ASCII even if my language doesn't use some of the characters?

Comment: Since Unreadable is encoded in ASCII you can and probably should use all the characters in ASCII.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136436/72043)

Comment: It's not cracked yet! You are forgetting that the first value in A000027 in 1, not 0.

Comment: My answer is 1-indexed

Comment: Then it's cracked. You're right, I forgot about that...

Comment: I went ahead and added the 0-index version for you

Answer (score 1):

## [LOLCODE](https://tio.run/#LOLCODE), [A000290](https://oeis.org/A000290), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136444/72043)

Byte set:

```
.12ABDEFGHIKLMNOPRSTUVXY
```

The byte set also includes space and newline.

*HAS FUNZ!*

Comment: Are we allowed newlines? As far as the interpreter I'm using (your link), they are required to not get errors.

Comment: Yes, there are newlines... Sorry!

Comment: Also 1.2 (or other HAI version) would be needed to run

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136444/72043)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, [A007094](http://oeis.org/A007094) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/136695#136695))

Numbers in base 8

Byte set `sub {if($_[1]!=%/)ret-n;}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#perl5)

Comment: Two `r` in your byteset

Comment: I like how your byteset as-is looks like valid Perl.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136695/48198).

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045)

This produces the Fibonacci numbers, [OEIS A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045). There's both a space and a newline in there.

It's 0-indexed, so input `0` gives `0`.

```
 ()-;=>cdefinotu
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136513/48198).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, [A000004](https://oeis.org/A000004) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136527/71612))

Look from the other side

```
at~N+1
```

*Step Hen*'s solution

> ~NaN+1

My solution #1

> ~1+1+1

#2

> ~~NaN

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136527/65836) (at least for Chrome console)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ly), [A005150](https://oeis.org/A005150), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136606/56725)

```
!$+-012<=>JS[]lnprsu
```

Well. Let's see how this plays out.

Comment: I wanted to continue working on it, but you added a `-`, therefore: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136606/56725). Nice way to promote your language!

Answer (score 1):

## dc, [A028444](https://oeis.org/A028444) [(cracked)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136579/48198)

`-?/*+23568dpr`

There are no spaces in the byte set, but that’s not a big deal for `dc`.

Sequence is indexed at `0`.

Note: Rado’s Sigma function grows faster than any computable function and is thus **noncomputable**!

> Intended solution: `?dddddd***3*rdd**22*-rd*53*+r26*-8/p`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136579/48198).

Answer (score 1):

### CPython 3.6.2, [A000796](https://oeis.org/A000796) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137616/43394))

I like Latin-1. Here's another 70 characters.

```
,Ðûô[u÷ÎÆ»énb¤Äö]?có´å¡ùÇõÓ«;Ñ$èñÙdÁ¼
¢üÔltsð½(þÚ#ä.×çÈýÅ§ã¯\)³íï¬Â±¥_Ê=iÌ
```

This bunch of characters can calculate the decimal digits of pi. *Surely* this requires flow control. And yet there isn't a colon, so that is impossible. You can't even `eval` a string when there is neither `eval` nor a string.

I'll give a hint: my program takes input from `stdin` and outputs to `stdout`, but I am almost completely certain that it is possible to use other I/O methods.

Comment: For anyone wondering, the available ASCII chars are `#$(),.;=?[\]_bcdilnstu` and newline, and the non-ASCII ones are `¡¢¤¥§«¬¯±³´»¼½ÁÂÄÅÆÇÈÊÌÎÐÑÓÔ×ÙÚãäåçèéíïðñóôõö÷ùûüýþ`.

Comment: @ETHproductions Now you've spoiled it! :-) At least it makes my love of FreeBSD clear.

Comment: It's really not hard to sort the charset... :P Now I'm thinking this must be a template of some sort, since your other answer uses exactly the same ASCII set. I don't know zip about why you would be so specific about CPython 3.6.2 though, so I'll leave that to the Python experts...

Comment: @ETHproductions It's because the subset I've chosen is Turing complete. It's because I'm not about to claim that it works in a version that I haven't tested it in, and I've been very hackish.

Comment: @ppperry I felt like that many, many times. It took me two days to work out a solution, and I knew what I was going for to start with!

Comment: @ppperry You have `è` and `é`, if that helps. :-)

Comment: [Cracked, almost twice as long as the other two cracks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/137616#137616).

Comment: @ppperry Amazing. I've just realised that I forgot to upvote your cracks. They _definitely_ deserve it.

Answer (score 1):

## [shortC](//git.io/shortC), [A000240](//oeis.org/A00240), 64 bytes

Uses the characters in this ASCII map:

```
    "     %     ( ) * + , -     
  1 2                       >   
@ A         F     I             
    R   T             [   ]     
  a     d         i         n o 
p       t     w       {   }
```

Map credit: [ETHproductions](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124323/61563)

Comment: By far the most random place I've ever found myself given credit for something :P

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5 `-n`, [A000290](http://oeis.org/A000290): the squares, score:18, safe.

```
 ;cdeghijklnopqrst
```

### Rules

- Input from stdin, as a string of decimal integer.

### Intended solution

> `int or print;int or die;int ne length q q q or print;int ne length q q q or die;s ss s;chr sqrt length eq chr or redo;print length`

> [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxBDsAgCAS/wgd6bHrwOZVUEwMKvL9UjT00adjDws5SUcrunsmABap0E9YSM05LCAXpsgRtzof7CUdPQbvCmQS0ib0MNhinDglGDvPNytyPm6tlJvWNHg)

> Usage: from stdin, as a decimal integer. 0-indexed.
>  Can accept only a line.
>  Input shall match `/^\d+$/`.
>  No trailing LF to your input.
>  Output from stdin, as decimal integers.
>  If your input is 0 or 1, the program dies but please don't care for such thing; this specification is just for this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

## R, [A000027](http://oeis.org/A000027) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136164/58974))

An easy one to warm up :)

Byteset:

```
eiytnd
```

Solution:

> `identity` returns the input, so maps n to n.

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136164/58974)

Comment: @Shaggy Wouldn't that just return the integer? Shouldn't it return a whole sequence? Or maybe Jarko misunderstood?

Comment: @MrXcoder: Or maybe *I* did! :D

Comment: It should return the nth entry, so this works.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2), 24 bytes, [A001246](https://oeis.org/A001246), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/136182#136182)

Byte set:

```
 )(+*-/12:=<acbdfmlonrx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#python3)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/136182#136182)

Comment: Agh, no fair. :P

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 21 bytes, [A157433](https://oeis.org/A157433), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/136193#136193)

```python
6ut1 28rp5=)ni+03(*7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#python2)

Original solution:

> `n=input()
> print 128*n**2+2336*n+10657`

Probably super easy, but eh, I have `=)`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136193/34388).

Comment: Well, I had already posted this, so [double cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136195/31516).

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes, [A000042](https://oeis.org/A000042) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136201/68261))

Byte Set:

```
%1@JOiv¤ØȷḌṁị“”€
```

(The two quotes are different: one is opening and the other is closing).

(uses Jelly codepage)

The sequence is: `a(n)` is the unary representation of `n`.

Comment: This challenge requires you to submit a character set to use rather than a list of characters

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136201/34388).

Comment: Well a character set rather than list makes this quite a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 19 byteset, [A000290](https://oeis.org/A000290), [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136240/65836)

This is the perfect squares: `0, 1, 4, 9, ...`.

Byteset:

```python
(fam, l+db-ise=10:)
```

Note: I had two iterations with duplicate characters (and missing characters) because I'm dumb.

My solution (not very efficient):

> `f=lambda l,a=1,b=0:f(l-1,a+1+1,b+a) if l else b`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/4PBAA)

Comment: Why are there two `a`s in the byteset

Comment: @ppperry my bad, sorry. Fixed.

Comment: still two `1`s.

Comment: @ppperry I don't know why this was so hard - I believe it's fixed now, so sorry 0.o

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136240/3852)!

Comment: @Lynn and you did it even without a `,` because I screwed up my byteset. Good job! Editing in mine.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes, [A000984](https://oeis.org/A000984)

Uses some of these bytes (ASCII):

```
$&)+/:HZdep
```

Due to floating-point precision, results are only guaranteed to be accurate up to the `26`-th term. I hope that's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org), [A000217](http://oeis.org/A000217), 15 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136400/3808)

Uses the `-p` flag to take input from stdin and output to stdout.

```
$mu.to_vim[d=s]
```

Intended solution:

> `$_=[$...$_.to_i][$..div$$].sum`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136400/3808).

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 10 bytes, [A000007](https://oeis.org/A000007)

Byte set: `-)$>yRa=A(`

Comment: OEIS is currently down, so for anyone looking, `A000007` is `a(n)=0^n`, which is `1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...`.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136380/41805)

Comment: [Cracked with 6 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136381/72685)

Answer (score 0):

## [Seed](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Seed), [A000027](https://oeis.org/A000027) (Counting Numbers) ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136467/72489))

You may use any valid character in Seed:

```
[0-9 ]
```

Have fun! The resulting Befunge program is short, so you should definitely be able to brute force it within a week (if you're crazy enough to do that).

### My Solution:

My solution is a little bit longer than Lynn's solution...

```
4 47142938850356537668025719950342285215695875470457212766920093958965599014291682211474803930206233718243166021324700185443274842742744297183042397910454208210130742260519105651032450664856693714718759816232968955289663444878636053035645231246428917992493766505872029989544065894418166685284738859999912471659057565000392419689361271972485444731284404987238803115210428572945108908191097214978382112218242627719651728712577306652405452922782307249485947045215982784790396555726144526602778473387279897334709142853151393812930171163300904436548870603006549005515709074682843356844201220668045057407146751793470423217099467145255174198241606814578351260769359571053755888106818197239116973006365593563235361647743411341624822052103816968153274122434280200888824954875622811325064255818154979564925710534165572852442761249176778416688044630942040966271963723430245979221181930857841829694362184653939393940015797332978459794253176110314873994228261888801228999293570329618551223457182420746927212801550646743152754821640064626761542582557138452651970009253770914346130172884305622027370793496993281847017017643506435562229916984107083951938286577012273222191422054315198157936674247934699496471202544270325061352014830137178245082445717253260177560449757186762445707057028987371278573629077370632470496186218574320801798046510846708620502139560277546345198686675095078255875594169064796673074708822106659920187882062247609587560174781170641367430722951002242213604709887062481149928551745163110045572994991844223216663621203042075294195007458339984527333125093390189721042315604498435269143549420166732177200370228527273606218617171975362431824163269672003982537382982066136613799403024924018145511099557720492305303748099327810811511080314262364010281851651151072957475365629128068033597559560186625877942054704386175359499573139930378099420149452745731809033737756051947913924265484582800618244473333957173960222243311738522875022546610298627492222587971756897328087719407454153248557203886421828643453889090192355970705084245312184441674098515659253482621260617211786550204852895652236768886852209506535523414991099331857674826373947830587028494510697603296607361093480842935154672353288419699354739650168309017848485131553416956405911683526896232046773861961911767319373432460217755874481607587604361758089936007730253450733375831228127106295259261723611771334468553746160739548375950046831923765023329346333968732796413192682936767133122325481273354810124729664400173367781325488656859581438769940474229394692089519981810909719628263357284973442177568041416363386891516725592952892168077523560584005586276794967492051823290615767599202657060820223928678900774601616908031321346819422162123048834532926372862962159255934240435694566497798544870186550219886342379298214007368081326725550763589917206162393892085506551547475259270513853987294911388226039365971184089828739349642347312302559286882065147953715607221387657413593069535573044067517274676745306396611760657091792151803798859781616126637075577936361782593546481811651450365118155866449850474140044293772144065341051900055416408240857348697564252386403719942197789892382627153382011984996644288495699209129097948405810551134169739499539470610790009272281731894550593600643079188663110695127017324336488487580799309995227054576681630676222848231145106058050452439356753552872060820230589152143268436210090733908507724084889788244157692417246691477400856716677564609725979550100138132944851304473466485128295568194188600539248624248078558656162635444219199062786468487219220160009464328883337821175254405764395407405891483810757405446047244460754827113527540703326714751461178900155717130399854320238635234164429884664271159504714368008455653061601459723385727262777232764564573673873772208222457183846136405752956618693937985108892893985455752900109747276359722218661153262749015305405756329658744441481575547254529963547290233424398012124166511178581644295375904189900373061373853471489496222876806462541916199940534855562482928962080779491332702863921351256172643450743469939804784306286205587292552998145733381435925702081855362374409244827640579395543246453123597643190692540938806013686596772963034314363354010871521973403725835700408947963387110274004628480425371734331910891935140460595015189156420163115488068088520486798706569490006916112796733633895122682258059129006594304004203161927532260544237735899697152969940248758172957772287759336801595261613720119580891726456931895143417855893848415813470404827691913198395587019754512910027895295524122640301750273229263700158423422494600783294301471077720755163088097928474808200825811331834384330131090616226795924514158947235407965623454021092089105236025774499670509312408897668570458845620423145441557589436789713088947243846896823513743795131462439985465454654508125778329519910755888052092925306512948187971238329609568930378458165199920437525216462470929107070404811453630873763646812061350580161443056020563505260186672704841049972564837245044063297483792279875783885332694312955039151703943626840229495942158368887321883672956326501715270278543111513846830331160757034936022626603927067201550075630055296060821698451711220226998542584472966056248420845670285305975196992649811350779376980410458954534606441616709943508562093877902996409050522302853982991210150961788557227893313889825011281746787557452112185337922107257901043776646541934164147921577497411930472664026894384833716916001510862714001082105916461354489145794983975342462583664139916994875750562786683033654066234795041967161156949148282294752956521537053912878502375506909313842856133697079387338725355753694963250928996068864246591064004864326952187480597051907196284596345012237848475736570739686898404311769576575237233438553293161482584973742517010294566986396986963333792493710800886286588229647009335037917560300340277732774595016553407284174237194411762775063365955286488230300605484062176178336345135677894004813511507360069468591733327248913533084977745451497662084575239380871947004076480854627777980299105041121280
```

Comment: Can you link an online interpreter? I can't seem to find one

Comment: @Azulflame There's no interpreter because the language is converted to Befunge before being interpreted. Use the python script provided on [esolangs.org](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Seed) and [TIO's Befunge-98](https://tio.run/#befunge-98) interpreter.

Comment: [Gotcha.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136467/3852) Only took about a minute of bruteforcing on my laptop!

Comment: @Lynn Nice job! I knew I should have gone with a more complex series :P

Comment: @Lynn Care to try a [harder one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136484/72489)?

Answer (score 0):

## C, [A000312](https://oeis.org/A000312) [(cracked)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136693/56725)

`-,;:?(){} eglnortu`

The specs call for a complete program, however this would add many more characters to the byte set making the challenge trivial. Instead, you’ll be providing the code within this template:

```
«your-code-composed-of-characters-in-byte-set»

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n = argc > 1? atoi(argv[1]): 0;
    printf("%d ^ %d = %lld\n", n, n, «your-function-name»(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Note that your code comes before the `#include`s.

> Answer: `long long l(long long o,long long n){return o- -n;} long long o(long long n,long long g){return g?(--g?l(o(n,g),n):n):g;} long long n(long long g,long long l){return l?o(n(g,--l),g):- --l;} long long g(long long l){return n(l,l);}` Addition `l` is expressed as subtraction of a negated value `m + n = m − (−n)`, multiplication `o` as a series of additions `m × n = m × (n − 1) + m`, exponentiation `n` as a series of multiplications `mⁿ = mⁿ⁻¹ × m`, and finally the function `g` which calls the exponentiation function. On machines where `long long` is 64 bits wide, this code will give incorrect answers for `n ≥ 16`, but note there are machines out there with word lengths of more than 64 bits, *e.g.* the [Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM)](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/introduction/what-is-ethereum.html) with 256-bit words where `long long` could naturally accommodate values ≫ `2⁶⁴`. So *in theory* the code would work for `n ≥ 16`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136693/56725)

Comment: @ChristianSievers - Great work!

Comment: Your code has an unlucky combination of `o` recursing on the second argument, and `n` calling `o` in a way such that the second argument is potentially much bigger than the first. If you avoid this, you will see your numbers overflowing long before your stack does.

Comment: Thanks for that! Have reordered the parameters and revised the spoiler.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, [A001107](https://oeis.org/A001107) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136731/56725))

This one is easier, the sequence is growing slower and the charset is smaller.

Compute the decagonal numbers *n(4n-3)* using the following charset of size 9:

```
.,_-=[ ]!
```

Again there is no newline.

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136731/56433)

Answer (score 0):

### CPython 3.6.2, [A000720](https://oeis.org/A000720) ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137582/43394))

I have decided to squeeze as many characters out of Latin-1 as possible without simplifying the challenge. There are some unprintables, so I will provide the characters in the following format:

```
print(",".join((
    "0x0-0x8",
    "0xa-0x1f",  #inc. \n
    "0x23-0x24",  # chars #$
    "0x28-0x29",  # chars ()
    "0x2c",  # char ,
    "0x2e",  # char .
    "0x3b",  # char ;
    "0x3d",  # char =
    "0x3f",  # char ?
    "0x41-0x5d",  # A-Z and chars [\]
    "0x5f",  # char _
    "0x62-0x64", # chars bcd
    "0x69",  # char i
    "0x6c",  # char l
    "0x6e",  # char n
    "0x73-0x75", # chars stu
    "0x7f-0xff"
)))
```

I think that makes 208 characters. Feel free to use any of these.

I did not hard-code; that would take *so* many characters I would have to start meta-meta-programming. This set of characters is provably Turing-complete.

Comment: Why the downvote? Dennis did a similar thing.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, and I don't think this is why the downvote, but couldn't you just say "I used `0x0-0x8,0xa-0x1f,0x23-0x24,0x28-0x29,0x2c,0x2e,0x3b,0x3d,0x3f,0x41-0x5d,0x5f,0x62-0x64,0x69,0x6c,0x6e,0x73-0x75,0x7f-0xff`"?

Comment: @MDXF I could, but then there wouldn't be the comments explaining what the characters were and people would have to manually look things up or write a program to get the printable characters out of it. (I admit that my "format" isn't the best, though.)

Comment: [cracked verbosely](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/136151/restricted-mini-challenges-robbers-thread/137582#137582). Sorry, I posted this on the wrong cop answer previously.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, [A005150](http://oeis.org/A005150/) (Look and say), safe

```
 "()+,.01:=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]_celnortwx
```

Gee, you <s>don't</s> didn't have much, <s>do</s> did you?

Intended solution:

> `exec("FROM ITERTOOLS IMPORT GROUPBY\nA=\"1\"\nFOR _ IN RANGE(1,INT(INPUT())):\n\tA=[\"\".JOIN(GRP)FOR M,GRP IN GROUPBY(A)]\n\tA=\"\".JOIN([STR(LEN(X))+X[0]FOR X IN A])\nPRINT(A)".lower())` You have all of the uppercase characters, and just enough lowercase ones for `\n`, `\t`, `exec` and `lower`.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5 `-p`, [A005843](http://oeis.org/A005843), score:16, safe.

```
 .0123456789aelv
```

A simple problem. You should solve this easily if you are familiar with the language well.

### Intended solution

> `eval 36.95.42.61.50`
>
>  How it works: version number such as `5.10.3` is represented as a string.
>  So, you just need to construct a version number to be `eval`uated.
>  Example: `v33` is `'!'`.

Answer (score 0):

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CLC-INTERCAL) 1.-94.-2, [A001477](http://oeis.org/A001477), safe, score: 16.

Byteset:

```
@ABDEHIP`abdehip
```

You may use any i/o method.
Also you may use any compiler option.

[Try it online!](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb) Submitting as CLC-INTRCAL does not let you set compiler option, so you might need to try as shell.

### The answer

```
D`h@I@`P@pAB@d@p`DPb@PD`h@`P@d@aD`h@E@ABPb@P
```

This is equivalent to `DOWRITEIN.1DOREADOUT.1` in Hollerith character set; so input range is `OH` or `ZERO` to `SIX FIVE FIVE THREE FIVE` (inclusive).

[Try the following Bash script online:](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

```
printf 'D`h@I@`P@pAB@d@p`DPb@PD`h@`P@d@aD`h@E@ABPb@P'>.i;sick -h .i;./.io
```

#### How it works

The code can be in Hollerith character set. However, [it is implemented incorrectly](https://groups.google.com/g/alt.lang.intercal/c/JFxcHOjY2lc) so the code above is for such behaviour as in implementation, not for documentation.

[Here is the script to accept punch lines to generate a program in Hollerith.](https://tio.run/##TY5hS8MwEIa/51ccp6MrjZBra@nc@kGHyqDsD5Q42uA025ilGxrQ/vaapS3sw@V97@65l@xPn1330bzXcPcN3tuNB3@QLzePeZ4tofzZg/f0/Lpa/57qgz5PURiC0AgQJoTYaQyp0xQocYYS2EDUQ1GIvPRZWQiZIRmB7RiEvOL4gD7bfjVTnYm5DoLF@mXuD0BZ3GrJFUczMDvQR1B@VexkkCn7tnWjj@ctTtREIU/ioCpI9hrK1us6sl9kRJAwYcuaGbOjme2ii7nvOzt3LoKUOWC4GXm3JHYdFo8R7uYf)

Also why doesn't the compiler guess anything other than ASCII? So I had to force it to use my intended character code, by `-h`.

#### See also

[My answer on Print X without X](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235691/100411)

Answer (score 0):

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CLC-INTERCAL), [A001477](http://oeis.org/A001477), safe, score: 14.

Byteset:

```
ACFGIJLPRWX[\_
```

### Rules

- You may use any compiler option.
- You may specify i/o format by yourself.
- You may specify range of input.
- You may specify whether 0-indexed or 1-indexed.
- I made a program that works on [this online environment](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb).

### Answer

```
IXRJFPAFL[\W_IXJACIXGP[\W
```

This is `DOWRITEIN.1DOREADOUT.1` in Baudot encoding, so input range is `OH` or `ZERO` to `SIX FIVE FIVE THREE FIVE`.
Due to the encoding, you need compiler option `-b` if it is newer so the character guessing does not work.

### Try the following Bash script in online environment

```
printf %s 'IXRJFPAFL[\W_IXJACIXGP[\W'>.i
sick -b .i
./.io<<<'THREE FOUR FIVE'
```

[Copy and paste to try it online!](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

### See also

- [My problem that requires Hollerith encoding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235638/100411)
- [My problem that requires EBCDIC encoding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235691/100411)

Answer (score -5):

## Javascript (ES6), [A000079](http://oeis.org/A000079), 6 Bytes

```
[]()+!
```

Hint:

> Intended solution is 25496 characters long.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137967/21173)

Comment: @L3viathan Close enough. :) I'd actually used `$=>Math.pow(2,$)`, but you had the right idea. JavaScript is weird.