# Print X without X (cop's thread)

Tags: string, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source, cops-and-robbers

*This is the cop's thread of a [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge. You can view the robber's thread [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560)*

A pretty common beginner style question is to print some string, but there's a catch! You need to do it without using any of the characters in the string itself!

For this challenge, we will find out who is the best at printing X without X.  There are two threads to this, a cop's thread and a robber's thread.

In the cop's thread (this thread), users will choose a language (which we will call Y) and a string (which we will call X) and write a program in language Y which takes no input, and outputs exactly X without using any of the characters in X.  The cop will then post both X and Y without revealing the program they have written.

Robbers will select the cop's answers and write programs in language Y which take no input and output X.  They will post these "cracks" as answers in their thread.  A crack need only work, not to be the intended solution.

Once a cop's answer is one week old, so long as it has not been cracked, the cop may reveal their program and mark it as "safe". Safe answers can no longer be cracked and are eligible for scoring.

Cops will be scored by length of X in characters with smaller scores being better.  Only safe answers are eligible for scoring.

### Extra Rules

You may be as specific or precise in choosing your language as you wish.  For example you may say your language is Python, or Python 3, Python 3.9 (pre-release), or even point to a specific implementation.  Robber's solutions need only work in one implementation of the given language.  So, for example, if you say Python is your language, a robber's crack is not required to work in *all* versions of Python, only one.

Since [command line flags](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/56656) and [repls](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7844/56656) count as different languages, if your language is one of those then you should indicate that as at least a possible option for the language.  For ease of use, I ask that you assume there are no command line flags in cases where command line flags are not mentioned.

You may choose to have your output as an error.  If your intended solution does output as an error, you must indicate this in your answer.

### Find Uncracked Cops

```html
<script>site = 'meta.codegolf'; postID = 5686; isAnswer = false; QUESTION_ID = 207558;</script><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script>jQuery(function(){var u='https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/';if(isAnswer)u+='answers/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJeRCD';else u+='questions/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJO6t)';jQuery.get(u,function(b){function d(s){return jQuery('<textarea>').html(s).text()};function r(l){return new RegExp('<pre class="snippet-code-'+l+'\\b[^>]*><code>([\\s\\S]*?)</code></pre>')};b=b.items[0].body;var j=r('js').exec(b),c=r('css').exec(b),h=r('html').exec(b);if(c!==null)jQuery('head').append(jQuery('<style>').text(d(c[1])));if (h!==null)jQuery('body').append(d(h[1]));if(j!==null)jQuery('body').append(jQuery('<script>').text(d(j[1])))})})</script>
```

Comment: Since you said "outputs", are we allowed to throw errors?

Comment: @user I believe errors are considered output, by our standard rules.  I defer to those, so I believe the answer is yes.

Comment: STDERR is [allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2451/36398) as an output means. So maybe it should be specified if the intended output is STDOUT or STDERR, or ...

Comment: @LuisMendo To start as of now full programs are required so return is not possible regardless.  I will say that you must indicate if your intended output is to STDERR, although for most languages errors should be somewhat distinct from legitimate output.

Comment: Does X contains characters from printable UTF-8 only, or can we use any characters?

Comment: @SomoKRoceS You can use any characters.

Comment: Can I allow robbers to use snippets (rather than full programs or functions) to crack my code?

Comment: are programs allowed to take input? can it be just a cat program?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate You can use a REPL if one is available, however snippets on their own don't have sufficiently concrete rules for this challenge.

Comment: @NooneAtAll I will defere to default kolmogorov complexity rules on input.  I believe this may allow you to take input but ignore it, however I am quite certain it does not allow you to take the output as input.

Comment: Can disallowed characters be used in arguments?

Comment: @EthanChapman What do you mean by arguments?

Comment: @Ad Hoc Garf Hunter Command-line arguments, such as `-print` in Mathematica, which redirects hanging values at the end of each line to output, but might create loopholes with things like CJam's `ea`. I'd have to check standard loopholes.

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter To be clear, are robbers allowed to take any input that doesn't share any characters with X, and cops cannot require that it takes no input? So that e.g. rot13'ing the input into X can a be valid solution? Or do you mean that input can be taken but must be discarded/ignored in whatever way makes sense for the particular language?

Comment: @Discretelizard I am not AdHocGarfHunter, but if your program does *anything* with the input (other than completely ignoring it), it is almost certainly invalid.

Comment: @EthanChapman Program flags are [considered different languages](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/56656).  I had not thought if this initially so I will update the question but I will say that in order for command line flags to be used they should be explicitly allowed, either a specific flag or flags in general (as per the language vagueness rules).

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I would expect (and hope) it isn't allowed, but e.g. the tag [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] does not mention it. I guess that in code golf, you could count the size of the input as part of the program and this doesn't lead to problems, but as there is no code-golf scoring here, using input is not penalized by the scoring. Is there some precedent for your interpretation? I've been able to find [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9887/), but that seems mostly about how to apply the tag to questions.

Comment: @Discretelizard [Here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7172/56656) seems to be the ruling on what counts as no input for KC.  I will defer to that for this challenge.

Comment: I am interested to create a T-SQL answer. I'd like to know what is considered output - print or select?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I can't say since I've never user T-SQL with this site.  I think the meta would be better place to ask.  In fact there may already be a question.  Whatever they say there is acceptable complete program output is fine by me.

Comment: @pppery Can the snippet deal with two submissions in a single post? Or should I make two answers and link them if I have a pair of highly related challenges?

Comment: @Discretelizard I don't think it can, although I'm not the author of the snippet so can't know for sure.

Comment: So I had to delete a cop due to misunderstanding the rules. Question should not have kolmorogov-complexity tag.

Comment: Is it legal to post an answer in a specific version of a not yet stable and poorly documented compiler? I’ve already posted an answer in Dotty 0.20, but no one’s been able to answer yet, and only one person has tried. The information needed to crack it can’t be found with a simple Google search, and I’ve linked the Dotty website, but is it too much to expect people to go through the entire site?

Comment: @AdHocGarfHunter Regarding [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207833/95792) that attempts to crack [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207558/print-x-without-x-cops-thread/207759#207759) I wrote - I commented that it wasn't valid because it was in the REPL, and my challenge didn't say anything about that, but Ismael Miguel said that they think it's valid, also because I didn't say anything about repls. I feel that by omitting it from my answer I disallowed it, but I'd like to hear your opinion about it.

Comment: If the string X can contain any unicode character, can't I just add a ton of unused unicode characters at the end of the output and get a score of like 100000? How is the score even meaningful?

Comment: @madlaina The lower the score, the better. You could use 10000 characters, but your score would then be abysmal

Comment: @user Oh, it's obvious now. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 35):

## Python 3, Score: 81, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207567/36398)

X =  `` abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'*,./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ ``

Not terribly interesting since it has such a high score, but this should be somewhat difficult to crack...

**Clarification:** This is in fact a full Python 3 program, running it locally with `python3 print_x_out.py` produces the above output for me. Likewise, the below verifier script produces no output:

```
with open("print_x_out.py") as file:
    source = file.read()

output = """ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&'*,./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~"""

for c in output:
    if c in source:
        print(f"Failed verifier check for '{c}'")
```

**Edit:** Well, that was faster than expected...

Comment: I hope this is a program (complete program or function) and not a snippet?

Comment: I don't think there's actually a way to output something without any letters. If the language is actually Python 3 REPL, can you label it as such?

Comment: No, this is a full program. `python3 print_x_out.py` produces this output for me.

Comment: I added this clarification to the answer -- I can assure you it is possible, but you might have to wait a week to find out how ;)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207567/36398)

Comment: @LuisMendo Don't you mean "?"

Answer (score 15):

## Javascript (Browser), score: 3, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207575/91569)

```
(\)
```

Simple, but hard.

My solution:

> ```` Function`$${unescape`alert%28"%28%5C%5C%29"%29`}``` ````

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207575/81278)

Comment: Every day I learn about more cursed JavaScript features...

Comment: @nthistle: Ah yes javascript is turing complete in so few characters.

Answer (score 14):

## Python 3.7, Score: 1 - [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207662)

X = `(`

Same base rules as [nthistle's challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207563) above:  must be a full script, run with `python3 print_x_out.py`.

I believe it's not possible to use [wacky non-ascii substitutes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207567) for `(` in a Python 3 script, but I may be wrong (I haven't tried them all). My solution does not use that approach, anyway, and the intention is that yours should not either—now that we've seen it once, there's no fun in taking that as the easy way out for all Python 3 challenges.

I know code length is not in the rules, but as we're all golfers here I'd be curious to see how short the solution can get. FWIW mine is 104 characters (97 if we're allowing a trailing newline at the end of the output).

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207662/46076)

Comment: [Removing the redundant class from pppery's answer brings it down to 92 with no trailing newline.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKG4spgrOSexuFjB0So@HsyKT08tySxJzY2Pt03OKILKOmGRBerVKy5JyS8t0SsvAopxOUU7RpsYxMb@/w8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [29 bytes with a different trick](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Xzk5PyUzL92qtCTNnKugKDOvRNvROV0dTGj@/w8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [70 bytes with pppery's answer if you allow a trailing newline.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzknsbhYwdEqPh7Mik9PLcksSc2Nj7dNzijigsg6YZEtKMrMK@FyinaMNjGIjf3/HwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: All very nice.  Here's [my original](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCG/mCs5J7G4WKHCKj4@My@zJD5eJz4@B0jZ5iTmJqUkahVY@eXnpeqkliXmcOUX68XHp6eWJJaUFAFVVHBV2gKFqrgqbdQLijLzSmIqjCyUwISm@v//AA), for what it's worth.

Answer (score 13):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), Score 81, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207593/56656)

```hs
" !#$%&()*+/0123456789;>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\^_`bcdefghjkloqsuvwxyz{}~"
```

This one might be a little difficult.

#### Stuff you don't have

You don't have newlines or spaces (my intended answer doesn't use *any* whitespace at all, however I can't get it to print some of the funkier whitespace characters so you are free to use them for yourself).  You also don't have any of the other ways to apply functions such as `$` or parentheses.  You don't have the other line delimiter `;`, so everything has to be on one line (as far as I know).

#### Stuff you do have

I had to give you the bare minimum of `main=` for a complete program.  I've also given you `prt` as extra letters, it shouldn't take much to see that this allows for `print`.

You also have an assortment of other symbols available to you, I'll let you figure out how to use them.

```hs
:,.[|<-]'
```

These are all the characters I've used, there are no unprintables present in my intended solution.  However since I can't print the unprintables you are fine to use them.

For your reference here are all the functions available using only the permitted characters:

```hs
(||) (==) (<) (<=) min (-) pi tan atan (=<<) (.) map init (:) print
```

## Even harder Haskell, Score 82, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207593/56656)

```hs
" !#$%&()*+/0123456789:;>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\^_`bcdefghjkloqsuvwxyz{}~"
```

A little while after I posted this I realized I do not *need* `:`, so this version has a `:` in the output as well.  I have posted in this answer to prevent clutter from two nearly identical answers, but both should be crack-able separately.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207593/78584) (both versions)

Answer (score 12):

## Rust, score 3 (safe)

`pwx`

No `extern` possible this time, so no calling C functions! (or other crates, but that wouldn't be allowed anyways)

Pretty challenging to output to stdout without being able to type `print` or `write`!

Rust version: `rustc 1.45.1 (c367798cf 2020-07-26)`

---

### Solution

The main challenge is printing to stdout. I identified the following methods:

- `print!`/`println!`
- `std::io::stdout()` and then:

  - `write!`/`writeln!` (or `std::fmt::Write`)
  - using the `std::io::Write` trait and calling `.write()` or similar

All of these require calling a method or macro whose name is excluded by `p` or `w`.

Enter [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html), Rust's method of having runtime polymorphism. Trait objects are pointers both to some data (like regular pointers) and to a `vtable` which is used to look up the implementation of the trait method when called. So a the code

```rust
let trait_obj : &mut dyn Write = ...;
trait_obj.write(&buf[..]);
```

is transformed to something like this

```rust
let trait_obj : (&WriteVtable, *mut ()) = ...;
(trait_obj.0[WriteVtable::write_index])(trait_obj.1, &buf[..])
```

Now we obviously still can't directly call `.write` on the `&dyn Write` trait object, but we can instead do the vtable lookup ourselves. This is extremely unsafe, but it works. Now Rust understandably doesn't provide a way to get the index of a trait method in the vtable (wich we probably couldn't do anyways without spelling `write`). This is implementation dependent code, which is why I specified the compiler version.

Looking at the [compiler code that generates the vtable](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/e22b61bff0bdd08be7665607cb7be3748c8a35d2/src/librustc_codegen_ssa/meth.rs#L108), we see that it first contains the `Drop::drop` implementation (needed for owned trait object such as `Box<dyn Trait>`) and then size and alignment. Then come the trait methods in the order specified by the [function `vtable_methods`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/76e83339bb619aba206e5590b1e4b813a154b199/src/librustc_trait_selection/traits/mod.rs#L468). We see it first collects methods from supertraits, and then methods from the trait in definition order. Looking at the [trait definition for `std::io::Write`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/e22b61bff0bdd08be7665607cb7be3748c8a35d2/src/libstd/io/mod.rs#L1244), we see that it has no supertraits, and `write` is the first method, so its vtable index is 3.

This is the final code:

```rust
use std::io::Write;
fn main() { unsafe {
    let y = std::io::stdout();
    let lock = y.lock();
    let x : &dyn Write = &lock;
    let (data,vtable) = std::mem::transmute::<&dyn Write, (*const (), *mut usize)>(x);
    let z : usize = vtable.offset(3).read();
    let fun = std::mem::transmute::<_, fn (*mut (), &[u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize>>(z);
    let array = [112,119,120];

    fun(std::mem::transmute(data), &array[..]);
}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBT4QwEIXv/Io5kXZTiawXLSs/wosHQkxdhoQIJWmnZmGzvx2HGoWD9jTpe/O@yXPB07IEj@Cp0bobtX51HWGRtBYG01kh4QrBetMiXBPg1yPBBM/bAg9jICGLX7kfzx/smLJ12AsX0JA2k4UIYUu6OjZdNIaM@iTz3qP8YQw4aE3OWD8EQq1PW4ICcTiP1vOmVHBgHYLvZpSluOywM2PjP0d@h2dj23ok8SAzh6bZ39gG@y/5TQH3IiJoJaZVeKwl3JVbGy/oQ0@niCtLMe@SjXNmba7K86PK8yeVH@/rIok6U8UfzFjICoq7VZbVnHe7JcvyBQ)

Answer (score 11):

## [Mornington Crescent](https://github.com/padarom/esoterpret), Score: 4, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208937/)

X = `myHp`

You may have survived the 7UBES, but the real challenge begins now. Face me in battle! First, allow me to rid us of some distractions. Four lines are closed. Over half of the special stations are unavailable. In spite of this ruin, victory remains possible. Even for the likes of you, but it won't come easily... I'll be impressed if you can cut even the tiniest bit of my Hp.

---

Consider the language again to be defined by the linked interpreter, also available on TIO.

---

The main challenge here was the fact that your only arithmetic operation is division, so there is no way to get the character codes by only using arithmetic operations.

My solution is below is quite a bit shorter than the crack (7410 bytes after removing comments), but uses the same basic idea: first divide the character codes of some lowercase letters by 2 to get the character codes of the symbols `'1'` `'2'` `'7'` `'9'` `'0'`. Then, copy and concatenate these symbols to get strings `'109'` `'121'` `'72'` `'112'`. Parsing these strings to integers at Parsons green gives the character codes for `m` `y` `H` `p`, which can then be concatenated to get the result.

A simple trick, but quite a piece of work to implement. In hindsight, I was lucky that I only needed 5 different number symbols and all symbols could be found on position -7 in some available station name.

```
# "myHp" 7 and division is enough to create 2. 
#7 can also be used to get the lower case characters:
# 2 == ord('A')//ord(' ');  Goodge# Street, 7 [District]
#'1' == chr(ord('c')//2);       Be#contree, 7 [District]
#'2' == chr(ord('e')//2); Gloucest#er Road, 7 [District]
#'7' == chr(ord('o')//2);        B#ow Road, 7 [District]
#'9' == chr(ord('s')//2);    Baron#s Court, 7 [District]
#'0' == chr(ord('a')//2);        W#aterloo, 7 [Northern]


###print "myHP" without using those characters
##Plan: get 2
#get 65
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: 65
#put 65 at Cannon Street
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street
#get 32
Take District Line to Sloane Square
Take District Line to Mile End
Take District Line to Victoria
Take Victoria Line to Seven Sisters
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take District Line to Mile End #ACC: ' ...', End: 7
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: 32
# 65//32 == 2
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street #ACC: 2, CS: 32
Take District Line to Southfields #Sof: 2
Take District Line to Cannon Street #CS: str
##Plan: get '1'
#get 99
Take District Line to Becontree
Take District Line to Mile End #ACC: 'c...', End: str
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: 99
#put 99 at CS
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street
#99//2 == 49
Take District Line to Southfields
Take District Line to Cannon Street
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street #CS: str
Take District Line to Southfields #Sof: 2
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: '1'
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Kew Gardens #Ke: '1'
##Plan: get '2'
#get 101
Take District Line to Gloucester Road
Take District Line to Mile End
Take District Line to Victoria
Take Victoria Line to Seven Sisters
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take District Line to Mile End #ACC: 'e...', End: 7
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: 101
#put 101 at CS
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street
# 101//2 == 50
Take District Line to Southfields
Take District Line to Cannon Street
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street #CS: str
Take District Line to Southfields #Sof: 2
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: '2'
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Chiswick Park #Chi: '2'
##Plan: get '7'
#get 111
Take District Line to Bow Road
Take District Line to Mile End
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: 111
#Put 111 at CS
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street
# 111//2 == 55
Take District Line to Southfields
Take District Line to Cannon Street
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street #CS: str
Take District Line to Southfields #Sof: 2
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: '7'
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Ravenscourt Park #Ra: '7'
##Plan: get '9'
#get 115
Take District Line to Barons Court
Take District Line to Mile End
Take District Line to Victoria
Take Victoria Line to Seven Sisters
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take District Line to Mile End #ACC: 's...', End: 7
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: 115
#Put 115 at CS
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street
# 115//2 == 57
Take District Line to Southfields
Take District Line to Cannon Street
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street #CS: str
Take District Line to Southfields #Sof: 2
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: '9'
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Waterloo
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Acton Town #Act: '9'
##Plan: get '0'
#get 97
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Mile End
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: 97
#Put 97 at CS
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street
# 97//2 == 48
Take District Line to Southfields
Take District Line to Cannon Street
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street #CS: str
Take District Line to Southfields #Sof: 2
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: '0'
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Bank
Take District Line to Earl's Court #Earl: '0'
##Plan: get 1 
# 7//2 == 3
Take District Line to Victoria
Take Victoria Line to Seven Sisters
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take District Line to Cannon Street 
Take District Line to Southfields 
Take District Line to Cannon Street #ACC: 3, CS: 2
# 3//2 == 1
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Cannon Street #ACC: 1, CS: 2
Take District Line to Barking #Ba: 1
##Plan: make 109
#copy '1'
Take District Line to Kew Gardens
Take District Line to Paddington #ACC: 'Paddington1', Pad: '1'
Take District Line to Mile End
Take District Line to Barking
Take District Line to Mile End #ACC: '1', End: 1
Take District Line to Kew Gardens #Ke: '1'
#concat '109'
Take District Line to Earl's Court
Take District Line to Paddington #ACC: '10', Pad '0'
Take District Line to Paddington #ACC: '010', Pad '10'
Take District Line to Acton Town 
Take District Line to Paddington #ACC: '109', Pad '9'
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Acton Town #Act: 109
#make 72
Take District Line to Ravenscourt Park
Take District Line to Paddington #ACC: '97', Pad '7'
Take District Line to Chiswick Park
Take District Line to Paddington #ACC: '72', Pad '2'
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Ravenscourt Park #Ra: 72
##Plan: make 112
#Grab '2'
Take District Line to Parsons Green #ACC: 10
Take District Line to Paddington #ACC: '2' , Pad 10
Take District Line to Barons Court #Ba: '2'
#copy '1'
Take District Line to Paddington 
Take District Line to Kew Gardens #Ke: 10
Take District Line to Paddington #ACC: '...1', Pad '1'
Take District Line to Kew Gardens
Take District Line to Mile End #ACC: 1, End: 10
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Mile End #End: str
Take District Line to Kew Gardens
Take District Line to Mile End #End: '...1'
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Mile End #ACC: '1', End: 1
Take District Line to Paddington #ACC: '11', Pad '1'
Take District Line to Cannon Street
Take District Line to Paddington #ACC: '1', Pad int
Take District Line to Cannon Street #Can: '1'
Take District Line to Paddington #Pad: '11'
Take District Line to Barons Court
Take District Line to Paddington #ACC: '112', Pad '2'
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Bank #Ban: 112
#make 121
Take District Line to Cannon Street
Take District Line to Paddington
Take District Line to Paddington
Take District Line to Parsons Green
#int to char
Take District Line to Bank #Ban: 121
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank #Ban: 'p'
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank #Ban: 'y'
Take District Line to Barons Court #Bar: 'p'
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Bank #Ban: 109
Take District Line to Kew Gardens #Ke: 'y'
Take District Line to Ravenscourt Park
Take District Line to Bank #Ban: 72
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank #Ban: 'm'
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Bank #Ban: 'H'
Take District Line to Acton Town #Act: 'm'
#Concat 'myHp'
Take District Line to Paddington
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Paddington #Pad: 'm'
Take District Line to Kew Gardens
Take District Line to Paddington
Take District Line to Paddington #Pad: 'my'
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Paddington
Take District Line to Paddington #Pad: 'myH'
Take District Line to Barons Court
Take District Line to Paddington #ACC: 'myHp'
Take District Line to Bank
Take District Line to Bank
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
```

[Version without comments on TIO](https://tio.run/##7VnBTsMwDL3vK3LjxEewMu0AQ9M6wTlKDY1aYuGk9PNHyrRNCNpkTbvByG2VHfsleX6111ckJdWLQXUtCLQAZTabNS@APSCZHEixe6mAGWRTrorJp@lWakNSmL3pRtgAbI21anHoWHswfcuY5JwsOJYQah3g05GiA1jClbK7Sg0BmBaftERuf6VvFSdo8VnIEthMZS3mR/uAJPnWvHs6ZIB3sCDsKiDd4uMI8dV8LL6LvTqsTP4socx0QJQpCFSNQzzcEQ53bBC/9ozvoGZzThmoNujzEisBjSqwFfIsak8sj/9THkkudS1FwZacWgmCdUBlROZF5v0EbMWtJGqBFZlO8nFCpVnS@EVpjgVyYQXyxC3tSsTJSSfFyMjIyB5nPONUXnVr8dnF9s/w4NzLqbAk6T00LXmWbf/t6isxXfkdi93wPJjq3IHTwanAHilIN93N3N5U7yyejZQTjM8oMMiOvAG7QznxeLSPzhgDVIM7RP9XcnCxjJbaTTkPpTpNkCF44kPYQNkOF63jQJ6jARk@RZ/bDmmv3SXnPfxe@EWEv0LDIwwg7x7yoooRg4drV7@Rb7H/5mkJsPvm@QE)

### The cutting room floor

As much as I'd like to be able to give an encore, I'm afraid I've exhausted my material. The design-space is a bit limited both due to the fact that Mornington Crescent is a language with a simple description and few commands (unlike, say, Javascript or Perl), as well as the fact that `Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent` must be present in every valid program.

I can't present any challenge that is solvable only by a method different from the solutions given so far. Best I can give you is some strings that I didn't use either because they were too easy (i.e. solvable with ideas already given) or too hard. (i.e. I couldn't think of a method to solve them. Feel free to post these as a challenge here if you do!)

I provide the following strings at your own risk, do with them as you please.

### Easy

1. `Spy` leaves open a bit too many arithmetical operators for my taste.
2. `l` shuts down surprisingly many lines with only a single letter, but still leaves many options open.
3. `HypV` is too similar to this challenge, with only a small difference in the startup due to the lack of `Seven Sisters`

### Hard (likely impossible)

1. `SpyH` closes down many pesky operators, but I don't see a way to get a `1` and am stuck without it.
2. `HypVm` is similar to the this challenge, but I don't see how to get a `2` without `Seven Sisters` here.

Comment: This is definitely much harder that the previous answer.

Comment: FWIW, the four lines are `Hammersmith & City`, `Piccadilly`, `Metropolitan` and `Waterloo & City`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208937/46076)

Comment: That was a great challenge, I didn't managed to solve it, but I had fun trying. So if there gonna be more, please notify me :)

Comment: As I said in my crack, I realized I had an inefficiency after I was 2/3 of the way done with the code, but didn't bother correcting it since code length is irrelevant in this challenge. I suspect I would have gotten to something similar to yours if I had corrected the inefficiency.

Comment: @SomoKRoceS Unfortunately, this is the last one from me. I have added a few strings that I didn't end up using for various reasons. I think `l` is a reasonable one to try if you're new to the language.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), Score: 23, safe

```
 "%'*+-./;=_`abehmtvy{}
```

I tried to make this one somewhat difficult. No `exec`, no `import`, and no `print`.

*Note: there is no newline in X.*

[Verify  it online!](https://tio.run/##dZAxT8MwEIV3/4oDVBxDMaJsRRlQ6VCxRCxUAhSS9NJYSmzLvlAixG8PSRpaFrbT0/vu7j3bUGH0bdueQZR4QmhM7SAaVJhBZjYISgMVCHylbU0cUvPJmKqscQS@Tq0zGXp/UJrDSFjZXJXI2BpCSDmcTl75xeWVvL4L4/ckxaKij@brm7PhTNiz0tNGaZnWeY5OOkw2gWCqLHGblL0DKejNAs6HeS0Y2ykqwFjUAafKStvwKfBdygUkHvI5g1zunCLcg4x1F0xN/bLD89LVOnjhdog96/lx09sU9vbwjzlaRUsh9zpT@eiAkxDW3TXrlKaAPzujt9DpXWdzmHgOk9EoGJYdNYY6EqsxZVYkLskInf/l0obQByMget7jkVs83S8elw8nXLRtHO@7j@OAG8/FmPymS/Rv@@IH)

---

### Solution

The code is to large too fit here, so try visiting one of these links: *[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##5Ze7DoIwGIV3X8OFJg605WJ5CRPjRpgwotEAaXTw6REoIKXYmOjicSmcXv72@1tOSnm/HoucVdUyLfanPIu2mx3lC3mWpVNcMnlw4u6RkNhNVkq4pHvJiwOJ6VCvZNDLtiSx0Jp1RS1toabWvdJWooLwXt7kuZbi1QIcMhpKyfRFkFE/Op5vIuqCRZGfkJlETVIym4NnirJLKtu6OmJoy1OgSWbLG7cGbypHfd7ZMt@YzNabz49V83qvcvdBROvmOnTV4H/hvPA@JJs9Jkr8Pp0HTRdC0wlEOg/6uxvoODSdD00XQNNBeqYP7ZmBcbdFohPQriKgXUVAu8pAt0akG0K60PZiYnr/gSmgMSm0r5qY2BbE/sOCGPTvoYn51o2uqh4) or [Verify it online!](https://tio.run/##5ZdLb5tAEMfv@ykmrdxlW5ca8CO48qFKcrByqBVVqiVqtWAvNgpmV8tSF1X57Ckv42dQpPbSzQXvDPOf2d8sjDBP5YpF1uPja5i4saSQskTApPCCCXO2oBBEIFcU8DjiicTgsV8IBWvOhIQ48bhgcxrHtSetl5KuuR@EFKEpjMDD8Kr1Db99917/8HH0/Yfr0dVa/kx/P2BUlBnlWj2WiyDSvcT3qdAFdRcaQUEY0qUb5hFUankwgTfFekoQ2gRyBYzTSMNyzXWe4jbgjYcJuDH4QwS@vhGBpKUQoawCS2SerN68LpJIczAvsM1cX2WataEMH@0FT8aTG6KXfhT4VQRcjGCaVeMiiKSGvwoWLSHzZz0bQivG0KoCCaJhpqqgdopxRTlfucKdSyrirc5LJY21SkByfUx3uqu7T1e3N9cXmGSnmDEG0XJ49/mLYSFxL7jGwqXwNaf6mRGnM2uXRodUi4j5xDFqf2n2t2ZxJY59cPvQMhruDQ6sy611sJMyibU1E3GfmfZTG9DIntQgxwub7MUZ@/WOjOxiDoe9GTnTqKOWnO3BrkXLcC4KX5Zx0NSn/oFpNvXNakyeO/dinnNkvZNiTdHWeW1Zt/tU7/4iY@PhakY7x/8Hz4u1TWmefUxK4/@n6ypNN1CazlaRrqv0e1fTWUrT9ZSm6ytNp@TM7Ck9M/sn37Yq0dlKTxVb6aliKz1VarpLFenqlB2lx8spZvdlYNpKYxpKz9VTTLVHkPkyRpCp9N/DU8xnfdH9AQ) or [Generate it online!](https://tio.run/##pVPfb9owEH73X3EaQrZLxjDpj8HUh9LysKdJ7d7SqMsPA54aG9luC6r2tzM7IYNQGk2qFDn@7nz33X0@L9d2oeRws@nAHbcGnhMtkvSRQwpWAX7BqAPRYKa0MwgZZQtNGBvROEZXcAk4XVtuSLT9xTQaxEEFBnS7SVJDI/bPXsHzGpYrjUYNdxOxFt9FA32tUaOSKklYwwVfOTh6rwBC90IZPdyM6N45ts93ANwyHI/PYoycgt@LpdIWsDIYCpU/PXJnnGlVgDIgKueLFpajyRtVD/Q7KthOT7te8tLm6C/aRD1vwGGbyGFrcm/cO/M/93v2hqztdHg8tuI9bQo94XMhpZBzULNKUZg9ycwKJZ23NBAW@ClG16XSHyBuHRjH4lX6yAyWDU1lfrQVStHNblQaw1gBF6258Uf4imeka@i93O0wdIFcBTChyL/tlXvbgOFT9x6f9D73v3y7fPiVpHxR2Of16x88RjD1mQLc/62EJFtWl8nnycGnyH0KYzVROicr6uoDz9@rC9jOdNcE5VffWl3LdQDTAG6o7/n2x08WQpHMRVb30MlU7m51XLp8SM9n73Pp7JxgrSwLMUVLLaT1ns3mLw)*.

The main idea is to use `#coding:ENCODING` to define an encoding for the source code. The intended solution was to use `#coding:ROT13`, but there could be another encoding which I have not yet explored.

After placing this magic comment on the first line of our program, every letter will be translated with `rot13`. This means that `print -> cevag`, etc.

Next we need to determine which builtins (when encoded with `rot13`) are actually available to use. It turns out that we are limited to just a few:

```python
cmp, set, bytes, abs, hash, hex, type, map, max, exec
```

Also note that the output should not contain a newline, meaning we must use `os.write` as opposed to `print`. But since we don't have access to `import`, it seems impossible to call `os.write`... On the other hand, we do have access to `exec`, which allows us to evaluate a string! The only problem now is that we can't use quotes. It is possible however, without needing them.

As a start, let's figure out how to `exec` the letter `i`. We can't use quotes, but `bytes` turns out to be very useful here. For example, `bytes(abs)` evaluates to `'<built-in function abs>'`, which coincidentally contains an `i`. Thus, `exec(bytes(abs)[3])` will do exactly what we want.

This strategy of creating letters is abused throughout the entire source code. It should look something like `exec(bytes(abs)[10]+bytes(bytes(9))+...)`.

One last thing. `+` is not allowed either, though this is manageable. We can use the following construct as an alternative to joining characters: `bytes([a, b, c, d, e])[2::5]`.

Comment: the `.` and `e` are really killing me

Comment: That was my intention :)

Answer (score 7):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), score 4 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207634/9481))

```c
#_ep
```

My source code doesn't contain any of these characters and when complied and run, it outputs `#_ep` to `stdout`.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207634/90181). Interesting question, I have never had to use inline assembly before.

Comment: @xibu You got it bang on! Well done! :-)

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) \$\le\$ [2.10.3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/releases/tag/v2.10.3), score 252, safe

```
λƛ¬∧⟑∨⟇÷×«
»°•ß†€½∆ø↔¢⌐æʀʁɾɽÞƈ∞¨ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQRSTUVWXYZ[\]`^_abcdefghijlmnpqrstuvwxyz{|}~↑↓∴∵›‹∷¤ð→←βτȧḃċḋėḟġḣḭŀṁṅȯṗṙṡṫẇẋẏż√⟨⟩‛₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈¶⁋§ε¡∑¦≈µȦḂĊḊḞĠḢİĿṀṄȮṖṘṠṪẆẊẎŻ₌₍⁰¹²∇⌈⌊¯±₴…□↳↲⋏⋎꘍ꜝ℅≤≥≠⁼ƒɖ∪∩⊍£¥⇧⇩ǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔ⁽‡≬⁺↵⅛¼¾Π„‟
```

(Or, in other words, everything except `koPĖ` is disallowed)

If you're wondering where to start, some of the ideas from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236209/100664) may be applicable. However, Vyxal has changed a lot since that competition. Good luck!

<sup>Btw, my intended solution is 37 yottabytes.</sup>

## Solution

<sup>note: Due to bug fixes, some of the links here won't work anymore</sup>

This character set is quite powerful. We have these builtins:

- `ko` - octal digits as a string, `01234567`
- `kP` - printable ASCII
- `o` - remove string a from string b
- `P` - strip string a from the outsides of string b. Has *interesting* (and very helpful for us) behaviour on lists/ints
- `Ė` - Evaluate string as Vyxal / take reciprocal

In older versions of Vyxal, regular python floats were used, making it [a lot easier](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236209/100664). Now, we have sympy floats.

The significance of this is that 1/1234567 used to be represented as `8.100005913004317e-07`, allowing us to easily get the characters e and -. Now, it's represented as `1/1234567`.

In older versions of Vyxal, a leading zero on a number did nothing. Now, it pushes a zero before said number. This is a problem, as our only real way of getting numbers is with 1234567, and since the zero is before the number using `o` or `P` will just leave a zero.

`koĖ` [pushes a zero](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia2/EliIsIiIsIiJd) as well, but appending a `P` (strip) [results in a zero](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia2/EllAiLCIiLCIiXQ==), which we can then [remove](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia29rb8SWUFDEliIsIiIsIiJd) from the string `01234567` leaving 1234567, which we can eval.

#### Getting strings

Following this, we can [get](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29QIiwiIiwiIl0=) the `/` character by taking the reciprocal (resulting something that stringified gives `1/1234567`) and stripping `01234567`. We can evaluate this to:

- Divide two numbers (because we have reciprocal, also multiply)
- Split a string into n parts
- Split a string by another string

Because of this, we can get [1](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia29rb8SWUFDElmtva2/EllBQxJZrb2tvxJZQUMSWxJZrb1DEliIsIiIsIiJd) by dividing 1234567 by itself.

We can get the range from 2 to 7 by [removing 1](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia29rb8SWUFDElmtva2/EllBQxJZrb2tvxJZQUMSWa29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29QxJZvIiwiIiwiIl0=) although this seems useless for now. We can also [get 1-7](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia29rb8SWUFDElmtva2/EllBQxJZrb2tvxJZQUMSWa29rb8SWUFDElmtva2/EllBQxJbElmtvUMSWb28iLCIiLCIiXQ==).

Taking a step back, we can stringify 1/1234567 by [stripping
`/`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29QUCIsIiIsIiJd). We can [get `1/`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29QUGtva2/EllBQxJZvIiwiIiwiIl0=) with this although it doesn't seem to help much right now.

#### List trickery

For reasons that I don't quite understand, we can get 7654321 with something like [this](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia29rb8SWb1DEliIsIiIsIiJd). In general, we can reverse a string/number by [calling `P`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwiYDEvMTIzNDU2N2Awd1AiLCIiLCIiXQ==) with it and `[0]`. This will prove *very* helpful.

Taking a step back to numbers, we can get `234567` with [what we already have](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29QUGtva2/EllBQxJZrb2tvxJZQUMSWa29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29QxJZva29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29Qb8SWIiwiIiwiIl0=).

For some reason, stripping a string from certain types of lists seems to return (wrapped) the first item of said list. But how do we get that item?

I'm not sure yet, but using some [very confusing stuff](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia29rb8SWUFDElmtva2/EllBQxJZrb2tvxJZQUMSWa29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29QxJZva29rb8SWUFDElmtva2/EllBQxJbElmtvUMSWa29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29QUMSWa29rb8SWUFDElmtva2/EllBQxJbElmtvUMSWxJYiLCIiLCIiXQ==) lets us get the singleton list containing 2.

Removing that from [2..7] yields [7...3](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia29rb8SWUFDElmtva2/EllBQxJZrb2tvxJZQUMSWa29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29QxJZva29rb8SWUFDElmtva2/EllBQxJZrb2tvxJZQUMSWa29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29QxJZva29rb8SWUFDElmtva2/EllBQxJbElmtvUMSWa29rb8SWUFDElsSWa29QUMSWa29rb8SWUFDElmtva2/EllBQxJbElmtvUMSWxJZQIiwiIiwiIl0=). We can repeat these techniques to get every element of [2...7] in a singleton list.

Since we can simulate multiplication with use of division and reciprocals, we can finally get the elusive [8](https://link.rf.gd/auyaj) and [9](https://link.rf.gd/511rd)!

#### Printable ASCII

By removing both of these + the octal digits from printable ASCII, we can get [something usable?](https://link.rf.gd/5akzz)

Vyxal's split into pieces builtin doesn't actually give you the right amount of strings. Instead, it tries to make the strings all equal in length.

We can [split](https://link.rf.gd/v7g09) this into 64 pieces, but our trick to get the first character doesn't work since it's wrapped in a list...

And anyway, executing a list produces a horrific mess...

However, there's another way we can get numbers! By removing select digits (in lists) from `01234567` we can get quite a few numbers, including all the digits as individual numbers. We can construct [56](https://link.rf.gd/6ajze) with this method.

Using this method, we can split the string into 56 pieces instead of 64, cutting this down into a much more manageable result, with [a single unnested list](https://link.rf.gd/qajng).

This can be [represented](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwiNTZrUGtkby8iLCIiLCIiXQ==) with a much shorter piece of code.

So, we can get the first item of a list of strings as a singleton list, and we can strip a singleton list from a string to yield a string, and we can split a string into a list.

#### Letters

By [stripping `/` to get the first item](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwiNTZrUGtkby9cXC9QIiwiIiwiIl0=), we can get `["a"]`. Then we can get [`["b"]`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwiNjdrUGtkby82N2tQa2RvL1xcL1BQIiwiIiwiIl0=).

We can remove `a` from the [string form of printable ascii](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXVCIsIiIsImtQa2RvNjdrUGtkby9cXC9QUCIsIiIsIiJd) (and reverse it as a side effect, but that's easily fixable). We can then [remove `b`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwia1BrZG82N2tQa2RvL1xcL1BQNjdrUGtkby82N2tQa2RvL1xcL1BQUCIsIiIsIiJd). You can probably see where this is going, can't you.

With this method, we can [get `c` in a list](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwiNTZrUGtkbzY3a1BrZG8vXFwvUFA2N2tQa2RvLzY3a1BrZG8vXFwvUFBQL1xcL1AiLCIiLCIiXQ==), remove abc, get d, remove abcd, etc. The cost for this method grows exponentiially, but it works.

Then, we can get the string with n characters removed, and remove it from the string with (n-1) characters removed, leaving just the character itself.

*Finally*, we can evaluate this and execute arbitrary ASCII characters.

#### Scoring individual letters

Whew, that was a lot of work. Now let's put it all together.

The overhead for splitting a string into a character list is 941 (56) + 14 (division) = 955 bytes.

The overhead for getting the first character of a string as a singleton list is 955 + 3 = 958 bytes (referred to as `head`)

The overhead for removing a character and then de-reversing the string is only six bytes - `PkoĖoP`. (referred to as `strip`)

The overhead each time we push printable ascii - digits is 2052 bytes (referred to as `ascii`). The overhead for pushing this as a character list is 3007 bytes.

Then, we can generate each character of ascii in sequence by removing all the previous ones and `head`ing. For example, to get `b` we remove `a` from `ascii` and `head`.

- `a` as a singleton list costs 1 ascii + 1 head = 3010 bytes.
- `b` as a singleton list costs 2 ascii + 2 head + 1 strip = 6026 bytes.
- `c` as a singleton list costs 4 ascii + 4 head + 3 strip = 12058 bytes.

Can you see the pattern? The formula is \$2^n\text{ascii} + 2^n\text{head} + (2^n - 1)\text{strip} = 3016 * 2^n - 6\$ for a 0-indexed n representing the position.

#### Putting it all together

To get say `a` as a single character, we need the overhead for getting `b` as a singleton list, minus one head , and the overhead for getting `a` as a singleton list, minus one head. We also need a single `o`.

With this, we can take the string `bcdef...` used to get `b` before it is `head`ed, do the same with the string `abcdef...`, and remove the former from the latter leaving only `a`.

So, we need 3 ascii, 1 head, 1 strip and a single `o` = 7121 bytes to get the single character `a`. [Simpler version](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwiI2tQa2RvIDU2L1xcL1AgUGtvxJZvUFxua1BrZG9cbmtQa2RvXG5rUGtkbyA1Ni9cXC9QIFBrb8SWb1AgbyIsIiIsIiJd).

For `b`, we need 6 ascii + 4 head + 4 strip + `o` = 16169 bytes. [Simpler version](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJXIiwiIiwiI2tQa2RvIDU2L1xcL1AgUGtvxJZvUFxua1BrZG9cbmtQa2RvIDU2L1xcL1AgUGtvxJZvUFxuXG5rUGtkb1xua1BrZG8gNTYvXFwvUCBQa2/Elm9QXG5rUGtkb1xua1BrZG8gNTYvXFwvUCBQa2/Elm9QXG41Ni9cXC9QXG5Qa2/Elm9QXG5vIiwiIiwiIl0=).

The formula *here* is \$(2^n + 2^{n+1})\text{ascii} + (2^n + 2^{n+1} - 2)\text{head} + (2^n + 2^{n+1} - 2)\text{strip} = 3016(2^n + 2^{n+1}) - 1927\$.

What we're interested in are the characters `C` and `+`. I've made a [calculator](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrUGtkbyDhuJ8gOuKAulwiReKIkSAzMDE2ICogMTkyNyAtIiwiIiwiQyJd) for the overhead of a single printable ASCII character, and for `C` it spits out `2428804003961`. For `+` it gives `41726535094731005753465`. Of course, we must increment these due to the need to evaluate them.

Because I'm lazy, to create a certain character we're going to go `1 1+ 1+ 1+ ...C`. This has a total cost of \$41726535094731005753495 * (\text{ord}(c) - 1) + 2428804003991 \$. [calculator](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJDIOKAuSA0MTcyNjUzNTA5NDczMTAwNTc1MzQ5NCAqIDI0Mjg4MDQwMDM5OTAgKyIsIiIsIuKIkSJd).

Finally, we need to get this over *all* characters in the Vyxal codepage except the four we're using. We need 251 more `+` to concatenate it all together, and we're done!

The final size of the program is 37,775,866,751,962,486,187,362,186,532 bytes, or 37 yottabytes.

Answer (score 6):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Esoteric_Language), Score: 47, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207573#207573)

Let's throw my own language into the ring.

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-.ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
```

My solution:

> `{32}{15}0ɑbesχue1søɒ{65}{32}0ɑbesχue1søɒ`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207573/81278), your well-documented esolangs page was your own downfall...

Comment: aaa well that goes to show that documentation is good

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), Score 74, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208935/56656)

```hs
	
 !"#$%&()*+/0123456789:?;@BEDAFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^_`bcdefgjkloqsvwxyz
```

I've changed this one up quite a bit from my last Haskell answer.  The basics are somewhat similar:

- Hard to apply functions due to missing whitespace, `()` and `$`.
- No line delimiters so program must be on one line

This time I've given you some new characters to play with.  Along most the characters from the last version you also get

```hs
uCh>{}~
```

The only character's I've taken away are `:`, which was already disallowed in the hard version, and tab, which neither me or the cracker used in the first place.

So how is this harder than those versions?  Well this time the output is not possible in whole or in part with `print`, you will need to use `putChar`.  Which you will find much less coöperative.

## Intended solution, 829 bytes

```hs
main|[ih,a,i,n,p,u,t,h,r,mm,ma,mi,mn,mp,mu,mt,mC,mh,mr,am,aa,ai,an,ap,au,at,aC,ah,ar,im,ia,ii,ip,iu,it,iC,m,ir,nm,na,ni,nn,np,nu,nt,nC]<-['-',','..],[m,a,mat,i,n,p,u,t,h,r,mm,ma,mi,mn,mp,mu,mt,mC,mh,mr,am,aa,ai,an,ap,au,at,aC,ah,ar,im,ia,ii,ip,iu,it,iC,ih,ir,nm,na,ni,nn,np,nu,nt,nC,nh,nr,pm,pa,pi,pn,pp,pu,pt,pC,ph,pr,um,ua,ui,un,up,uu,ut,uC,uh,ur,tm,ta,ti,tn,tp,tu,tt,tC,th,tr,hm,ha,hi,hn,hp,hu,ht,hC,hh,hr,rm,ra,ri,rn,rp,ru,rt,rC,rh,rr,mmm,mma,mmi,mmn,mmp,mmu,mmt,mmC,mmh,mmr,mam,maa,mai,man,map,mau]<-map{--}putChar[m..'{']=m>>a>>an>>ap>>au>>at>>aC>>ah>>ar>>ia>>ii>>ip>>iu>>ir>>nm>>na>>ni>>nn>>np>>nu>>nt>>nC>>nh>>nr>>pm>>pu>>pa>>pt>>ph>>ua>>um>>pC>>ui>>un>>up>>uu>>ut>>uC>>uh>>ur>>tm>>ta>>ti>>tn>>tp>>tu>>tt>>tC>>th>>tr>>hm>>ha>>hi>>hp>>ht>>hC>>hh>>rm>>ra>>ri>>rn>>rp>>ru>>rh>>rr>>mmm>>mmn>>mmu>>mmC>>mam>>maa>>mai>>man>>map
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZBBbiNRCESP403ZJ0i8@cewvGAxEigBIQZWyZzdKQ6Q5agb1KJe0f@Xyt@PP5@fr5eLxffDFAJDIDFoKArucIEbPOAJH3jDD1zhBXGIQAwSkIQMpCEHwkUFcxj3GSxhA2sYjbBCOEIQ/FUgEjGIRpzn2/VxuV7A53Z74sHt/Hv/7yPx2r@fCaGIQjpSkIbkURI5yEYepCIL4xjBGCYwPOlgGnMwiim0owVt6EAnmhdp9EEruqAOFahBA5rQgfKeB6rQQjlKUIYKVKIG1aiDYhIbBbPYMDaNjWPz2EA2kY1kM2EoLpvZhkmOwTiTcRnmza@v6/VfTh@Vevjtdvm6PN/9fhe@wUrWsJp1WMqq@92om7GoG3XjLGgLzoPzoDeoBbWgN@gNeoNckkvOk2xSS86H37NzckP/0D/0D7khMztfjv4m1@SbXJNrck2uyTW5JtfklJySU3JKRqkrdaVe1IpaUSvuKOrFHbUavYx2W2ybbfQxxm2yzbatKvl6/QA)

My intended solution uses the fact that `{--}`, that is opening and closing a comment, separates tokens, so it can be used as a substitute for space.

Although it seems unlikely anyone might ever realize this fact, it seems near impossible to construct a cop that *requires* this fact, so after two failed cops I am giving up that attempt.  Good job to both the robbers here.

Comment: What is preventing the use of `print`? The characters are still available (set("print")<=set("main")|set("putChar"))

Comment: @ManfP The actual output can't be produced in whole or in part by print (without adding new `Show` instances).  This is because print adds a trailing newline and the only newline in the output is the second character.  No native haskell object has a `show` that produces a single tab or the empty string to my knowledge.

Comment: Oh right! Totally missed that, was just looking at the character diff, not the actual output

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208935/69655)

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript, score: 83, [cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207665)

<sup>(the crack is not executable like `/path/to/interpreter file.js`, unlike my solution, but I don't think that matters a lot)</sup>
I only know one Javascript implementation where my intended solution works.

```
!"#$%&'()*,-./0123456789:;=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

In this implementation, only five distinct characters are sufficient to represent any Javascript code. I removed some more characters to (try to) avoid giving away the answer.

The solution should be a full program, executable like this:

```
$ /path/to/interpreter file.js
```

I solved this by modifying `aemkei/jsfuck` on GitHub, until it was able to encode JSFuck code using the 5 characters `[]+|>`. My solution was produced by encoding `console.log("the string")` in JSFuck (via jscrew.it so that I do not run out of both RAM and HDD space), and then encoding the JSFuck using the modified JSFuck generator. My solution is 46 megabytes of code, its sha256sum is `d0c72f380b1623f9bff06fbed03b1ecd9c7fc012c9cc1ac9d758c9a317ad6855`, and it is *very* slow; if anybody is interested I can try to upload it somewhere.

Comment: Are [these](https://syllab.fr/projets/experiments/xcharsjs/5chars.pipeline.html) the five characters you're talking about?

Comment: I did not know that somebody tried to use these 5 characters before. The crack doesn't work in the implementation I'm using (it's not Babel), and the link on that site seems to be dead. I'll try to configure Babel to test this locally.

Comment: I tested it with Babel with the pipeline operator plugin. I get a syntax error that is somehow related to `99u111u110u115u111u108u101u46u108u111u103u40u34u33u92u34u35u36u37u38u39u40u41u42u44u45u46u47u48u49u50u51u52u53u54u55u56u57u58u59u61u65u66u67u68u69u70u71u72u73u74u75u76u77u78u79u80u81u82u83u84u85u86u87u88u89u90u92u94u95u96u97u98u99u100u101u102u103u104u105u106u107u108u109u110u111u112u113u114u115u116u117u118u119u120u121u122u34u41".split([[undefined[[undefinedundefined+[undefinedundefined[+[undefinedundefined[+[undefinedundefined`.

Comment: Ok then. I have no idea what else it could be, then.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think, since you listed just `Javascript` as the lang name (without specifying an implementation) then a crack that works in another JavaScript interpreter is fine: "Robbers solutions need only work in one implementation of the given language"?

Comment: @DomHastings It does not seem to work in Babel (it produces the scary syntax error mentioned above).

Comment: I could make a solution withour using a generator, but then I would manually have to make every single character. Maybe a converter from JSFuck to pipeline five would be good. I think all you'd have to do is change (thing) into [thing][+[]] and change function(thing) to thing|>function.

Comment: For reference, the allowed characters from ASCII 33-126 are `+<>?@[]{|}~`.

Comment: I used the [Babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator.html) with the auto-generator, but it has an unexpected token and there's absolutely no way I'm going to debug that.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207665/42091)

Comment: FYI after cloning my repository you can run `npx babel-node index.js`. So yes it is executable as you specify.

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), score: 71 (safe)

```
AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz
⁢{@[0 & ], \" <-> (.|), +*/, 123456789[]}
```

There are 4 characters preceding the `{` on the second line: invisible times (`U+2062`) followed by 3 private use characters (`U+F39E`, `U+F765`, `U+F76D`), in ascending order.

---

#### My solution

The exclusions of `[]`, `@`, `/`, and `\[InvisibleApply]` mean that, apart from special forms, only the infix `~ ~` can be used to apply functions.

In order to allow application of functions with a number of arguments other than 2, we need a way to generate `Sequence`s. Defining one of Mathematica’s built-in undefined bracketing operators allows us to do this:

```
〈$___〉:=$
```

Now, `〈〉` is a `Sequence[]`. As commas (and `\[InvisibleComma]`) are not permitted, we also define

```
$_·$$___=〈〉~$~$$
```

which allows us to apply an arbitrary head to an arbitrarily long list of arguments, without commas.

Now, to generate heads to apply. Note that `Names` is permitted. `Names·__` generates a list of names we can index into, and we can generate positive numbers with sufficient abuse of `π`/`Pi`, `√` (`Sqrt`), `⌊ ⌋` (`Floor`), `⌈ ⌉` (`Ceiling`), `^` (`Power`), and juxtaposition, using `〈 〉` as parentheses, for multiplication.

There’s one last thing: values returned from `Names` are `String`s, not `Symbol`s. Applying `Symbol` to a string returns a symbol with that name, though, and every symbol has the head `Symbol`. We can extract it by taking its 0th part. While the operations we used earlier can’t generate 0, `'` (`Derivative`) can (As an aside, my version of Mathematica evaluates `N'` to `1&`, but TIO’s evaluates the same expression to `0&`). For the sake of convenience, again:

```
±$_:=〈Names·__〉〚$〛;∓$_:=N〚N''·〈〉〛·±$
```

(We actually didn’t need `·`: we can build arbitrarily long expressions  with `#1~〈〉〚N''〛~#2~〈〉〚N''〛~...~head~#k`, but `·` is much nicer to look at)

and we can put the parts together to make:

```
〈$___〉:=$;$_·$$___=〈〉~$~$$;±$_:=〈Names·__〉〚$〛;∓$_:=N〚N''·〈〉〛·±$;$=〈∓〈⌊〈√〈⌊π⌋^π〉〉〈〈〈π〉π〉^⌊π⌋〉⌋〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌈〈π〉〈π^〈π〉〉⌉〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌊〈π〉⌈π^π⌉⌋〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌈〈π〉〈⌊π⌋^π〉⌉〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌊π⌋⌈π^π⌉〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌈〈π〉⌈π^π⌉⌉〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌊〈π〉⌈π^π⌉⌋〉〉〉;∓〈〈⌈⌈π⌉^π⌉〉〈⌈〈√π〉〈π^〈π〉〉⌉〉〉·$·〈∓〈⌊〈⌈π⌉^π〉〈⌊〈√π〉〈⌊π^〈π〉⌋〉⌋〉⌋〉·∓〈⌊〈⌈π^π⌉^〈√π〉〉〈⌈π⌉〈√⌊π⌋〉〉⌋〉·∓〈⌊〈⌊〈π〉〈⌊π⌋^π〉⌋〉^√⌊π⌋⌋〉〉;∓〈⌈〈π^⌊π⌋〉〈⌈〈π〉〈⌈π⌉^⌊π⌋〉⌉〉⌉〉·$·〈∓〈⌊〈√〈⌊π⌋^π〉〉〈〈〈π〉π〉^⌊π⌋〉⌋〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√〈〈π〉⌈π⌉〉〉^〈⌊π⌋^√⌊π⌋〉⌉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈⌈π⌉^〈√π〉〉〈〈⌊π^〈π〉⌋〉^√⌊π⌋〉⌉〉·〈〈∓〈⌈⌈π⌉〈〈〈π〉π〉^√⌊π⌋〉⌉〉·〈〉〉〚;;;;〈√⌈π⌉〉〛〉〉·〈∓〈⌈⌈π⌉〈〈〈π〉π〉^√⌊π⌋〉⌉〉·〈〉〉〚〈√⌈π⌉〉;;;;〈√⌈π⌉〉〛〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌈〈π〉π⌉〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌊〈〈π〉〈〈π〉⌊π⌋〉〉〈⌈〈π^⌊π⌋〉〈⌊〈π〉π⌋〉⌉〉⌋〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌊〈π〉π〈⌈〈√⌈π⌉〉〈⌈π⌈π⌉⌉^π〉⌉〉⌋〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈〈〈⌊〈π〉π⌋〉〈⌊π^⌊π⌋⌋〉〉〈⌈〈√⌊π⌋〉^〈〈π〉π〉⌉〉〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌊π^⌈π⌉⌋⌊〈π^⌈π⌉〉〈⌊π⌋^√⌊π⌋〉⌋〉〉·〈∓〈⌊〈√〈⌈π^⌊π⌋⌉〉〉〈⌈〈π^〈π〉〉^〈√π〉⌉〉⌋〉·〈〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌈π⌉^⌊π⌋〉〉·〈N''〉〉·〈∓〈⌊〈⌊π⌋〈√π〉〉^〈⌊π⌋〈√⌊π⌋〉〉⌋〉·〈∓〈⌊〈√〈⌊π⌋^π〉〉〈〈〈π〉π〉^⌊π⌋〉⌋〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌈〈π〉〈⌊〈π〉〈〈π〉⌊π⌋〉⌋〉⌉〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌈√〈〈〈π〉⌊π⌋〉^π〉⌉〉〉〉·〈∓〈⌊〈√〈⌊π⌋^π〉〉〈〈〈π〉π〉^⌊π⌋〉⌋〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌈π⌉〈⌈〈π〉π⌉〉〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌊⌈π⌉〈⌈π⌉^〈√π〉〉⌋〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌈π⌉〈⌊π^⌊π⌋⌋〉〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌈〈π〉⌈π⌈π⌉⌉⌉〉〉〉〉·〈∓〈⌊〈√〈⌊π⌋^π〉〉〈〈〈π〉π〉^⌊π⌋〉⌋〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌊〈√⌈π⌉〉^〈〈π〉〈√⌊π⌋〉〉⌋〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌈〈π^⌊π⌋〉〈√〈√π〉〉⌉〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈√√⌊π⌋〉〈〈√π〉^⌈π⌈π⌉⌉〉⌉〉·〈⌊〈√π〉〈⌊π⌋^⌊π⌋〉⌋〉〉〉·〈〈∓〈⌊〈√〈⌊π⌋^π〉〉〈〈〈π〉π〉^⌊π⌋〉⌋〉·〈〈∓〈⌊〈√〈⌈π⌉^π〉〉〈〈⌊π⌋^π〉^√⌊π⌋〉⌋〉·∓〈〈⌈π^⌈π⌉⌉〉〈⌊〈⌈〈π〉π⌉〉^〈√π〉⌋〉〉〉·〈∓〈⌈〈〈π〉〈√⌊π⌋〉〉〈〈⌊π⌋^π〉〈⌊π⌋^⌊π⌋〉〉⌉〉·〈⌊〈π〉π⌋〉〉〉〉·〈〉〉〉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VdLbsMgEL0MUu5QK1fIEbCsKlK7yKpZR1lik1126QnMrivvfYHewTmIy8fADAZXVY2aRojYMLxhhpk3@FAdX/aH6vj6XI3jcGlJWZbDRTxtSUHKviPqfSvH5diJnAgp@g9SPqmRXXXYv/WdFr@fb@R@fi8GdlWzO/m@22z6ziyUM30n1xVEI7GrHm708808f56HC6eqF7q1pukB3VErpKdVb9AnMDaBKTwg15phi8DUg@5q3YTpp30yq1D/U/8mrPD6OhuvRcrQSYxn0gYtDJ2ezcJpHTAvt21A1Z@cm2yFVWb0GRxgv9/GtxFH0OYbs9bjCZhM6HABHg96CRnimc1RhCOAMputwGMJsGYhyrh2LsThgcOY9QU@Ghy6zG4WCMEzivhsbabxq7yHhFnu1YQeq6No3pyZ76MnuQCLkP3BzUxMAwhD54X8WUudeZLI4/n0G00zLT9TvR5x5GSnBsULeMTplI7/Bu4SBjzPzXCqg3HPMIshEFxMcm2tTXnEZUtALtgAp5aG0erOP1MhpH6aWwNo6NEEdcScCYmNIcPrWES56oKZpg6IbuX0ilC1mZM3xJRNThgSIp3NJKrRP7ljhpUyQgk869WMuToWUU6XM@LxPOtLUIzRM1Ek1Bov4tnu8l5zgvNy37GRoHfzw0dKM6tkNKjOcWbJ59Gw2rNbGEVZ7yXBd4OuPpHSEykQ65xtsqCBGwW8Djs10SLpP0dcVcTm@6@ekCdw8i4l0mKwtBF/JFy7cOfi84yyb@P4BQ)

On the current version of Mathematica on TIO, this is equivalent to

```
$= StringJoin[FromCharacterCode[115], FromCharacterCode[116], FromCharacterCode[100], FromCharacterCode[111], FromCharacterCode[117], FromCharacterCode[116]]; (* "stdout" *)
WriteString[$, StringJoin[Riffle[ToUpperCase[Alphabet[]〚;;;;2〛], Alphabet[]〚2;;;;2〛]], FromCharacterCode[10], FromCharacterCode[8290], FromCharacterCode[62366], FromCharacterCode[63333], FromCharacterCode[63341], List[FromCharacterCode[64][N''], TwoWayRule[StringJoin[FromCharacterCode[92], FromCharacterCode[34]], StringJoin[FromCharacterCode[40], FromCharacterCode[46], FromCharacterCode[124], FromCharacterCode[41]]], StringJoin[FromCharacterCode[43], FromCharacterCode[42], FromCharacterCode[47]], StringJoin[Map[ToString][Range[9]]][]]]
```

This could also just be put together with `FromCharacterCode` alone. `WriteString` is required here to suppress the trailing newline, and to get special characters to print verbatim instead of as `\[name]` (and yes, `$Output` would have been much shorter to generate than `"stdout"`).

Comment: Are Mathematica-specific fancy characters (that keep getting converted to `\[Something]`) allowed?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate yes.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), Score 60, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207591/86301)

```
";<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSVWXYZ[\\]^_`abeghjklmqrsvwxyz{|}~"
```

Note that your output cannot have an initial `[1]` (as would be given by default printing). You cannot use `cat` because of the `a`, and you cannot use `write` because of the `w`.

Cracked by Giuseppe.

My solution:

> `dput(intToUtf8(c(59:83,86:98,101,103:104,106:109,113:115,118:126)))`

Comment: Oh good, you left us with `'()` at least...

Comment: [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207591/67312)

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, Score: 7, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207613/6828)

```
p<.$a1s
```

Previous crack wasn't the intended one, so trying to head it off with another character.

Comment: ...I'm going to have a long night ahead of me.

Comment: Not sure if this is intended either... https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207613/9365

Comment: ...Nope, curses!

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), Score: 14, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207668/81203)

```
Echo@Dt[0 & ]
```

Comment: Can we output via `SendMail`? (this is the only acceptable way to output I found so far)

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate standard output

Comment: It seems like that should maybe count as a [file](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2453/96155)? I don't think output as email was explicitly brought up in there, but the idea of output as email is so hilarious to me that I really want it to be legal.

Comment: @att by standard output, do you mean the output which is shown with `-print` (which is also the output shown as `Out[1]` in documentation examples like [these](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html))?

Comment: @EthanChapman no additional flags needed

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207668/32372)

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), score 6 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207608/96155))

```
"aces'
```

This will more than likely get cracked, but I couldn't quite manage to make it harder. Hopefully this is difficult enough that it remains open for a little while.

Update: 5 hours, I'll take it. My solution:

> `` 1`{15-}%135`{48+}%1`{66+}%1`{10-}% ``

Comment: I'd try, but I don't know CJam. It seems some things are missing from the PDF. Like the double quotes. Sure, that might be obvious, but I don't know what else is missing.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207608/92069)

Comment: @PkmnQ If you're referring to the PDF [here](http://foldr.moe/cjam.pdf), that's only meant as a cheatsheet. I use that PDF for the basics but defer to [the wiki on the Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/) (which I thought I linked, sorry) for detailed documentation.

Comment: @Ethan Chapman Well, time for me to learn CJam and use it for a few weeks, then change to another golfing language.

Answer (score 5):

## BBC Basic II, Score: 2, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207804#207804)

One more example in a "non-golfing" language:

> VP

(I tested my program on an Acorn BBC model B emulator and on an Acorn Archimedes emulator. However, according to the BBC Basic manual I found in the internet, it should work on "modern" BBC Basic versions for the PC, too.)

---

My solution:

The solution in the [crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207804#207804) directly writes to the display memory of the BBC model B. This means that the solution would not work on an Archimedes, an x86-based machine or on a second CPU (tube) of a BBC.

My solution uses a special feature of BBC Basic:

> On 6502-based computers (like the BBC), the `CALL` command calls some assembly function located at a certain address. The value in the variable `A%` is written to the `A` register before calling the function.
>
>  On non-6502 systems (ARM or x86), the `CALL` command normally works in a similar way; however, if the parameter is the address of an operating system routine of the 6502 operating system, the BASIC does not interpret the argument as address of an ARM or x86 assembly language routine. Instead, the `CALL` command will more or less emulate a call to the OS of a 6502-based computer for such arguments.
>
>  For this reason `CALL 65518` will always write the byte represented by the value in variable `A%` to the "standard output" - even on ARM-based computers where `65518` is not a valid code address!

Using this feature, the solution is quite simple:

> `10 A%=80`
>  `20 CALL 65518`
>  `30 A%=86`
>  `40 CALL 65518`

Comment: I've never touched any assembly in my life and I'm feeling like that's what I need to do here... Slowly making progress though!

Comment: @DomHastings Maybe. You will see when the answer is cracked or one week is over. However, you should keep in mind that assembly language differs on different CPU types: I wrote in my comment that my program works on the BBC (6502 CPU), on the Archimedes (ARM CPU) and with a high probability on the PC (x86 CPU), too.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207804#207804).

Comment: Thankyou very much for this challenge!  I haven't written BBC BASIC for many years, and this was a lot of nostagic fun!

Answer (score 5):

## Befunge 93 (FBBI), score 15 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207639))

```
,0123456789"~@!
```

Take two. Thanks to Befunge's limited instruction set, I expect you'll find out what I think is the only remaining way to get a non-0 value on the stack, but I don't expect you to enjoy using it. That said, it wasn't as bad as I was hoping. It should be possible to remove `:` and maybe some others too, but I'm not going to code it to verify by hand.

Good crack, I'll post my solution here (as a TIO link, because the <pre> block didn't like it), which is along the same lines but more brute-forcey. It takes a `+` from the top left with `g` whenever it needs a new character, does some math to make that a `,`, and does a little more math to place it. Then it takes a copy of that comma and turns it into whatever character it needs, then rinses and repeats.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##rZS9DoMgFEZ3n4K5hDjYDpKm6Xs0LiRqujQu9fUpoPwIAlcLAwNczne4JLB@@H7GnrQNGRh7c45HSmtMxUQnOWE8VzPyx7162DoqiqawyquRVaJOMSPUxNnl9HpeATKEKEeTjAuUFeVZovVTS1Bqku3SrfMJfjJjm@LcY1k/npTN8xOdu607Z0PzyWG2e2O9@Vc@yGLPw@1DQROQzb7PpjemopAT2CzmZuwwvUgEKSkG8oqbKTf5mLWaSdmmwf1ShspRNE//haS04yHPtKn/RxR/79D7yfmrRTfUoGv3Aw)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207639/81278)

Comment: I very much did not enjoy using it :)

Comment: By the way, it looks like your solution uses an `@`, although it shouldn't be too hard to change to self-write that. Nice answer!

Comment: Oops, I meant to specify `&` in the challenge but accidentally put `@` instead. It shouldn't be hard to self-write, though, no. Fortunately the `&` loophole didn't come up, so it's no big deal. If I post another one with even more characters removed, I'll make sure to fix that.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), Score=30, safe

```r
t <-
"$&0123456789=?[\\^`lv{|"
```

A trickier version of my [previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207696/86301), which Dominic van Essen [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207700/86301) in a few hours. Without `t` you cannot easily use `get` or `cat`, and without `l` you cannot use `ls`, `eval`, `do.call` or `el`.

Hopefully this time you will have to come closer to my intended solution!

---

Solution :

The key is to use the function `dump` to print. This function produces a text representation of objects, i.e. R code to recreate the objects. All we need to do is assign to `t` the character string `"$&0123456789=?[\\^lv{|"`, and then use `dump('t','')`.

This requires two tricks. First, to create strings, we shall use `rawToChar(as.raw(NNN))` where `NNN` is the ASCII code of the characters. Such integers can be created with `T+T+T+...+T`. Second, since we cannot assign using `=`, `<-` or `->`, we use the function `assign`. Conveniently, this requires the object name to be given as a string, so we can also define the object name with `rawToChar(as.raw(NNN))`.

In order to make the solution more readable, I have added spaces and newlines, and I have written the integers directly rather than as `T+T+T+...+T`. The TIO gives the complete solution.

```r
assign(rawToChar(as.raw(116)), rawToChar(as.raw(c(36, 38, 48:57, 61, 63, 91, 92, 94, 96, 108, 118, 123, 124))))
dump(rawToChar(as.raw(116)), '')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P7G4ODM9T6MosTwk3zkjsUgjsVgPyNEwNDTT1NTBEE7W0AjRhkNNLS0QV1MHmyCIrYOmHJkHFtG00kAVw6IG0wJ0JVBlxKmCuAtThihTCZpNmmrydKDogqmFBjtyYGFKaWMxVic9MTc3UQNLIOGSAMWbpqZ1SmluAa6Eo66u@f8/AA)

Comment: Hmm... I notice that you're suspiciously still allowing 'e' and 'a'...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I'm trying not to give too much away, it [was used against me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207591/86301) in my first challenge!

Comment: Congratulations Robin!  I got as far as```dump()```, ```assign()``` and (of course) the integers, but ```rawToChar(as.raw())``` eluded me!  Good challenge!

Comment: Congrats! `rawToChar` threw me too! I did not know about `dump`, though, good one to file away for future reference.

Comment: @Giuseppe I've just used `dump` to create a [new (shortest) R quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209082/86301). I've been sitting on this function since I discovered it 10 days ago!

Answer (score 5):

## [Mornington Crescent](https://github.com/padarom/esoterpret), Score: 5, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207764/68693)

X = `7UBES`

London's burning! A large amount of the Underground has been closed off while the authorities try to avert disaster. Amid hellfire, dare you enter... the 7UBES<sup>†</sup>?

---

As for the language definition, consider it defined by the linked interpreter (This interpreter is also used on TIO). Note that the interpreter may not fully conform to [the language specification](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Mornington_Crescent), in particular not to the [forward compatibility](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Mornington_Crescent#Forward_compatibility) clause, as the interpreter is not maintained in parallel with infrastructural projects taking place in the Underground.

---

While the lack of Upminster and Upney block the easiest ways, there are quite a few options left. My solution mostly depended on Manor House while ignoring Holland Park, in contrast to @pppery.

```
#First, place an int at Paddington, such that the string starts with our character instead of 'Paddington'
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: 67
Take Northern Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Paddington #PAD: 67
##Plan: get 120
#First, put 'Oxford Circus' on Gunnersbury
Take Circle Line to Victoria
Take Victoria Line to Oxford Circus
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take District Line to Gunnersbury
#Now, get 2
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take Piccadilly Line to Heathrow Terminals 1, 2, 3
Take Piccadilly Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Parsons Green
Take District Line to Parsons Green
#Get 'x...'
Take District Line to Gunnersbury #ACC: 'Ox'
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take Piccadilly Line to Turnpike Lane
Take Piccadilly Line to Turnpike Lane
#Get 120
Take Piccadilly Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Tottenham Court Road
Take Central Line to Tottenham Court Road
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: 120
#Move to PR
Take Northern Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Metropolitan Line to Preston Road #PR: 120
#get 65
Take Metropolitan Line to Amersham
Take Metropolitan Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
#get '7'
Take Metropolitan Line to Preston Road #ACC:55 PR:65
Take Metropolitan Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Moorgate
Take Northern Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Paddington #PAD: '7' 
##Plan: get 85
#get 4
Take District Line to Parsons Green #int from Pad triggers swap
Take District Line to Parsons Green #ACC: 3
Take District Line to Wimbledon #Wi: 3
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take Piccadilly Line to Heathrow Terminal 4
Take Piccadilly Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Parsons Green #ACC: 4
#put 4 at MH
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take Piccadilly Line to Manor House
#get 81
Take Piccadilly Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Queensway
Take Central Line to Tottenham Court Road
Take Central Line to Tottenham Court Road
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: 81
# ~~(81 | 4) == 85
Take Northern Line to Tottenham Court Road
Take Central Line to Tottenham Court Road
Take Central Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Holborn
Take Piccadilly Line to Manor House #ACC: ~85, nor: 81
Take Piccadilly Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Notting Hill Gate
Take Central Line to Notting Hill Gate #ACC: 85
#get 'U'
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: 'U'
#concat 'U'
Take Northern Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington #PAD: '7U'
##Plan: Get 66
#get 32
Take District Line to Parsons Green #ACC: 7
Take District Line to Gunnersbury #Gu: 7
Take District Line to Richmond #Ri: 2
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take Piccadilly Line to Covent Garden
Take Piccadilly Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Gunnersbury #ACC: 'Covent '
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take Piccadilly Line to Turnpike Lane
Take Piccadilly Line to Turnpike Lane
Take Piccadilly Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Tottenham Court Road
Take Central Line to Tottenham Court Road
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross #ACC: 32
#Get 64
Take Northern Line to Moorgate
Take Northern Line to Moorgate
Take Metropolitan Line to Chalfont & Latimer
Take Metropolitan Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Temple
Take District Line to Richmond #ACC: 2
Take District Line to Temple
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Metropolitan Line to Chalfont & Latimer #ACC: 64, tim: 2
# ~~(64 | 2) == 66
Take Metropolitan Line to Rayners Lane
Take Metropolitan Line to Chalfont & Latimer
Take Metropolitan Line to Rayners Lane
Take Metropolitan Line to Rayners Lane
Take Piccadilly Line to Oakwood
Take Piccadilly Line to Manor House
Take Piccadilly Line to Oakwood #Oak: 81
Take Piccadilly Line to Manor House
Take Piccadilly Line to Rayners Lane
Take Piccadilly Line to Manor House #ACC: ~66, nor: 64
Take Piccadilly Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Notting Hill Gate
Take Central Line to Notting Hill Gate #ACC: 66
#get 'B'
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
#concat 'B'
Take Northern Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington #PAD: '7UB'
##Plan: get 69
#Get 5
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take Piccadilly Line to Heathrow Terminal 5
Take Piccadilly Line to Acton Town
Take Piccadilly Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Parsons Green #ACC: 5
# ~~(64 | 5) == 69
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take Piccadilly Line to Manor House #ACC: ~69, nor: 5
Take Piccadilly Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Notting Hill Gate
Take Central Line to Notting Hill Gate #ACC: 69
#get 'E'
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
#concat 'E'
Take Northern Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Paddington
Take Circle Line to Paddington #PAD: '7UBE'
##Plan: get 83
#Place 81 at nor
Take District Line to Acton Town
Take Piccadilly Line to Manor House #nor: 'B7UB'
Take Piccadilly Line to Oakwood #ACC: 81, Oak: 5
Take Piccadilly Line to Manor House #nor: 81
#get 2 == 65 % 3
Take Piccadilly Line to Acton Town
Take District Line to Wimbledon #ACC: 3
Take District Line to Temple
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Metropolitan Line to Preston Road #ACC: 2
# ~~(81 | 2) == 83
Take Metropolitan Line to Rayners Lane
Take Metropolitan Line to Rayners Lane
Take Piccadilly Line to Manor House #ACC ~83
Take Piccadilly Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Holborn
Take Central Line to Notting Hill Gate
Take Central Line to Notting Hill Gate #ACC: 83
#get 'S'
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
#concat 'S'
Take Northern Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Paddington #PAD: '7UBES'
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
```

[Try it online! (without comments)](https://tio.run/##7VjBctpADL33K3TqKTm0aT4g487AISSE8aTnxVbinaxXjHYdwtenohADiQn2YghMOcJ7K0ta6Ul2Tmy1ffRkzxNGl6D1r6@xekK4IfYZsoVrbRE8QZQpFipETM59q@b0iPhReZzBkebEYD2wr9J05kglfK8TT6zVDHz7VcK3Lw/E6b9DhVvD2WBiFf6tnWf5p4Q7hbXIbljwZA3jSs5biGk8j6Cvk0Sl2phJSemi8hnTGGLkXFtlHPw4g59ncLH2yHurGx/7gdBX7Mg66DDirjnNsxSSxrhgO9KCXSuLW7K6ZIbSA/Oik/JnZeqBMXmPNlM5RFSwhwGptCkzqMlabsQeeqYRGe3V4nxfxGB6DwtXK2lXudy2BPYJpYEnx56Nwwu1WSbea/DOZOKPzocGU7ItSin8@mINbUPZesoSi@wULlCx7gpx0I3V5Ag1qw3nGin4CriL2/gUvJEgpinpij3oLHqyJq3BbnV4Ktts@WtFlzavJgOdZDnZNLx9I3qW25Nb4hTtDuXotGYd5Jq1Aa7cGeQp5oGkaL5LAr2WfSp0wYgxHxkMq@3ls@HKsn2AAzWZFvZSLe3N5kdaRRnfqqcxUbrVxJjbgK2M1PJ2yRAc0ACD/3mCQZsr72XtGRMyhlamKuxn6z3V6fHXaa3rbKKCEF7D5Zsm7H/yLX81gD0NqFMrfUErtR9dr/wsL86/fZb/Cw)

<sub>†: Pardon me for the 1337-speak, my options are limited: each valid program in this language ends with `Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent`.</sub>

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207764/46076)

Answer (score 5):

## [Stack Cats](https://github.com/m-ender/stackcats), Score: 3, Safe

```
)*(
```

All Stack Cats programs are symmetrical, and the reflection of a command undoes the original.

As a result, every program with an even length either runs forever or does some work, then immediately undoes that work, and devolves into a `cat` program. The only way to write something else is to use an odd number of characters and let the center give structure to the rest of the code.

If you want to run the code `xyz`, the easiest approach is to use a structure like `<(zyx)*(xyz)>`, which completely skips the first half. This is boring, so I’ve made that construction impossible.

Naturally, the output is also symmetrical :)

### Solution:

```
_+!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_[!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_]_:_[_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!]_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!_!+_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTiwp/v8/XlsxfuBg9EBaPhRhbLxVfPRoOJAGYwfScu34//8B)

### Explanation:

For this explanation, `s[0]` is the top of a stack, `s[1]` is the element below `s[0]`, and a stack is written `[top, middle, bottom]`

Here's what the stack looks like after each step. I’ll use a number to represent how many `!_` / `_!` pairs are used:

```
_+       # [0, 0, 1]
62       # [62, 0, 1]
[152]    # [214, 0, 1]    
_:_      # [-214, -214, 1]
[152]    # [-366, -214, 1]
62       # [12840, -214, 1]
+_       # [-215, -214, 12840]
```

This approach is mostly built around `!_` and its reflection `_!`. `_` sets `s[0] = s[1] - s[0]`, and `!` sets `s[0]` to its bitwise negation. When `s[1]` is 0, `!_` increments the top of the stack and `_!` decrements it.

In the first half of the program, `[` moves the top element to a different stack and continues incrementing it there, then `]` moves it back. By itself, this is pointless, but those characters are important in the second half. The code increments the top of the stack 214 times (62 + 152).

In the center, `_:_`  negates the top of the stack and sets `s[1] = s[0]`. `[152]` moves the top element to its own stack, decrements it 152 times, then puts it back on the primary stack. Now that the stack has a nonzero `s[1]`, `_!` no longer decrements the top, but sets `s[0] = !(-214 - s[0])` 62 times.

Once the program ends, the stack has the values `[-215, -214, 12840]`. These are output mod 256, giving `[41, 42, 40]`, which in ASCII makes `)*(`

Answer (score 4):

## Scala, score: 2 [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207572/95792)

```
(.
```

Shouldn't be too hard to crack.

Edit: Guess I was right :/

The [code](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0oge1IgHRZ6MfAH2wmA2gg) I used:

> ```
>  object Main extends App {
>    def f: String => Unit = println _
>    this f "\u0028\u002e"
>  }
> ```

Comment: I'd crack it, but I don't know Scala.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207572/81278), unless the main method declaration can't use `(` either (it works fine in a repl).

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, score 6, [cracked by @nthistle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207581/6828)

```
p<.$a1
```

Not intended to output via error, although I also don't think it's possible to do so without a lot of other characters.

Comment: I'm not sure how you could get `p<.$a1` as a ruby error, but you're fine to say so.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207581/81278)

Answer (score 4):

## Befunge 98, Score: 4, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207607/46076)

```
=sp,
```

Trying to prove ovs' claim that "I don't think this can be made harder in Befunge" wrong. (This answer may still be too easy, but I can say for sure that it is harder than  the other one, because I've blocked both self-modifying code operators)

Intended solution:

> `"PAMI"4('+1+'o1+'r1+'<1+'+1+'ZMZZZZ@`

Comment: Are fingerprints allowed?

Comment: "You may be as specific or precise in choosing your language as you wish.". I was very un-specific about what language in the header I used, so any Befunge 98 interpreter can be used the crack this answer, regardless of what features it supports or doesn't support.

Comment: Cracked (using a fingerprint): https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207607

Comment: This can also be done with the [`ORTH`](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9X8ggJ8lcy0VAwUFDXNtRWUM8HEUUgwgZIBCs4/P8PAA) and the [`IMAP`](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XCnD09VQy0VBQ1zbUVtfzVVC3MdTWU1AvApP5YFIbRDr8/w8A) fingerprint.

Comment: The intended solution was using IMAP. (I was deliberately vague about whether fingerprints were allowed earlier in an attempt to avoid giving the fact that I used them away). Ah, well, this answer still served its purpose, because it lasted 13 hours, and the previous answer lasted less than an hour, so it was definitely harder)

Answer (score 4):

## Dotty 0.26-RC1, Score: 7 (Safe)

```
"+. p\{
```

Earlier versions may work too, like 0.25 and 0.24, but I'm not totally sure how low you can go, since Dotty's features keep changing.

Harder version, score: 8 (I still had the same solution for this, but the one above may have alternate cracks, and this doesn't allow them, hopefully.)

```
"+. p\{[
```

---

### Update

Since my answer's over a week old now, here's the solution I got (I'm sure it could be made shorter, but whatever)

```scala
object`Main`:
    @main
    def`main`=(Console`out`)write(new`String`()concat((34`toChar`)toString)concat((43`toChar`)toString)concat((46`toChar`)toString)concat((32`toChar`)toString)concat((112`toChar`)toString)concat((92`toChar`)toString)concat((123`toChar`)toString)getBytes)
```

I basically just used `concat` instead of `+`, `xx.toChar.toString` to get around the `"`, postfix and infix syntax to get around the `.`, and the backtick to get around the restriction on spaces.

A couple Dotty-specific features that helped: `@main` meant I didn't have to write `(args: Array[String])`, saving me `[`, and Dotty's new indentation-based syntax let's you use `:` instead of curly braces. Note that even though you see spaces here and in the playground, Dotty does let you use tabs.

[Try it in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/zbt7CJn8QbCR8teXPS6rqQ)

Bonus (the same thing, but no parentheses this time)

```
"+. p\{(
```

Here's my solution to it (unfortunately, the backticks were removed, because I don't know how to put code in spoilers, but imagine they were there)

> ```
>  object`Main`:
>      @main
>      def`main`=
>          val`a`=34`toChar`
>          val`b`=43`toChar`
>          val`c`=46`toChar`
>          val`d`=32`toChar`
>          val`e`=112`toChar`
>          val`f`=92`toChar`
>          val`g`=123`toChar`
>          val`h`=40`toChar`
>          val`i`=new`StringBuilder`
>          i`append`a`append`b`append`c`append`d`append`e`append`f`append`g`append`h
>          val`j`=i`toString`
>          val`k`=j`getBytes`
>          val`l`=Console`out`
>
>          l`write`k
> ```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/eJ1RfCz6TUCyva2RCQFgUg)

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), Score=23 [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207647/86301) by Robin Ryder

```
0123456789+-*/^!&|%`()$
```

This has a worse score than [Robin Ryder's currently-latest R challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207558/print-x-without-x-cops-thread/207615#207615), but if you crack this you'll probably crack his one, too.

Comment: Clearly, my challenge is easier, as I have a solution to mine but not yours. For yours, without `(), we can't even call functions!?

Comment: @RobinRyder we have `'=<>?~"` so we can reassign some functions if we are clever...

Comment: @Giuseppe Indeed! I'm so used to using backticks when reassigning functions that I had forgotten quotes worked as well. We are also allowed `[],` which should be useful.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207647/86301) (with a lot of sweat!)

Answer (score 4):

## Java, Score: 3 [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207638/95792)

```
\[;
```

This eliminates unicode literals, arrays, and semicolons

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), Score: 5, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207786/78410)

```
uvUV┼
```

Can you generate the Unicode box-drawing character `U+253C` or `⎕UCS 9532` without `⎕UCS` or `⎕AV`?

Any system variable setting (`⎕IO`, `⎕ML`, etc.) can be used. The code should work in TIO's code section, so SALT (and user command) is not available. Since there is no trailing newline in the expected output, use `⍞`-printing (which prints to STDERR).

Comment: Cracked https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207786/75429

Answer (score 4):

## Java, Score: 3 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207702#207702))

```
.\
```

Round two for this solution, fixing the previous crack. As with the original, the output from my solution was to standard error.

Comment: While I was doing research for this, I stumbled upon [this](http://wouter.coekaerts.be/2019/puzzle-no-dot-solution), which is basically almost identical -- since I'm assuming this isn't intended either, I'm going to some time looking for something better (I'm kinda close on a reflection approach).

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207702/95792). @nthistle, you really helped me!

Comment: @user Same trick I used, just in a different format; I just made my main class extend Exception, allowing me to invoke printStackTrace without a dot from its constructor. I guess I could have just reposted again blocking colons (to prevent creating an Autocloseable from a Throwable), but I think twice is enough for one solution, especially when you're that close. Good work!

...still would be interested in seeing the Reflection that nthistle was planning, though...

Comment: Not sure you can use reflection for this - I just spent half the day trying to do it, but you *have* to use dots in Java to do anything more than this

Comment: Yeah, the reflection ended up being a non-starter. The originally idea was basically to use method references (which you only need `::` to get) to something like `System.err::write` and then find a way to invoke them, but invoking method references in Java basically requires `.`, unless I could find something in the standard library that would invoke it for me (unlikely). Likewise, you can't really use reflection to even access the `err` attribute of System without using a `.` somewhere.

Comment: [Here's a similar crack](https://tio.run/##ZU/BDoIwDL37FQ2nLWJijDExnD16khvxUGYVdAyzFTkYvh23QALqu7Sv7Xtt7/jC1f3y6Ptnk@tSgdLoHByxNPBegMdYd4zsw6suL1D5rjixLc0tOwPam5PAha1bB2kImGsa1QGG2qkuoig2jdYx24biK2pHcjYb8M0CHPGJUT1Si4pE8JvoQVNFhrP1WSZ/wqe/cS79Gem@2Pjp8BhwPSTCnweWuLEGogiWIFSBVortTk5kv5HJzK0b1nSLru8/ "Java (JDK) – Try It Online") that doesn't use `AutoCloseable`, possibly closer to the original solution(?).

Comment: That's exactly what I had, just using an anonymous inner class instead of the enclosing class.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl 5, Score: 80, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207814#207814)

```
!"'*+,-0123456789:;<?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|~
```

This means that the following printable ASCII characters are permitted:

```
 #$%&()./=>[]_}
```

Inspired by Dom Hastings's challenges ([1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207618), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207673), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207698)) and my solutions ([1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207671#207671), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207688#207688), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207718#207718)).

Comment: So, I have a solution, but it relies on an implementation detail and a low-byte char, so I imagine it's not quite right... I'm going to continue just in case I can figure out a more portable way...

Comment: @DomHastings My solution only uses ASCII characters, but I'd be curious to see what you can gain with an unprintable character: I didn't find a way to make use of one until I no longer had any use for it. My solution technically uses an implementation detail, but one that works very broadly.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207814/9365), although if this isn't the intended solution, adding `\x18` to the output would give me another chance to figure out how to generate `a`!

Comment: @DomHastings Nice! Pretty different from my solution. I'm going to make another challenge that forbids `$^X`, but first I want to try and see if I can close another loophole.

Comment: @DomHastings [Here we go](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207558/print-x-without-x-cops-thread/207828#207828). In addition to forbidding some control variables with system-dependent content, I'm also trying to steer you away from constructing numbers as the length of a list. If you're stuck, start with `/` instead of `?`, it lets you do pretty interesting things, but I eventually decided that it was an unnecessary indulgence.

Answer (score 4):

## [Malbolge](https://github.com/TryItOnline/malbolge), score: 2, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208925/95679)

```
To
```

In Malbolge, the "print X" part of the challenge should be hard enough by itself.

---

Original solution:

> `('&%$#"!~}|{2V0w.R?`
>  
>  
>  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MScrPSU/9/19DXU1VRVlJsa62ptoozKBcL8j@/38A)

Comment: Cracked: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208925/94694

Answer (score 4):

## Rust, score 2 <s>32</s>, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208946/97519)

`pw`

<s>`pw?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQSTUXYZ!"#$%`</s>

Pretty challenging to output to stdout without being able to type `print` or `write`!

Rust version: `rustc 1.45.1 (c367798cf 2020-07-26)`

Comment: [Cracked your edited answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208946/48931). Not sure why you changed it, my approach wouldn't work otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.7, Score: 7, [Cracked by Ethan White](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/209878#209878)

```
(nuvwxy
```

Inspired by [Tips for restricted source in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/209734/tips-for-restricted-source-in-python).

This should block `eval` and `exec`, function calls that don't use the `__class_getitem__` trick, and most forms of output (`print`, `write`, etc.)

My solution only uses ASCII characters.

### My Solution

```py
class C:__class_getitem__=chr
class D:__class_getitem__=dir
class M:__class_getitem__=__import__
    
code = M[C[99]+C[111]+C[100]+C[101]]  # Import code
i_spect = M[C[105]+C[110]+C[115]+C[112]+C[101]+C[99]+C[116]]  # Import inspect
    
I = code.__dict__[D[code][2]]  # I = code.InteractiveInterpreter
class A:__class_getitem__=I.__call__
e = A[{}]  # Instantiate InteractiveInterpreter({})
    
class S:__class_getitem__=i_spect.getmembers.__call__
class R:__class_getitem__=S[e][28][1]  # Get the runcode method

z=C[112]+C[114]+C[105]+C[110]+C[116]+C[40]+C[34]+C[92]+C[34]+C[39]+C[40]+C[110]+C[117]+C[118]+C[119]+C[120]+C[121]+C[34]+C[41]

R[z]  # Run the constructed print statement
```

My approach was to use `code.InteractiveInterpreter().runcode()` as an alternate version of `exec`. Since I blocked `n`, I couldn't type that class or method directly, so I imported `InteractiveInterpreter` and `inspect` by constructing strings and passing them to `__import__`, then used `dir` and `inspect.getmembers` to get the `runcode` method, then passed in a string to execute.

I had a lot of fun coming up with this convoluted approach, but I didn't realize `timeit` was a much simpler version of `exec` that avoided this complexity, and there's no way to block `timeit` without also blocking `__class_getitem__`.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, Score:96 [Cracked by pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218093)

Similar to my other answer, improvements inspired by Wheat Wizard's [crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218016/56656). Still self-verifying.

Output viewed through hexdump (non-printable output makes it look incorrect on the terminal):

```
$ python3 ./test4.py | hexdump -C
00000000  09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18  |................|
00000010  19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 21  22 23 24 25 26 27 2a 2b  |.......!"#$%&'*+|
00000020  2d 2f 30 31 32 33 34 35  36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d  |-/0123456789:;<=|
00000030  3e 3f 40 41 42 43 44 45  46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d  |>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLM|
00000040  4e 4f 50 51 52 53 54 55  56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d  |NOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]|
00000050  5e 60 64 6b 70 71 76 77  78 79 7a 7b 7c 7d 7e 7f  |^`dkpqvwxyz{|}~.|
00000060
```

Original:

Script generating script:

```python
import re

filecode = "__builtins__.__getattribute__('globals')().__getitem__('__file__')"
code = "__builtins__.__getattribute__('open')(1,chr(119)).__getattribute__(str().join([chr(119),chr(114),chr(105),chr(116),chr(101)]))(str().join([b for b in (chr(u) for u in __builtins__.__getattribute__('range')(9,128)) if b not in __builtins__.__getattribute__(str().join((chr(111),chr(112),chr(101),chr(110))))(__file__,chr(114)).__getattribute__('read')()]))"

code = code.replace('__file__',filecode)
code = code.replace('[','(')
code = code.replace(']',')')

squots = re.compile("'([^']+)'")

dquots = re.compile('"([^"]+)"')


def fy(x):
    return f"str().join(chr(b) for b in {repr(tuple([ord(x) for x in x.group(1)]))})"

def replaceliterals(x):
    xx = squots.sub(fy,x)
    return dquots.sub(fy,xx)

digits= re.compile("\d+")
open(1,'w').write(digits.sub(lambda x: f"len({repr(tuple([tuple()]*int(x.group(0))))})",replaceliterals(code)))
```

[Try the result online!](https://tio.run/##7ZtBDoIwEEWv0uU0MWw8UGMNSA22BoaFp8cSjdHEaNyBfU0eC7ZvSmc@cL5om@J2mpzzY@g0xMG5yrlDrTvVPvhRa@dk0F5sdUwhyr7txVvTpN54E6KRro4iYjcG1ojNVxSiEVADb/Xl9Tjlssz5BMTn3zv/2AUJRVBCEbDXUQroAtSW1/Tal47HP2U@s7nxFgKN8w3SI2DORQWgD0WwoMDuu0c0UjJ5mdDknjQm/amhJQhkFgVUAnpKSoZIfBhsAG2AQnQAKgBthWSr92/jgtYnmn12IKAAPYAqQBtqAAVrm2l4LVXYH1yMqjxUATWoQMUSI9a8pukK)

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218093)

Answer (score 4):

## Lost, Score 4, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233242/56656)

*Runs in `-A` mode for character output*

```
<>^v
```

You are going to have to write a deterministic, halting Lost program without any hard redirects.

### My solution

```
/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/
\%(((((265**:2+:65*+:2+:83*+@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/Xz8GD@SKUdUAASMzUy0tKyNtKyCtDaItjLW0Hf7//68b6AgA)

## Lost, Score 5, Cracked

```
<>\^v
```

Now do it without `\`.

### My solution

```
/|////////////////////////////
|/%(((((265**:2+:65*+:2+:83*+@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/X79GHw/gqtFX1QABIzNTLS0rI20rIK0Noi2MtbQd/v//rxvoCAA)

## Lost, Score 6, Cracked

```
<>\^v|
```

You don't really need `|` either.

### My solution

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
%((((((((((((265**:2+:65*+:2+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+2:+*65:+2:**562
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/X58iwKWqgQSMzEy1tKyMtK2AtDaItjAG0mbaDtpmVtpaxhZW2kZA2swURGtpmZoZ/f//XzfQEQA)

Comment: [Cracked?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233242/85334)

Answer (score 4):

## Vyxal, score 250, cracked by [aaroneous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236299/101522)

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijmnopqrtuvwxyz{|}~¡¢£¤¥¦§¨«¬°±²µ¶¹»¼½¾×Þßæð÷øĊċėĠġİĿŀŻżƈƒƛǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔȦȧȮȯɖɽɾʀʁΠβελτḂḃḊḋḞḟḢḣḭṀṁṄṅṖṗṘṙṠṡṪṫẆẇẊẋẎẏ‛„‟†‡•…‹›⁋⁰⁺⁼⁽₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₌₍€₴⅛←↑→↓↔↲↳↵⇧⇩∆∇∑√∞∧∨∩∪∴∵∷≈≠≤≥≬⊍⋎⋏⌈⌊⌐□⟇⟑⟨⟩꘍ꜝ
```

So *this* is how emanresuA felt.

Comment: [keep feelin' it, buddy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236299/101522)

Answer (score 3):

## 05AB1E, Score: 21, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207589#207589)

X = `•”“’‘Ž…„'"ഭ0123456789`

A bit more difficult entry :)

**edit**

Cracked by @nthistle

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207589/81278)

Comment: I'm thinking without blacklisting `ç` or some way to get arbitrary values on the stack, it's going to be difficult to stop my approach from working (and removing the ability to put arbitrary values on the stack will make it hard to do anything in 05AB1E...)

Comment: True. I'll think about that.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), Score=13

```
-/+0123456789
```

Printing characters without using digits should be tricky (and I'm pretty confident that you won't find a way to sneak in a `utf8ToInt`!). I wouldn't be surprised if the crack ends up completely different from my own solution.

Comment: Robin: I hope that I have not duplicated your challenge, and that adding some extra characters to my challenge actually makes it tricker.  If your secret solution will already crack my challenge, I'll withdraw it (but obviously I've already cracked yours...).

Comment: @DominicvanEssen No, my solution doesn't crack yours, so it isn't a duplicate! And I thought mine was hard...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen This confirms my last sentence: your crack must be very different from my own solution!

Comment: I'm trying to make a new crack to yours that doesn't give away my own one.  That could even be a new challenge: 'crack X without cracking Y'...

Comment: I've got the digits at least, but the '-/+' is proving trickier than I expected!

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207623/67312) curious what your intended solution was. I don't think this approach will be quite so fruitful for Dominic's, though.

Comment: @Giuseppe Well done! I'll wait a couple of days before adding my (completely different) solution, as I might be able to channel the idea into another challenge.

Comment: Amusingly, I think you can solve this using `utf8ToInt`, albeit calling it implicitly via `get` and an index-based lookup in `ls(pi*pi)`

Answer (score 3):

## C, score 2 ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207641/90181))

Output `{;` to stdout.

Probably not that difficult, but I was quite surprised when I first saw this C feature.

Answer (score 3):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), Score: 18, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208940/92901)

```
Pp1234567890'"+-*/
```

My code outputs to STDOUT with no leading whitespace and a trailing newline.

---

#### My solution

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' used exactly the same approach in the crack, with minor differences in implementation:

> ```
>  character(bit_size(i)) :: fmt, out
>  izero = floor(epsilon(r))  ! len_trim(achar(bit_size(i))) also works
>  ione = ceiling(epsilon(r)) ! len(achar(bit_size(i))) also works
>  itwo = ibset(izero,ione)
>  ithree = ibset(ione,ione)
>  ifour = ibset(izero,itwo)
>  ifive = ibset(ifour,izero)
>  isix = ibset(ifour,ione)
>  iseven = ibset(isix,izero)
>  ieight = ibset(izero,ithree)
>  inine = ibset(ieight,izero)
>  iten = ibset(ieight,ione)
>  ieleven = ibset(iten,izero)
>  itwelve = ibset(ieight,itwo)
>  ithirteen = ibset(itwelve,izero)
>  ifourteen = ibset(itwelve,ione)
>  ififteen = ibset(ifourteen,izero)
>  isixteen = ibset(izero,ifour)
>  iseventeen = ibset(isixteen,izero)
>  ieighteen = ibset(isixteen,ione)
>  fmt(ione:ione) = achar(ibset(ieight,ifive))
>  fmt(itwo:itwo) = achar(ibset(ione,isix))
>  fmt(ithree:ithree) = achar(ibset(inine,ifive))
>  out(ione:ione) = achar(ibset(isixteen,isix))
>  out(itwo:itwo) = achar(ibset(ibset(isixteen,ifive),isix))
>  out(ithree:ithree) = achar(ibset(iseventeen,ifive))
>  out(ifour:ifour) = achar(ibset(ieighteen,ifive))
>  out(ifive:ifive) = achar(ibset(ibset(ithree,ifour),ifive))
>  out(isix:isix) = achar(ibset(ibset(ifour,ifour),ifive))
>  out(iseven:iseven) = achar(ibset(ibset(ifive,ifour),ifive))
>  out(ieight:ieight) = achar(ibset(ibset(isix,ifour),ifive))
>  out(inine:inine) = achar(ibset(ibset(iseven,ifour),ifive))
>  out(iten:iten) = achar(ibset(ibset(ieight,ifour),ifive))
>  out(ieleven:ieleven) = achar(ibset(ibset(inine,ifour),ifive))
>  out(itwelve:itwelve) = achar(ibset(isixteen,ifive))
>  out(ithirteen:ithirteen) = achar(ibset(iseven,ifive))
>  out(ifourteen:ifourteen) = achar(ibset(itwo,ifive))
>  out(ififteen:ififteen) = achar(ibset(ieleven,ifive))
>  out(isixteen:isixteen) = achar(ibset(ithirteen,ifive))
>  out(iseventeen:iseventeen) = achar(ibset(iten,ifive))
>  out(ieighteen:ieighteen) = achar(ibset(ififteen,ifive))
>  write(isix,fmt(ione:ithree)) out(ione:ieighteen)
>  end
> ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVRRbsMgDP3vKdhfInUXQNpZqrQjDRqFidBk2uUzYwMJgXQ/w4vfs5/No72xznb6/d5TsCy3obPdzQnbXKW7jPJXNLJtGeesf7gzM093gm/WsA/WK2NsI75HqYxuLKDYG1NCX5yVj6bzlbIiLevUaNhs7Nd4kkYLqHETUkl9z6pgkX/5bvYa5HUUrkFFZ1@yhcRghVhT8DFmevO0ew6U8Rk5bSged8Y8pEb5s89QtVFMQq8pwCWOkPfBFZ28LkhqqTe9EJqIblsxpKibUHk7QK6sWaiprEmjuUFaJzIqwhPbz1QHhK3JPk9HwnZFOYIG9ri4pzwfCPm@6gjUANbDi@T4L6DIHPm4/g7bgIXROc6/x6IboHgC@kvh4W72YH9TqS44/4WGpJdqI/hQxI6CDXLmK1Vpn7k0v21OO68uqCRAzOlLXSC2D9eYU0EqR711Ir2SGs9L53QcceVU74lDcDqON1ql@nvk@PeI6AVVqc7rdYdqo/UqchXNSucBPRis0hZfIA/nsdsyTnjoPEV165S2IVaMChZYeO@cPlAoKA2nykZBM49B2SaorlgmEGNYUves6HieooITtCfebKEMeWj9uaEX2LL18ad6J6E/l@UP)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/208940#208940). By the way, I don't know Ruby or Fortran beyond the hello world stage. It's an interesting journey.

Comment: I had a feeling this was coming. Maybe now you should say *didn't* know. 'Hello, World!' generally doesn't take 1000+ bytes in either language :)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, Score: 7 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207693/91267))

```
cdnsvw,
```

**Note:** There is no newline at the end

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207693/81278)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), Score=14 [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207692#207692) by Giuseppe

```
0123456789([aE
```

My previous challenge was [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207647/86301) (embarassingly within less than a day) using indexed-retrieval of the searched-for characters from within larger expressions/strings.

This challenge is intended to make that approach more difficult.

## Solution

Giuseppe's crack was different in several places, so here's the solution that I had in mind when I posed the challenge:

> ```
>     # make some numbers:
>     zero=T-T
>     two=T+T
>     three=T+T+T
>     one=three-two
>     four=T+T+T+T
>     five=T+T+T+T+T
>     six=T+T+T+T+T+T
>     seven=T+T+T+T+T+T+T
>     eight=T+T+T+T+T+T+T+T
>     nine=T+T+T+T+T+T+T+T+T
>     ten=nine+one
>
>     # zero to nine is the first series of digits in the output string:
>     zerotonine=zero:nine
>
>     # 40, 69 and 91 are the ASCII values of ([ and E
>     forty=ten+ten+ten+ten
>     sixtynine=forty+ten+ten+ten-one
>     ninetyone=forty+forty+ten+one
>
>     # now we need to get some of the 'forbidden' functions
>     # first we use 'tolower' to get the (lowercase) function names of 'apropos',
>     # 'tail' and 'cat' (so we avoid the the lower-case letter 'a')
>     ~=tolower
>     b=~'APROPOS'
>     A=~'A'
>     t=~'TAIL'
>     c=~'CAT'
>
>     # Now we can use 'get()' to get the functions from the names
>     ?=get
>     ~=?b          # apropos()
>     i=~'intToUtf'   # look-up the full-length 'intToUtf8' function name
>     !=?i          # intToUtf8()
>
>     # Now we've got 'intToUtf8()' we can create the forbidden characters
>     p=!forty;b=!ninetyone;e=!sixtynine
>
>     # We want to paste them all together with no separator.  Since we can't easily give
>     # multiple arguments to a function (because we're always replacing binary operators),
>     # we need to construct 'paste0'.  This is the second function looked-up using
>     # 'PAST' (without the final E), so we use 'tail()' to get it.
>     -=?t
>     pp=~'PAST'
>     ppp=pp-one
>     +=?ppp
>
>
>     # Finally, we build our string using our new 'paste0' function, and use 'cat()'
>     # to output it:
>     string=zero+one+two+three+four+five+six+seven+eight+nine+p+b+A+e
>     ~=?c
>     ~string
> ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHBaoRADL3nLzx5CP5Al0Gkp0JhpWvv4jK6A8UZZtPd2oO/bl9G6toeJHnvJZlnEpfl20ZvmqIhuSMy4iVaqxlyP1qTcAGVev8ZVwFS7272FwBe3dcDKbY3O@4ZcNYNF/nLgR3daP@TagPtKjE8kJoUnyo1fdIMdqJMBnW8@9SITKky6Xut0FEqyeQ3/VGlaju3RvyHv9tInZnzqn471sdTTpWCnAShqV5eczoje66anNqyNYOV1Fp25MC7URr/Lj3EDKSjYLL0zqEz2WbgYE22uaW2QKVQCOivqxMGB@QhJNMtQwSmq0Q3DmkJ6pdxFk4HYj0O61EYMzmtn9PCOW0xcMcVrz9YnmleBy3LDw)

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207692/67312)

Answer (score 3):

## [PicoLisp](https://picolisp.com) , score: 1, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207699/)

```
(
```

Writing lisp without parentheses is really easy, with picolisp.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207699/) (Btw, this was fun!)

Comment: The output of the linked crack is `: (`, not `(`. If this was the intended solution, the challenge is wrong. How do you get picolisp not to display a prompt?

Comment: Comments about a cracked answer shouldn't be on thr cops' post. As you double-commented, I explained my answer there.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' You run the program as a script like `pil script.l` instead of typing it in after running `pil` like jdoodle seems to like to do.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, Score: 77, [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207718/9365)

```
 "#'+\-/0123456789:<>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz|~
```

Note: there is a leading space on this line. This leaves you with:

```
!$%&()*,.;=?@[]_{}
```

So much for trying to get a low score, there's too many ways to do it!

### My approach

First, it's necessary to break out of the `while(<STDIN>)` loop using `}{`. My aim wasn't to stop printing, but to make generating the string difficult. Without access to any letters immediately, it's tricky, but using the trick Gilles used `$_=*_` you get `main::_` which provides `a` and `:` (stored in `$;`) which we'll need later. Accessing these is also tricky as you can't index into strings directly like you can in some languages, but we still have `?` which (up until v5.22.0) works similarly to `/.../` allowing us to repeatedly match a section, store in `$_` (via `$_=$&`) and match again. `a&_` yields `A` and using that in a range with `_` (or `aa`/`AA`) produces the list of uppercase and lowercase chars needed (stored in `@@` and `@!`), accessing the indices is a little tricky without numbers, but these can be easily generated using list lengths to generate 0-9 and then concatenation to build larger numbers, although having enough short variables to store data in is an annoying problem to have. To generate the string I used a program to build the numbers I wanted, but it would be a lot shorter using ranges and I pass the codepoints into `pack` (by calling `CORE::pack`, via `&{'CORE::pack'}`)using `C77` as the definition which stores the desired string in `$_` which is implicitly printed.

```perl
}{
$_=*_;
?......$?;
$_=$&;
?.?;
@@=$&.._;
@!=(_&$&).._;
?..$?;
$_=$&;
?.?;
$;=$&;
$%=!$?;
$==()=(_,_);
${$![$?]}=()=(_,_,_);
$$=()=(_,_,_,_);
$*=()=(_,_,_,_,_);
$,=()=(_,_,_,_,_,_);
$.=()=(_,_,_,_,_,_,_);
$@=()=(_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_);
$}=()=(_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_);
$_=&{$![$=].$![$%.$$].$![$%.$.].$![$$].$;.$;.$@[$%.$*].$@[$?].$@[$=].$@[$%.$?]}(
$![$=].$..$.,
${$![$?]}.$=,
${$![$?]}.$$,
${$![$?]}.$*,
${$![$?]}.$},
$$.${$![$?]},
$$.$*,
$$.$.,
$$.$@,
$$.$},
$*.$?,
$*.$%,
$*.$=,
$*.${$![$?]},
$*.$$,
$*.$*,
$*.$,,
$*.$.,
$*.$@,
$,.$?,
$,.$=,
$,.$*,
$,.$,,
$,.$.,
$,.$@,
$,.$},
$..$?,
$..$%,
$..$=,
$..${$![$?]},
$..$$,
$..$*,
$..$,,
$..$.,
$..$@,
$..$},
$@.$?,
$@.$%,
$@.$=,
$@.${$![$?]},
$@.$$,
$@.$*,
$@.$,,
$@.$.,
$@.$@,
$@.$},
$}.$?,
$}.$=,
$}.$$,
$}.$,,
$}.$.,
$}.$@,
$}.$},
$%.$?.$?,
$%.$?.$%,
$%.$?.$=,
$%.$?.${$![$?]},
$%.$?.$$,
$%.$?.$*,
$%.$?.$,,
$%.$?.$.,
$%.$?.$@,
$%.$?.$},
$%.$%.$?,
$%.$%.$%,
$%.$%.$=,
$%.$%.${$![$?]},
$%.$%.$$,
$%.$%.$*,
$%.$%.$,,
$%.$%.$.,
$%.$%.$@,
$%.$%.$},
$%.$=.$?,
$%.$=.$%,
$%.$=.$=,
$%.$=.$$,
$%.$=.$,
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVTBasJAFLznK1a6G8yyfbeewpL3Cb2XkBQSoVCNROlF9teb7mbi02hFnHmzb2biCh778fttelHtvj2pz67rO3UeVFsRUdWq3TCq/TD28aPrx4P66cfT13A4qWGn3qNzCpdMN942ZbZPlvjSVZkknc9SHJjjQBRXeOO3Ta7zYp6S4WlZl/Ogjd/MZ95vi2hyTRGHi9586KoOVw2qvo0Q7L0Aya0liPQoQuZnGQfhvwMcNT6fH87XlMCQ1sIILAnl/OZZtvXMKoCvr3r8ftvsmhVviNzti5P2q0mvJruaQpw0iYDJAgjAgHRmYzHAADzgzm7RZ5ESwQEIkMIcUhzsDpsOmw6bTjZTJsFAqCX4aFVLqCWEEcKWeyGEEcIYYYwwRhivwhhhjDBGGCOMEcYICwhbrny56wBDgCHAsNx1@ungATPCvLC7J4GghVlhThgJY2GL10iVkSojVeaxykiVkSojVUaqjFQZqfJS5aXKS5WX5MhcVmTT9Dscz@lPYno9/gE) (with slight modifications to make it work on more moderns versions)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207718#207718). I found `-p` to be an extra difficulty. Was that intended, or did you intend a completely different approach for which `-p` would help?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Nice one! It was intended to give you an easy out, but it's not obvious, it'd possible to prepend the code with `}{` and escape out of the block, apologies that it caused extra stress! I think you got all the rest of the tricks and underhanded stuff I laid out, `?...?` was worrying me, I didn't know if it was too obscure! I'll share my solution later too when I'm at the computer!

Comment: Hey, the fun of the search is the point. We certainly haven't reached the end. [My turn to cop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207558/print-x-without-x-cops-thread/207732#207732). Without `-p`, though I'm curious if a solution for `-p` exists without `{`. I made my challenge mostly because I was close to a solution without using `*=`, then I realized that `*_` made things a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3):

## [Dupdog](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dupdog), Score: 10 - [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208924/87986)

```
[\x0e][\x0c]
[\x10][\x0e][\x18][\x16]
39
```

May I join the fun?

Inside brackets are escape characters. Assuming linux line-breaks.

### Intended Solution

```
~!!?*
```

I love short codes.

Comment: This should be really really trivial, by the way - none of the three Dupdog commands (`?!~`) happens to be in the output, so basically, this is a "Print X" challenge. The answer is suspiciously short - can you find it?

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208924/92901)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), Score: 11, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208888/92901)

```ruby
p.`'"?%([:<
```

Take 2, after @DomHastings and @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' found unintended weaknesses in [the original](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207832/92901). I've fortified this version by adding `p` and `` ` `` to the list of forbidden characters. As before, my code outputs to STDOUT with no trailing newline and works for Ruby 1.8.7 onwards.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/208888#208888)

Comment: Stay tuned for Take 3!

Answer (score 3):

## [Dirty](https://github.com/Ourous/dirty), Score: 8 - [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208923/87986)

```
hd of []
```

This is way too easy for people who knows this language... (I don't.)

### Intended Solution:

```
1
```

Yeah, you read that right.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208923/92901)

Answer (score 3):

## ><>, score: 20

```
0123456789abcdef&lol
```

Forgot the register... happy now?

Comment: [got 'em! cracked, lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209455/78850)

Answer (score 3):

## ><>, score: 24

```
123456789abcdef&io'"()=
```

The second approach. Also no newlines. Also be a little bit golfier please.

### Intended approach (I think)

It's 2022 and I've completely forgotten what I was thinking of two years ago, I only found this post through BoC2021 which mentioned this BoC2020 battle. I had to re-read the ><> specs, go through my eight answers, speculate what I was thinking about, and finally cracking it myself.

> In a some-what anti-climatic twist, round seven allowed the usage of a constant again -lyxal

> Two ways. -me

The first is lyxal's seventh crack. But why did I suddenly allow `0`?

...

Because `00g`!

Comment: golfing is overrated. [cracked lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209495/78850)

Comment: @lyxal see the post

Answer (score 3):

## [Shakespeare Programming Language](https://github.com/TryItOnline/spl), score: 4, [cracked by Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209796/86301)

```
mMbB
```

You cannot use `the sum of` or `the difference between`, so constructing integers is tricky.

---

Dingus' [crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209796/86301) is very similar to what I had in mind. The solution relies on the `product`, `square`, `square root` and `factorial` operators (which are not well known, since they are not or barely mentioned in the [official](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/) documentation), and on the fact that SPL only uses integers, so that e.g. 5 can be represented as \$\sqrt{32}\$ (`the square root of a cunning cute peaceful trustworthy healthy squirrel`).

Comment: Ha! I figured out! Robber coming soon...

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209796/92901)

Comment: @Dingus Well done! That is very close to the solution I had in mind (modulo the choice of epithets, naturally!)

Comment: Factorial... Nope. I did find the solution with a search script, however. The `b` is: `the square root of the square of twice the square of the square root of twice the square of the square root of a little little little little little cat.` [Try b online.](https://tio.run/##jYsxDsIwEAR7v2IfEPkB6SgQog4NQhQn5yAByxfsswKvN3GDEEKI5vZ2NJsmX0pjVxe6N3Y3MDaDJF2AU2xb2zkOXJ/DOihHvAwKPeroaOptDfaSQZFBCWeRvqYucrrlSqOIQk7vqLZ5dPzJvoz@0wh@VPX8MxypNegmpisekqMt5Qk) imagine I optimizing a program for two days only to find out it was cracked. EDIT:

Comment: Why not a new `mMbBlL` challenge? That will almost certainly be more interesting... (Mwahahaha)

Answer (score 3):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), Score: 23 [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/210255#210255)

```
15125177041707640200000
```

Ignore the fact that Arn has a compressed form, the ASCII-only version does not contain any of these characters

### My Solution:

```
(:*:*:*:*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++);o
```

You use the `++` prefix to increment to 18, square it 4 times, and then conver to octal.

Comment: I do not know this language, but can we do something like `9/9+9/9+9/9+9/9+...`?

Comment: Can Arn please have an online interpreter? (Or one that can be run in TIO.)

Comment: It does have an online compiler, [here](https://ZippyMagician.github.io/Arn).

Comment: Yes, @my pronoun is monicareinstate, I believe you could get that answer to work, but that is not the method I intended (so I hope you could figure out a different method).

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210255/92901)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, Score: 86 [Cracked by Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218016/56656)

```
!"#$%&'*+-/37:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^`kmpqvwxyz{|}~
```

Self-verifying (will not print a character in the source), new-line is part of the output set. Apologies for the squares, not sure if the codes are valid or got replaced when pasting the output into my answer. Not done with any unicode tricks.

I could probably reduce my score, but choose to keep it simple instead.

Original code:

```python
__builtins__.__dict__[str().join([chr(111),chr(112),chr(101),chr(110)])](1,chr(119)).__getattribute__(str().join([chr(119),chr(114),chr(105),chr(116),chr(101)]))(str().join([b for b in [chr(u) for u in range(9,128)] if b not in __builtins__.__dict__[str().join([chr(111),chr(112),chr(101),chr(110)])](__file__,chr(114)).read()]))
```

I think it reads itself for each iteration of the list comprehension. Had to change my editor settings to prevent it from automatically adding a newline at the end of the file.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It might be preferable to link your output on [TIO](https://tio.run/#) or provide a list of codepoints. SE has chopped some of the unprintables - copy/pasting only shows [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/n4ubh4uPX0BYUUlZRVVNXUtbV9/Y3MraxtbO3sHRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsPCIyKiYuITu3oLCsvKKyqrqmtu7/fwA "Python 3 – Try It Online").

Comment: Thanks! for simplicity the codepoint integer values are: 9,10,11,12,10,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,42,43,45,47,51,55,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,92,94,96,107,109,112,113,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127

Comment: This means you can use the characters `(),.01245689[]_abcdefghijlnorstu` or code points [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,13,32,40,41,44,46,48,49,50,52,53,54,56,57,91,93,95,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,108,110,111,114,115,116,117].  Also worth noting that code-point "10" (newline) appears twice in the output according to the code point list.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218016/56656). It was good fun.

Comment: Nice! Good catch on the double newline, looks like I should have opened my output file in binary mode, the second 10 should have been a 13!

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 87 bytes, safe

```
i&I0,`Grn4T[wfp8Ll:\|t1~cCEN'zu"e7^DWOv+J35!yKBZkXUxSYq%6=2dQP>MsVo]jRHA*b?ah_/g.F-m9
```

(note the single trailing newline, which is required)

See [here](/a/218524) for an explanation.

Comment: This is now safe.

Answer (score 3):

## Lost, score 10, [cracked by Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233247/85334)

```
(/<>[\]^v|
```

That is, you must construct a deterministic and halting Lost program with no redirection whatsoever, or pushing to the scope.

> Not much harder than Wheat Wizard's cop answers, especially looking at the cracks to them, but I figured I may as well give someone else the *joy* of staring a crack to this down.

## Intended crack, 10505 bytes

```
**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%
*********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%*
********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**
*******85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%***
******85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%****
*****85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%*****
****85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%******
***85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%*******
**85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%********
*85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%*********
85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********
5*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********8
*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85
+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*
:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+
7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:
+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7
:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+
67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:
7++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:6
++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67
+:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67+
:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++
2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:
+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2
:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+
65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:
5*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:6
*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65
+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*
1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+
-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1
+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-
:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+
1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:
+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1
:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+
1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:
+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1
:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+
1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:
+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1
:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+
83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:
3*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:8
*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83
+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*
:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+
6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:
+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6
@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+
+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@
6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+
:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6
+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:
*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+
38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*
8:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*3
:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38
+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:
1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+
:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1
+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:
1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+
:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1
+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:
1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+
:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1
+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:
-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+
1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-
+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1
*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+
56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*
6:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*5
:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56
+2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:
2:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+
:++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2
++76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:
+76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:+
76:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++
6:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++7
:+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76
+7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:
7:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+
:+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7
+*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:
*58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+
58**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*
8**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*5
**********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58
*********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58*
********%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**
*******%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58***
******%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58****
*****%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58*****
****%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58******
***%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58*******
**%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58********
*%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58*********
%**********85*+:7+:67++:2+:65*+1-+:1+:1+:1+:83*+:6+@+6:+*38:+1:+1:+1:+-1+*56:+2:++76:+7:+*58**********
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vdpNaoYwFIXh@dlHJ7k4iKIJd/R1Cd1HoYN2//Yaf74V3FcCoogPHIjJAb9/fv/2vTxHX4t5M9@amc9xjus6mdd79CUe2Oxlm1tZulu9x1StrHF3drMW5xYPrP396g8hShGiPEyucjPJysVkKyeTrgwmXzkYQAmGUIoQpQhRuhBlFaIUIYoJUVyI0oQoJkRxIcomRGlCFBOimBBlzJt8ZRaixLwhFBeibEKUWG8IpQhRTIhShSiTEMWEKC5EqUKUO7Rk5QotWzlDS1dGaPnKERqgRGiEYkIUF6KMGpWvLEKUqFGEEjsbQol5QyibEMWEKC8hShQPQom2RiguRDEhShGiLEKULkRxIYoJUaoQ5Q4tWblCy1bO0NKVEVq@coQGKBEaobgQ5WgEgDIJUaoQxYQoRYiyClFiZ0MoLkQ5PjaAMgtRongQiglRTIjShCgxbwjFhSijRuUrTYgSNYpQYr0hlKhRhLIKUboQ5f1zUqryMLnKzSQrF5OtnEy6Mph85WAAJRhCKUKUsu/79PX5Dw)

I banned `(` as an afterthought to see if I could push robbers into using the same arithmetic spam to clear the stack, but `?` works too.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233247/56656)

Comment: `*` was a smarter idea than `?`, It's basically twice as efficient.

Answer (score 3):

## Vyxal, score 232, cracked by [EmanresuA](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235786/100664)

```
ḟṙIcKġ₴…‹›+*/-d↵Ǎ½ƒɖø∆₈₇∞₆₄JiẎȯht42069ḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İNeVERgȮṄnaGḭ⟇ėyOU⊍p⇩Ż÷«»⌐m≬\ṡ∷‡⁽⟨|⟩‟„$∇_Ǐq꘍₍₌Π⁺βτʀʁɾɽ¨żẏ?¹⁰²ǔǓǒǑǐǎꜝ₂₃₅&ẇŀl↑↓∴∵¢`;¥£¾F¼⅛%→←"ẋ¤Ḋε€ZȧṗṖ¦†A↲↳⋏⋎⁋×λ√⌈⌊:Dbjvwxz,BHMQSTWXY)}]([{<>ḂĊḞĿṀṠẆẊ℅@°•ß↔æƈ§≈µ¯±≠⁼≥≤=ḃ∩s∪ĠṁȦ'ċḋṅ13578
```

We do a little trolling.

Comment: [Craked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235786/100664)

Answer (score 3):

## Vyxal `D`, score 229, [crakd by Aaron](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236051/101522)

```
ḟṙIcKġ₴…‹›+*/-d↵Ǎ½ƒɖø∆₈₇∞₆₄JiẎȯht42069ḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İNeVERgȮṄnaGḭ⟇ėyOU⊍p⇩Ż÷«»⌐m≬\ṡ∷‡⁽⟨|⟩‟„$∇_Ǐq꘍₍₌Π⁺βτʀʁɾɽ¨żẏ?¹⁰²ǔǓǒǑǐǎꜝ₂₃₅&ẇŀl↑↓∴∵¢`;¥£¾F¼⅛%→←"ẋ¤Ḋε€ṗṖ¦†A↲↳⋏⋎⁋×λ√⌈⌊:Dbjwxz,BHMQSTXY)}]([{<>ḂĊḞĿṀṠẆẊ℅@°•ß↔æƈ§≈µ¯±≠⁼≥≤=∩s∪ĠṁȦ'ċḋṅ13578ȧ
```

Now do it without string decompression.

Edit: Dang.

Comment: 7 days and you didn't get it either :P

Comment: [ez](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236051/101522)

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, Score:106, safe.

and again...

This is the output of my program (displayed here as the repr() of the bytes in python):

```
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&*+-/0123456789<>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^`fghijkqrsuvwxz{|}~'
```

So these are the characters available to crack it:

```
'(),.:;=_abcdelmnopty
```

I'm not using any unicode tricks, I think it would be trivial to make this program dump more characters to defend against those cracks.

Of course this is similar to my other answers, strings are encoded basically the same way but I applied some better python tricks to get them printed.

Hopefully I've dodged obvious cracks... only one way to find out!

---

Looks like it's safe, and I'm not going to go for a better score. Here's my solution:

#### [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 24234 bytes

```python
a=lambda:len(());a.__code__=type(a.__code__)(len(()),len(()),len(()),len(()),len(((),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),type(b'')((len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(()),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),)),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),)),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(()))),('',type(b'')((len(()),len(((),)),len(((),())),len(((),(),())),len(((),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())))).decode(),(type(b'')((len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())))).decode(),)),(type(b'')((len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())),len(((),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),(),())))).decode(),),(),'','',len(()),b'');a()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZzJasMwEEA/RxKEXHopDfkWo9SGHtLElFzy9a4dGgptFi@yLM08GEgUcvHT7DO4Pp8@joeX1/qrafx27z93pX/bVwdrndv4dVG8H8uqKLanc13Z37OzP/9ZPfy0bnWRv@fcpX2eC5CdMc5aUY@WJu2bWoX0RtceoDeFnjwfhuKrc5/tN2vMv9B1j1WPKH6b7V3ij67iyTU9v8Ve99xXGQYozTD9GqyNY9R3pMqPt5RJNjbVQAMYeBgfEczThHRZgd1feG86i3@ey@nPGEzmjVOzR8EYYTZSKI@XMUTNTWInQgskXsvkeotlmEmktqnk12nl@SlWHYlWQukWaEmXjqnXtRnU3Xm0BrJpYOTUacmsK5RfEyvjtlv2HUMJLU8hbVs53WdRfXSBE2lpQw6Zcxux0yjJYzbhI0T5E1IVM2Atg25FA31duwvqNjU0rqYoXcfRu4Wkev@K5TP1W5MggAIgYAEOiAAFLqCBDoDAhAAOduCDIAJEOEIWuLCAL5QRQMMa3AjQ4Y6AHvpI4Atwbl1W3ds8uzNvs0SbASrHoB02jY4CF4IQBGiuMaz70ZhOrq@p7aLZxlvXNN8)

not that it really means anything in that form. My 'real' solution is more like this:

```python
b=lambda:print(end='hi')

def reduce_num(i):
    c=','.join(['()']*i)
    if i == 1:
        return "len(((),))"
    else:
        return f"len(({c}))"

def reduce_numstr(s):
    return reduce_num(int(s.group(0)))

def reduce_bytes(x):
    ol=[]
    for i in x:
        ol.append(reduce_num(i))
    cl=','.join(ol)
    return f"type(b'')(({cl}))"
    
def reduce_str(x):
    return f"{reduce_bytes(x.encode())}.decode()"
    
out='abc'
olds = ''
import re
numre = re.compile("\d+")
fullset=set(x for x in range(127))
s=fullset
cont = True

while cont:
    olds = s;
    out = f"""a=lambda:0;a.__code__=type(a.__code__)(0,0,0,0,3,67,{reduce_bytes(b.__code__.co_code)},('',{reduce_bytes(bytes(sorted(s)))}.decode(),({reduce_str('end')},)),({reduce_str('print')},),(),'','',0,b'');a()"""
    out = re.sub(numre,reduce_numstr,out)
    cont = any(x in s for x in out.encode())
    s = fullset-set(x for x in out.encode())
    print(bytes(sorted(s)))

with open('out.py','w') as fh:
    fh.write(out)

for i in dir(b.__code__):
    print(i)
    print(getattr(b.__code__,i))

import subprocess as s

p = s.Popen('python3 out.py',shell=True,stdout=s.PIPE)
b = p.stdout.read()

print(repr(b))
print(len(b))
print(repr(bytes(sorted(fullset-set(x for x in b)))))
```

This works by hijacking a lambda's `__code__` to get it's type, which is `code`, and creating a new code object with it. This new code object is written over the lambda's original code object and then the lambda is called. The arguments to code() define a lambda that just prints a fixed string. All of the arguments are encoded by calls to len() on tuples of empty tuples to get integers which are either used directly or enclosed in another tuple that is passed into bytes() (for whatever reason I used type(b''), but I really didn't save any characters with that) and then when a string is required I called .decode on that. The script that generates the answer outputs compiled code from it's own lambda `b`, so it's probably best to run the generator script on the same version of python you'll be running the result on.

Maybe this could be done with fewer characters, I didn't explore every choice available with this strategy.

As a side note, this experience has lead me to believe that python is actually a great system for hiding code.

Comment: ... should I combine my answers on this question?

Comment: I feel like leaving this open for more time due to the holidays and AoCG.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript ([Node.js](https://nodejs.org)), score 4, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246092/110449) [three](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246097/110449) [times](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246100/110449)

```
[.lF
```

I really hope I haven't missed something...

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246097/92689)

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E, Score: 1, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207583#207583)

X = `.`

I think it is an easy one :)

**edit**

Cracked by @nthistle

My approach (without using ASCII code to char conversion):

> `98/γ¦ć`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207583/81278)

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), Score: 10 [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207605/78850)

```
doesn't\\`
```

<s>This'll take some extra thinking for you all.</s> Apparently not.

> ¶7ƛ;¶¶Z¶ⁿ2+¶`¶

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207605/92069)

Comment: @Third-party'Chef' beat me to it by less than a minute :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), Score: 55, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209571/78850)

```
  
 - + . 8  ! _ ~ ⑨ \ ;
  
 - + . 8  ! _ ~ ⑨ \ ;
```

[View it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fQYFLQVdBW0FPwUKBXUFRIV6hTuHRxBUKMQrWXPjk/v8HAA)

Good luck with this one. Most commands used to generate values are gone. Edit: I just realised the output was invalid. It's fixed now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Is the Try it online! link intended? :)

Comment: @mypronoun yes, it is. I copied the out in a new tio page to utilise its formatting. Also, it retains all characters SE might botch.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207616/36445)?

Comment: Is the official implementation linked required, or can the extended variants used in TIO allowed?

Comment: Nevermind, I don't need it anymore.

Comment: Added crack: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209571/96155

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, Score: 7, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207640/6828) by @Dom Hastings

```
p<.$a1d
```

Attempt number 3 after being foiled by @nthistle and @Dom Hastings.

Comment: So I've got another crack, but I'm pretty sure it's still not the one you're expecting and I don't want you to get bored of having alternative cracks, so I'm looking for more alternatives...

Comment: I found another method, which could be a little closer perhaps? https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207640/9365

Comment: That was it! Nicely researched.

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge 93](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge), score 12 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207632))

```
,0123456789"
```

Not too hard to figure out in theory, but a pain to implement (at least the way I did it).

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207632/46076)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2,  Score: 14 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207633/91267))

```
"'0123456789dt
```

**Note:** There is no newline at the end

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207633/56656).  It was good fun.

Answer (score 2):

## J, Score: 3 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207648#207648))

Aiming for a low score, so might not be hard to crack. Blocks the straight-forward ways to convert a number to a character.

```
au.
```

Only tested with j9.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207648/81278)

Answer (score 2):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), Score: 7 [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208931/92901)

This is just a simple one for you.

It outputs the following characters to `STDOUT`:

```
cho0.84
```

Should be a bit easy to find a working solution for this.

---

As you've seen, it has been cracked.
The code posted is a lot more complicated than I had written:

```
{@set x "a"}{@set k "{@in\x63 by 2251 x}{@in\x63 by -1 x}"}{@eval k}{@print "#{x}#{VERSION}"}
```

Simply starts `x` with "a" and increments it 2251 times.
Incrementing goes from "a" to "z", then "aa" ... "zz", "aaa" ... "chp".
Then, it decrements once (increments by -1), which results in "cho".

The line `{@print "#{x}#{VERSION}"}` just simply outputs the generated `x` and the `VERSION` variable, on a single string.
It's also possible to do `{@print "%s%s", x, VERSION}` for the same result.

Comment: I suspect this has to do with the `print` or `php` commands, but I'm not sure. Are you fine with plain PHP answers?

Comment: @user The intended solution has nothing to do with PHP, but sure. As the challenge states, it doesn't have to be the exact solution I was expecting. So, go ahead, you can post your crack. But please specify that it is based in PHP.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208931/92901)

Answer (score 2):

## R (with CRAN packages installed), Score: 3, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207681/86301)

```
([{
```

Yes folks, no brackets!

You may assume that any CRAN package is *installed*, but as per standard rules not *loaded*.

I haven't posted an R version number although your solution might reasonably depend on that, I'm happy to accept an answer for any version of R after 3.0.0.

Update: this is possible without using any CRAN packages, but given I originally posted this allowing CRAN packages, I won't change it.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207681/86301) (no packages needed)

Answer (score 2):

## J, Score: 3 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207689#207689))

After [nthisle cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207648#207648) my [previous challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207631/95594), here is a slightly harder challenge.

```
u:.
```

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207689/78410)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), Score=27, [cracked by Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207700/86301)

We have had several R challenges on this thread already. All the solutions needed a `t` (for `cat`, `get` or other functions), so here is one where you will have to avoid that letter. I also threw in a `v` to forbid `eval`, as I don't really understand all of the magic you can do with `eval`...

```r
t <-
"0123456789=[\\]^_`v"
```

Comment: I like that the output is perfectly fine R code, but now I'm *definitely* not going to get any work done today.

Comment: I've got a solution, but I won't have time to create all the numbers by making ```sum(T+T+...)``` for a while yet...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Note that you are allowed `*`, which can make it easier to represent numbers.

Comment: That's a good point.  I've posted an explanation of the [crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207700#207700) now.  I'll update it in a little bit by substituting in all the numbers...  Hope it's Ok for now.

Comment: Good enough for me, well done! I should have disallowed more characters. My solution would allow for disallowing `l` and `o` as well; I'll probably post it tomorrow (but I don't want to flood this thread with rather similar R challenges!)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Now I would love to see you and Robin take a crack at [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133486/find-an-illegal-string)! :-)

Comment: @Giuseppe I've been trying for months, without success! There was a short discussion about this in October in the golfR chat room.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript (browser), score: 34

`ABDEFGINOPGTUVZ234567890tf[evalsic`

I am not going throw away my chance! Yes, I like Hamilton.
(You may input code in the console).

Comment: Answer is safe.

Answer (score 2):

## TSQL (SQL server), Score: 1, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207762#207762)

X = `(`

I have made a [post on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19156/what-counts-as-output-in-sql) which asks what is considered SQL output, but no answer yet. Feel free to consider my post cracked on either the result-set output (1x1 or 0x1 cells only though), or the print output (print/raiserror low severity). I am not including raiserror with high severity because OP said in case we use the error output we should say so, and I don't.

My first post here, feel free to edit if I missed anything.

Comment: Cracked: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207762/14306

Answer (score 2):

## [Dotty](https://dotty.epfl.ch/) <s>0.20.0-RC1</s>, score: 3 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209052/95792))

```
:\{
```

Edit: Previously, I had the language marked as Dotty 0.20.0-RC1, but it appears there's an alternate crack(s) that also works on the latest versions of Dotty. This also means that you don't have to download Dotty 0.20, you can just test out your code in Scastie right in your browser.

---

Note: <s>This</s> The previous solution I had won't work before 0.20 or on the latest version (0.26 currently), so if you want to test it, you'll need SBT or Dotty 0.20 on your computer. However, you probably don't need to do that - just going through the Dotty website (linked above), and perhaps their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty) should be enough. If you do want to test it, I'd suggest [**Scastie**](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/J1VRRCzrThCLQ95TjvK7pg).

---

My original solution with Dotty 0.20:

> ```
>  object Main with
>    @main
>    def main = print("" + 58.toChar + 92.toChar + 123.toChar)
> ```

But it turns just [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/qQdEUjhWRuuUFAggPLqRGQ) works too, because functions can be toplevel in Dotty.

> ```
>  @main
>  def main = print("" + 58.toChar + 92.toChar + 123.toChar)
> ```

---

Hint: check the release notes for 0.20. There is also another feature, present since I think 0.18, that helps you do this. (To clarify, the first feature helps you avoid `{` and the second helps you avoid `:`, although the first can also help you avoid `:`).

Hint 2: The answer is very short and not at all complex (it took only 86 characters for me (no golfing)). Also, if you compile it on your computer, there will be 6 files: `main.class`, `Foo$package.class`, `Foo$package$.class`, and their corresponding .tasty files (assuming you name your file `Foo.scala`).

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209052/).

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 5.20 (packable with `pp` from [PAR::Packer](https://metacpan.org/pod/PAR::Packer)), Score: 87, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/208977#208977)

The ASCII control characters `^F^O^V^X` and

```
!"%'(*+,-/0123456789:;<>@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|~
```

As a Perl string:

```
"\x06\x0f\x16\x18" . '!"%\'(*+,-/0123456789:;<>@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\^`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|~'
```

As hex:

```
060f161821222527282a2b2c2d2f303132333435363738393a3b3c3e404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f505152535455565758595a5c5e606162636465666768696a6b6c6d6e6f707172737475767778797a7b7c7e
```

This means that the following printable ASCII characters are permitted:

```
 #$&).=?[]_
```

No more lists with `=>`, no more (balanced) parentheses. `/` is out but `?` is back in.

My solution works with an ordinary Perl on Linux or Windows, and with any version of suitable vintage. My intent with the PAR::Packer constraint is to express that you shouldn't depend on how Perl is installed. You can run `pp foo.pl` and run the resulting executable on any machine that can run the resulting binary, even if it doesn't have Perl installed.

For information, my solution's size (I didn't attempt to golf):

```
$ wc perl-no-asterisk-braces-comma-parentheses.pl  
  40  148 3993 perl-no-asterisk-braces-comma-parentheses.pl
```

Continuation of:

1. [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207618), [crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207671#207671)
2. [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207673), [crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207688#207688)
3. [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207698), [crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207718#207718)
4. [challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207732), [crack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207814#207814)

I used several tricks that I got from Dom Hastings's solutions. If you're new to this series, you may want to read our explanations before tackling this one.

Comment: A little worried I'm not going to be able to get this as I'm away next week! I've got all the numbers, all uppercase characters, but still missing a generator for lowercase! I've looked into quite a few mechanisms, still investigating `NaN`... Hopefully I'll get some time Sunday...

Comment: @DomHastings After this one, I have another one ready with a slightly different character set that forced me to use a completely different approach to construct letters. And I'm also thinking about one without `.` — no more concatenation — but I haven't yet found an interesting character set that works.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208977/9365) in probably the most horrendous way possible, but that was fun!

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), Score: 23, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208914/92901)

```
cdp0123456789.`'"?%([:<
```

Take 3, and hopefully this time I've better captured my intentions! The score has more than doubled over the previous iteration, largely thanks to the digits. Also now banned are `c` and `d`. For what it's worth, my code has hardly changed.

Previous challenges in the series:

[Take 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207832/92901) (score 9), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207861/92901) by @DomHastings. (@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' exposed another fatal flaw.)

[Take 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208876/92901) (score 11), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208888/92901) by @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/208914#208914). I'm sure this is way more complicated than your solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), Score: 16, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208933/92901)

```
cdopr.`'"?%([{:<
```

OK, fourth and final take! The score has actually dropped now that I've realised (thanks to chief nemesis @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil') that banning digits is redundant. But there will be no more `String` or `Array` (`r`), no more `Float` (`o`), and no more interpolation into regexps (`{`), thank you very much.

I'll surrender if this one is cracked . . . probably more like *when* this one is cracked :)

Previous challenges in the series:

[Take 1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207832/92901) (score 9), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207861/92901) by @DomHastings. (@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' exposed another fatal flaw.)

[Take 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208876/92901) (score 11), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208888/92901) by @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'.

[Take 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208893/92901) (score 23), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208914/92901) by @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'.

---

#### My solution

I surrender. Here is my code:

> ```
>  X = RUBY_COPYRIGHT
>  D = RUBY_DESCRIPTION
>  M = X=~/M/ && $&
>  Y = X=~/Y/ && $&
>  a = X=~/a/ && $&
>  b = X=~/b/ && $&
>  e = D=~/e/ && $&
>  g = X=~/g/ && $&
>  i = X=~/i/ && $&
>  k = X=~/k/ && $&
>  n = D=~/n/ && $&
>  O = X=~/O/i && $&
>  P = X=~/P/i && $&
>  R = X=~/R/i && $&
>  s = X=~/s/ && $&
>  t = X=~/t/ && $&
>  u = X=~/u/ && $&
>  One = X=~/\w\w\w\w-/ && $&=~/^\w/ && $&
>  thRee = X=~/\w-/ && $&=~/^\w/ && $&
>  nine = X=~/\w\w\w-/ && $&=~/^\w/ && $&
>  sPaCe = X=~/ / && $&
>  DOt = D=~/\w\s\w\D/ && $&=~/\D$/ && $&
>  lPaRen = X=~/\WC\W/ && $&=~/^\W/ && $&
>  RPaRen = X=~/)/ && $&
>  lsqbR = D=~/\S+$/ && $&=~/^\W/ &&$&
>  RsqbR = D=~/]/ && $&
>  take = DOt+t+a+k+e
>  C = eval lPaRen+b+DOt+DOt+e+RPaRen+take+lPaRen+nine+RPaRen+lsqbR+One+RsqbR # eval "('b'..'e').take(9)[1]"
>  S = eval lPaRen+lPaRen+M+DOt+DOt+Y+RPaRen+take+lPaRen+nine+RPaRen+lsqbR+thRee+RsqbR+DOt+DOt+Y+RPaRen+take+lPaRen+nine+RPaRen+lsqbR+thRee+RsqbR # eval "(('M'..'Y').take(9)[3]..'Y').take(9)[3]"
>  PutC = P+u+t+C+sPaCe
>  stRing = S+t+R+i+n+g+sPaCe
>  suCC = DOt+s+u+C+C
>  zeRO = eval stRing+One+lsqbR+One+RsqbR
>  twO = eval stRing+One+suCC
>  fOuR = eval stRing+thRee+suCC
>  five = eval stRing+fOuR+suCC
>  six = eval stRing+five+suCC
>  seven = eval stRing+six+suCC
>  eight = eval stRing+seven+suCC
>  eval PutC+nine+nine
>  eval PutC+One+zeRO+zeRO
>  eval PutC+One+One+One
>  eval PutC+One+One+twO
>  eval PutC+One+One+fOuR
>  eval PutC+fOuR+six
>  eval PutC+nine+six
>  eval PutC+thRee+nine
>  eval PutC+thRee+fOuR
>  eval PutC+six+thRee
>  eval PutC+thRee+seven
>  eval PutC+fOuR+zeRO
>  eval PutC+nine+One
>  eval PutC+One+twO+thRee
>  eval PutC+five+eight
>  eval PutC+six+zeRO
> ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZPNjtMwFIXX@CmiUjWtLFohVixmg4Ogi@LIHTQT0YISyXSsjiJBnHZgwasXX/veNONkgYQqp8p37u9J8rOtfl0u98lNoj6/K74JmRdq/eHjLcsIZe@3Qq3z27X8xDYO3t/8WW1WyWyWTGesQFAQKBGUBCoEFQHtQOaAJnDAiAMBg8AQOCI4EqixRk1AYoRcGSQ5krwjConqSIOkoTIWgSXQImi7RrVGtDuH3yuUHPq6O3eVHpS@Ro7H1CYqNh7W5KWguIRgJi164BIbd7Jr7i6bUthjXipdU5M7sbvrt6Abpp6FLbrs5kelqM2WTwe5kNqP2Xfrl0f/nKXllpf8yDUT7l6fysckzMQrDioczUN/DlkcZTCHuJ@DSwC@24uXodJknlbpcpnqdLGE3PnbxZfX@wnbRq3wb9N1LP6to3@Ioed/pF6nnacbGLfojftmPwATlrcW3Mp569wT3L8ArLHK1PCtbB1U3PCaH0hqhUC3G5cjuGC/tZLkQsj0/kVOMnsei4J67LtsVaSFpYJqTjpSISGIjXmKNReOmj75N62vuvgganN4sLEICSgDBnOC4XDpMZgc1vaXiOMZoc6BEQq79HBYzTzFEzxHwZ5oqgCjerCwFwaBftu4c7SQbz3cxm0yKOp9965G3aHk5fIX)

Explanation:

> The basic idea is to build the output exclusively by extracting
>  characters from predefined strings, then using those characters to
>  build other necessary characters using `eval`.
>
>
>  I made the mistake of extracting characters from `RUBY_COPYRIGHT` and
>  `RUBY_DESCRIPTION`, neither of which contain the essential `c`. If I'd
>  used `$LOADED_FEATURES`, as @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' did, I would
>  have had an easier time. I also made things difficult for myself by
>  avoiding digits. Even had digits been banned (as they were in Take 3),
>  they can be easily derived using `$$`.
>
>
>  `RUBY_COPYRIGHT` and `RUBY_DESCRIPTION` are strings (both added in
>  1.8.7) that both contain some fixed text and some version/platform-dependent text. For the Ruby version currently on
>  TIO, these strings are as follows, with fixed text (common across all
>  Ruby versions/platforms) indicated in bold:
>
>
>  `RUBY_COPYRIGHT` = `ruby - Copyright (C) 1993-2019 Yukihiro Matsumoto`
>
>  `RUBY_DESCRIPTION` = `ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux]"`
>
>
>  I limited myself to extracting characters from the fixed parts of
>  these strings so as not to tie the code to a particular
>  version/platform.
>
>
>  I start out by grabbing a bunch of necessary letters through simple
>  regexp matching, with the `i` flag used for case insensitivity to help
>  with `o`, `p`, and `r`. I also grab the version-independent digits
>  `1`, `3`, and `9`, the space, `.` (for method calls), `(` and `)` (for
>  grouping), and `[`, and `]` (for indexing).
>
>
>  Now comes the tough part: I need a `c` to create either `chr` or
>  `putc` (I used the latter) to convert numbers to their corresponding
>  ASCII characters. I also need a way to create the remaining digits
>  that I don't have, and sure enough the method to do that—`succ`—also
>  contains `c`. (A synonym for `succ` is `next`, which I avoided because
>  I couldn't get an `x` without using the platform-dependent
>  `x86_64-linux` part of `RUBY_DESCRIPTION`.) Agonisingly, there are
>  *two* (uppercase) `C`s in `RUBY_COPYRIGHT`, but with no way to convert them to lowercase (you guessed it, `downcase` and `swapcase` also
>  contain `c`) they're useless.
>
>
>  On top of that, I need an (uppercase) `S` to make `String` because
>  `succ` (called via `eval`) ends up generating integers rather than
>  strings.
>
>
>  After much wailing and gnashing of teeth, I realised that I had just
>  enough characters to create `take`, fortuitously allowing me to
>  extract `c` from the range `('b'..'e')`. A double `take` was needed to
>  get `S` from the range `('M'..'Y')` (Matz's initials). See the
>  comments in the code for a better idea of how this works.
>
>
>  With that out of the way, the rest is pretty straightforward. I make
>  the `putc`, `String`, and `succ` methods by concatenating characters,
>  use these to get the remaining digits, and then print the required
>  characters.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/208933#208933)

Answer (score 2):

## ><>, score: 1 - [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209443/87986)

```
o
```

How can you output a character without using the `o` command?

## Intended Solution

```
ab*1+:90p ;
```

Same trick, but much shorter.

Comment: [cracked lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209443/78850)

Comment: @Lyxal Of course it's supposed to be easy lol also that one's poorly golfed see my intended solution

Answer (score 2):

## ><>, score: 20

```
0123456789abcdef&loi
```

loi for loss of input

Comment: [round 6 when? cracked, lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209457/78850)

Answer (score 2):

## ><>, score: 22

```
0123456789abcdef&loi'"
```

No literals now.

Comment: I"m just watching as your answers get progressively bigger and Lyxal still manages to crack them each time :)

Comment: Well, you've won. I give up. It's just too hard for me to crack this answer................................is what I'd be saying if it wasn't [cracked lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209483/78850)

Comment: @user I've struck again with my longest one yet.

Comment: @Lyxal For a moment there I felt a little sad, thinking this chain was going to stop. Good to see you haven't broken it yet. HighlyRadioactive, keep the challenges coming! I wish both of you luck.

Answer (score 2):

## ><>, score: 21

```
123456789abcdef&loi'"
```

Two ways.

Comment: roses are red, my name is not paul. where's round 8? cause this is [cracked, lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209492/78850)

Comment: @Lyxal Herrings are red, my name is not Lyxal. I don't know ><> at all. Also, you are lazy.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, score 80, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/209715#209715)

Last one for javascript. You have to do jsfuck, but I've disallowed 4 of the important characters. I left you some extra, but you'll have to figure out which ones to use and how to use them.

```
<("MrJock,TVQuizPHDBagsFewLynx.mRjOCKtvqUIZ=phd#bAGSfEWlYNX? 12+34-56*78^90%!')>
```

Yes, this is possible, by the way. The problems you will encounter, in order:

- Making numbers (Notice in the number spot, I left out one operation, use that and one other symbol
- Making booleans (The answer to this was posted years ago in a chatroom about JSFuck)
- Executing functions (If you saw my previous two cop answers, you know how to do this)

My solution was exactly the same as the cracked one above.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/209715#209715)

Answer (score 2):

Php7, score: 14 ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209787/76153))

```
funtim(){}_=/\
```

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209787/9365)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, Score 104 [Cracked by dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218196/88546)

Slithering deeper into Python insanity

```
$ python3 ./test6.py |hexdump -C
00000000  09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10  11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18  |................|
00000010  19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 20  21 22 23 24 25 26 2a 2b  |....... !"#$%&*+|
00000020  2d 2e 2f 30 31 32 33 34  35 36 37 38 39 3a 3b 3c  |-./0123456789:;<|
00000030  3d 3e 3f 40 41 42 43 44  45 46 47 48 49 4a 4b 4c  |=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKL|
00000040  4d 4e 4f 50 51 52 53 54  55 56 57 58 59 5a 5b 5c  |MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\|
00000050  5d 5e 5f 60 61 62 64 67  6a 6b 6d 6f 71 73 75 76  |]^_`abdgjkmoqsuv|
00000060  77 78 79 7a 7c 7e 7f 0a                           |wxyz|~..|
00000068
```

This time it's not self-verifying.

Verification code:

```python
import sys
import subprocess as s

fname = sys.argv[1]
ph = s.Popen(f"python3 {fname}",shell=True,stdout=s.PIPE)
out = ph.stdout.read()
with open(fname,'rb') as fh:
    fc = fh.read()

matches = [x for x in out if x in fc]

if len(matches) == 0:
    print("Success, no output characters in source")
else:
    print(f"Error, maching characters: {matches}")
```

Verify output:

```
$ python3 ./verify.py ./test6.py 
Success, no output characters in source
```

Original generator:

```python
import re

code = "print(__dat)"

squots = re.compile("'([^']+)'")

dquots = re.compile('"([^"]+)"')

def fstrchar(x):
    return f"{'{'}chr({x}){'}'}"


def fy(x):
    return fystr(x.group(1))
    
def fystr(s):
    return f"f'{str().join([fstrchar(ord(x)) for x in s])}'"

def replaceliterals(x):
    xx = squots.sub(fy,x)
    return dquots.sub(fy,xx)

digits= re.compile("\d+")
def subdigits(x):
    return digits.sub(lambda m: f"len({repr(tuple([tuple()]*int(m.group(0)))).replace(' ','')})",x)

code = subdigits(replaceliterals(code))

dat = "".join([chr(x) for x in range(9,128) if chr(x) not in code])

ocode = code

code = code.replace('__dat',subdigits(fystr(dat)))

dat = "".join([chr(x) for x in range(9,128) if chr(x) not in code])

code = ocode.replace('__dat',subdigits(fystr(dat)))

open(1,'w').write(code)
```

[Try the result online!](https://tio.run/##7ZFbCsJADEWX0yn455JEqSBjKf0p4tpHNyDYaeaR5JR8Nrn3nJm3dXrGc0rzco9ruA2vy7SExzWGEMbTj/l@73/@2/fr7r9zFjJ38tcObR5dFtiXOSF2RfKQ8C35c0Uuljpa8G7Z08Wv1wiolFEvpmpS7bAGeW0im6W2DG6c3T6@0yrdtem3U7@1um7WezkF/XRUVNNSU1FlXfXVVdlYa2nFvXVXV9/eAoARBjsYpkiswRjksYlklsoymHE2@3guCL1AOuL0heqO1iOwU2a/2K7JvcPDjwIsIAIX6MAIUvCCGuwgCEdoQhOmkIUvlCGOwSAqscngFLP4ZbCMa3RjBONIZ/COeoYH4BkY0ZcYxpQ@)

Comment: Note that newline (0a) appears twice in the output...

Comment: Also, period (2e) is in the output set, which may be overlooked because of the other periods used to represent non-printing characters.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218196/88546), i think?

Answer (score 2):

## LUA 5.1, Score: 82 [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218511/90587)

### Output

`` !"$%&'*+,-/0123456789:;<>?@ABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^`bdefgijklmnopqstuvwxyz{|}~ ``

### Little hints whats allowed at all

`_Gachr.#()[]`

I can reduce my score a lot by allowing more crap letters tho.
This was a really fun task, code is brain fuck :D

Have fun guys

Comment: Is a trailing newline acceptable?

Comment: There's none in the output.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218511/92901)

Comment: Awesome @Dingus. New one is on the way soon.

Answer (score 2):

## x86 machine code (Linux, no libc), 1 byte, safe

Machine code this time, for 32-bit Linux.

```
0x80
```

Output is the byte <kbd>0x80</kbd> to stdout.

Your code cannot use libc. Specifically, expect it to be inserted into an ELF `.o` file linked as so (but the filename will not be used)

```
$ i686-linux-gnu-ld file.o -o a.out
```

My solution:

> The easiest solution is to use `sysenter` instead of `int 0x80`.
>  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVRda9swFH33r7i0r7HbrWUroQw2aGGwsdfCGEG2rmOtjiR0rxMH9t@zK9lJnLp@sJSjo/txznVKRc2hUgxfgJG4IHh8hKdfzwcYn8JYxnZFe8uqB@t8wNr02el43bqyhRWxCpwNy/J0eg3ELiDc9g@34Cxwg4Ko6hXKPfiOGmPXcvj5GZTVYGwVcIOWI2r4FCUS4xqJJ1DIaS33jOA5wG8k/@cis8RUQcMuGKHQnirVtkDInZ/Qyo6BHVQNiggKatylkLSAHUYyXLDvJS88fXtJ9X5IP76@LGJfFmin/Kzm@zPifFqxPKvXuzBgql/E16y7KbZx2wGrIpn8/EC/iXItcYhRaXC1bDn5kBpTYkpHUWfRRRTHMLn0ncEiaopydPZ1P1qWlIu9um7dFLC8yYofo6ortVbGXvguHWDM1KgtShhRvnKWg2vBbTFExSbsIKGDBaV1QCKoRZZjXancStkJe@ZVnKahm75q1mLntBBxRWwTi8WpNIC1CSSemw2mRGk8FpMbg7VpVFFq1mcq9oaLs3kx12DoIPvMfFfXcYLeyDSjiaFzTL@Dle94XvrLYTjqdpCPOMsUQZ7ffTx@27kbdi7LWg35BrCtV@bu4dMIR4IqXMcZVo2DK1f@1d3GL6@ycQe5HgiQ/0x/DIk4svteBq1j37FcKG4G3j8Q@PAf)

Answer (score 2):

## DOS x86-16 machine code, 1 byte, safe

```
0xCD
```

A similar challenge to my Linux one, this time for DOS. *The solutions are entirely different, though.*

In CP858/CP437, it is the **box drawing character** ═ (not to be confused with =), and in CP1251, it is the **Cyrillic letter** Н (not the English letter H).

That byte must be output to standard output. **I won't accept writing to video RAM.**

You can assume an i686-compatible CPU in real mode DOS.

I didn't make this obvious, but DOS has no memory protection. All RAM is fair game. Watch out for CPU cache issues, though.

<sup><sup>I expected this to last no longer than a day, and clearly I was wrong.</sup></sup>

My solution:

> `ba cc 21 42 52 68 b4 4c 52 b4 02 89 e5 16 55 cb`
>
> ```c
>         org 0x100
> start:
>         // DX = int 0x21
>         mov     dx, 0x21CC
>         inc     dx
>         // DL is also 0xCD.
>         push    dx
>         // mov ah, 0x4C (exit)
>         // We can't use ret or int 0x20 because we
>         // change CS.
>         push    0x4CB4
>         // Push int 0x21 again.
>         // SP now contains this code, which calls
>         // int 21 to print, then exits.
>         //     int 0x21
>         //     mov ah, 0x4C
>         //     int 0x21
>         push    dx
>         // AH = 02 = putc(DL)
>         mov     ah, 0x02
>         // Copy SP to BP so we push the right value
>         mov     bp, sp
>         // dos doesn't protec
>         // ez to attac
>         // but most importantly
>         // we can jump to stac
>         // jmp far ss:[sp] if it existed
>         push    ss
>         push    bp
>         retf
> ```
>
> Too easy.

I am willing to write a sequel that requires even more DOS abuse if anyone is interested. But getting all these assembly cops for free is just boring.

Comment: [Expecting this](https://tio.run/##NctBCoMwEEbh9eQU/1pSiNIbeAxxEROtLcZIBnU8fSraLt8HzzL3oZuOx2A55EwxvWCkNEZRiBv8pM@sa0Xv2cHLrXbUqBQtK49wrEhighPt5G9Cv50v/IQFg03we0wejZGqLJ5tzl8)

Answer (score 2):

## [YaBASIC](http://www.yabasic.de), score:15 [Cracked by Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220057/92901)

The new and improved string to crack:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
L
S
l
s
-
```

[Try it online in YaBASIC!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/v6AoM69EQck5MU@hMr9UIbkoMTlbIbPEXun/fwA)

<strike>Can you crack it?</strike> Yes they can!

My method relies on 1 variable,i, which defaults to 0. !i (NOT i) results in 1. Of course, with 0 and 1 we've got binary - the building block of all computing. However, in my case I just added as many !i as needed to get the result. Pretty ugly...

```
?i
?!i
?(!i)+(!i)
?(!i)+(!i)+(!i)
?(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)
?(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)
?(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)
?(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)
?(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)
?(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)
?chr$((!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i)+(!i))
```

And so on with ?chr$ and as many !i as needed for the desired character. In hindsight maybe adding = to the string would have slowed Dingus down by a few more minutes... Their solution uses it whereas mine doesn't.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220057/92901)

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), score 16, safe

```
0123456789pe[]{}
```

You don't have access to numbers, including pi and e, nor creating arrays, nor any functions that need `{}`. Since Desmos doesn't have strings, strings are generally outputted as character code arrays. You may be able to find some other suitable output method, but you don't need to. Good luck!

Safe: Huh, I shouldn't have used so many characters, I expected this to be cracked easily. There's a number of ways to get a 1, including but probably not limited to:

```
f(x)=x
f'(x)
```

and

```
floor(random())!
```

(note that we can't use `ceil()` as it uses e)

The former is what I used [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ocdeihbsgp). Once you have a 1, you can just add it a bunch of times and use a `join()` or two to make it into an array.

Answer (score 2):

## Javastack, score 15, [Cracked once more](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/233213#233213) by exedraj.

```
1234567890"dqwl
```

No `add`, no `duplicate`, no `double`, no `random`, no `power` - hopefully this will thoroughly bamboozle you.

Have fun!

<s>I gave you back `flatprint` - you're gonna  need it.</s> Turns out you don't need it, and I'm taking  away `l`.

Comment: [Crockeried](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233213/78850) or something idk

Answer (score 2):

## Javastack, score 14, [Cracked by exedraj](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233231/100664)

```
1234567890"crs
```

Game on.

[Up-to-date copy of the interpreter](https://tio.run/##rVl7b9vIEf@7/hQbIxeSEUM/Ehe46JxDGhRFDk1xSNIeClmNVuLKYkyRDLmUpTjKV09/s7sklxRluUAF2OLuzszO@0F95itezPIok8@SNBQ/YiGZiMVSJLJgl@zuiOHj8DB0Xo5c7k89dvmKswGb@udj3xwm9SHOnjyxj7JM2KejIAimPh83ENNIdvCnrcMkleoQR9@5f2adpLmF9c3CmokoxtE7LhcBPTdYswUnpA8yj5LrYJ6nyzfYeQO52zAz7ACOg3AwMxCvpes1UGG0ihSMYWB6whsGcLhMbam/f3cB4PnTn2zRw7ScxtU9A0u4sMziaMYlzpgWfcRJaWcNiPhS8tiS//LSUsA8TpVyiO4z/pOFpk7AXoNZsVYjL3g8N7gn5w1mlMxy5RWVNfjgzD4NxVpzq9UxsgWNpMiVNIQJ/2HkBm15PqdRYmkzoLVrsxWL5FouKqPolc9q/CXfTLW61AXK9jkcK11i4xd2Glz4pzWsbRuYpLlkWcYyyuJNc8w4ewpfZzWI5Y@PLJO1ndH2xoxH1tmo7f1ZmlXURi19ZOmtsNCmT59yi4ksF5244j5Flk0ZLi61umZpUqSxCOL0Gjd9@9a@CY4U5nC4xhEHLWfEeS5F5U4nL5oT0i8cissq2LTCG0XTuuYCjta2ylPGvTaxZZQs@bqRagdBrfm0cPkzJKIBc6ev@K/85dSzHEWDG3ZH7VvpTuM73rh193XHO1/nOd9gHdyITeG2gKF6Lq1syKaB3iN/bWyEvZjPqhThzxToLDDbr@PYhSt4/vMKvkDMSzsE1EYrBgqyhagD8KllpaKsRMYNYTkTrrv2N4BaDzaWlotbntVhqmTFA7ymgZCLKA8rYz@39lEiWj7SHKF@RBFxZRK81t3PF944WPLMdT/5a5z0JF13PXh@7nkq2CeTxm94nC34VEhD0@HTWSjm14vo8028TNLsS17IcnW73nx1GqQvZapTDGEc08HR9mheJjMZpQnLy8SlrO5HSVbK4nI09nRpqyFisXalWEuzTx@qhTK9EQlVQkQNK5QMWMx5XIhq/alIP815jm3H8dntAumuyGBj2mBXyZV0hjXJeZq7RJaqCkvnrHMjfaK529AIkHfjMhSFSxgee/KEPdK3drAM5qMWSx5D7MsoKcUOrJYryMpi4bZxhjuwu2K2YbboGApB1yuxLgFx7PTzZ3hvXT85fnzXumJ7PPH6lLufII4rtTyU2zbY4FKZpAbcHu3cUev0IarLhSzzxIAeNRRrd8t4Xgg3joquwyWikCIsJJ/dGK@zXHDXkdQheVKHlGFdHY9Ox/uNYkszcrQ8jq92x94eM6tTBLecLdyT0VV4FYwHJ95B4km5nKKSVMT3OdHIkdFSFI7vQEjBZws8ISKQfXzU@Qz/o7k5XBE5p4SPx@o7FgXhydtoRtBykesHhQ4DU54nzJLQ5tFKOOMmwhRbB6VQC99xxj2BYtlOQ2uSw/vUqCxDO3sipkUzzai/AQI00APey4Mh3gvcto8CVKLtABumodD0Flfcsg@bRPL1X/McfujoBVOrlxoSfRKLEkZ8HpYerYzHdsUh/4bImQjh/Dt66FOW3GQCsVAhEfESrek8SgRd8SD2/5koxwa@4uuATwPmkzPQF@6qzkh7KDDMwLUn7HqSko2OimvrhkruVxRiw9lXxVSgQgUJx/MenqKuRfKmBFKo1dTJU9RRwSxr6iLWo57ubt10Wgyt@hefrXby4@TxHWFABdoG8L73Yi5ykaiw/Qhz4uttggY04RTi/05L/P8NQyu@FF/4fickLf8Bl3udsAoBTbJU6eG97gjVg4r/d@UcHoGH39EyIHcoym@TVVREU5Vl/sJDKG2r6DPqDeA/7PFdj5Bnp6fe9uVk4FwlzqCWDmI1jdBXaKkH8@IUDSx7fuqZNmnd3yL1YP58AUxqnKrOadtzv8Ocqi3tIfHV87b/6cHSxjj6086W83ERUWZ9ky6XnB7@Hs1JUx8wFd6GeUTeheUfXKv8g1hGszTG4GFsBm2yGU8oK0wFK@FUcDxmqH@5hLeip/adjRD0FUYFJpYVXVCqlITRM1VL9DO4Sip6BnsF7CyVXKaqZhT21RvlLtBCgqZPoc/nQlcGwcLoGnED1lmxQfwsiejEb8Xe5PdYcARwmCaOrNm17sbjMxahn@NgtGC1umYqcJhQHoRiVnDcBT@6oRwaFXAq4mLKQ5aVitNQQLQ5ytVNGXMVfshjPItSlLklAfwrkhwDEnuD5wu5oOPfynjD5hEskOY3BbEfdPn/Y7GBnCGDIiAEOP2VvZVOgX6YUiJ7iwY0junUN1uPuhT@lsZz6rAwGCM3QheOEXIBvdcF1pTUcJOASUk79MpI2WumLBtv1irMUNDz3MRhJvJlKZW0insHFQOGgFIgXH0N9nfE@gjzZXmKaF2yqCDb3EbQCVmVuvxAC6n2IJuNTjbuS3YxLzBs5bmV5UyOwuYIfyabPTsb97ZzqEgq//poci7P/NucZ9WcYJG04d8L5SQN2m739oh2Kz5G46Od3pcSvuZLFbvTnp5ACaanHgL3AvjbIppLd@dAVdWerqa6v4uAtpLeOvSJgqA480@98cOKYXWBVdzvI9wl21MfV2jpc0E9c6@ih3Z3Dzhbh2dqxiL71ZoHBGTt@gV2@zxhli4zNJu6vSnstkbNffo07MwldIRy@0EgncqqqjorZ9BK3IFMdYlwz/7sBUWM0HPPvTYVpItPcZqS87mqjcYgpaiqcX9CYwOmLbWzBczpkDXLX/CscLbW7mDg3V0lNEdiVP0ExUYcYQfUGuIqmbTGknokMSpoG5yYLCo5a5ldr@LzvL09vHei0Y2@16gVc1ylAffcN5IfoKFz2B4izx9GROW/PSRePJAEjSN7SFw8UBQ1N7Vp7Jrcr1bnWx0gOjK8ritUQDvOwO7zhiHc4ZCu9FTXw@cOYd3MGwa9u8lBwjQRtgnTtjscendOF3m0OyiqydLMQfaY6NczaTWJNuNnJU93lARbJkhfoFdr84Sgce7XEk1ObRxA2Lo4SEHPfZ17TQ4G8r24WsoOstrs8nAvGTPxdyxtDadIOAr@bLz1DjqOeTnxf6JGrxI6AlqkRroAGUnrFh0SU21pXs/A3ZuSaFDXY2942DoYzzQLbR7UbCWKMpbt4GzfQzUSW00pAjzWW8/bufiAj@jJs//dQ6VNBWpic997h3026YY0sT3Z937hfyP9@K76pXJUcToenY9/dWA756XjbKvjwHIMSO7atvV7qQDQZzIvheftelK719jXgxjbVMwPrWZB1UDrDV9jWdrQK2yr33BUr6D6yKE2ZS2UWPGY4PnlK3p0q87DvFoUa5eDe3r738U03al6V66VcGpeLdYg6m4FQ781uO3fkPyGM9KRPxp76ielDo05JpmaDrh00bLPMAsFhQzTUoINjAquaWnAa5csq@hqsv0yUr9PYuq7qWk2VDybZytpKbiTE/t0P9Wj7RH9dDD5cYzRBIOnGi/YQuTi@MckAOdoy0j8H/8F)

Comment: [crocheted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233231/78850)

Answer (score 2):

## Javastack, score 11, round 10, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/233257#233257) by exedraj.

```
dfhklmquvx"
```

Game on... One more time.

[Up-to-date copy of the interpreter](https://tio.run/##rVnrbtvIFf5dP8XEyIZkxNCXxAU2WmeRBkWRRVMskrSLQlatkTiyGFMkQw5lyY7y6ul3ZobkkKJsF6iBROKcy5z7hfrCV7yY5VEmXyRpKH7EQjIRi6VIZMHO2d0Bw5/Dw9B5PXK5P/XY@RvOBmzqn459DYzTq2jGkxoDCM@eWXCeZcKGjoIgmPp83GBMI9mhn7aASSoVEKDv3D@xIGluUX2zqGYiigH6wOUioO8N1WzBieiTzKPkKpjn6fIdTt5B@TbODCfA4@dvNCquD2YG8610vQY7jFaRwjWCTI94IwiAy9TW/vt3FwieP/3JNkGYltPY3McHlpJhmcUwrwSMaROMOBnvpEERX0seW3Y4P7cMMY9TZSTi@4L/ZJEpCMRrKCvRauIFj@eG9ui0oYySWa5CpPIKH5zY0FCstbTaHCNb0UiKXGlDlAgmRuHQ1udLGiWWNQN6dm2xYpFcyYURLNBPPqvpl3wz1eZSF6gYyBFg6RIHv7Dj4Mw/rnFt38AlzSXLMpZRFm8aMOPsOQKftSPfCs4nlt8UrB2ednxmPLJgo3Y@ZGlWsRy1LJOlN8Iimz5/zi1xslx0Mo37MK4J36ln34AjqQ04S5MijUUAgXHjt2/tGxFaYY4QbEJz0ApPwHMpqgA7etVAyOIIMS6rNNQuaExPz7UUCL22n54z7rWZLaNkydeNdjsE6plPC5e/QJ0aMHf6hv/KX089K3Q0uhF31L6V7jTRBFvZd1914vVtnvMNFYRrsSncFjJcwKVVLFlt/kDDKJIbn@Es5rOqePgzRTILzPHbOHYRGp7/ssIvUA1kY4OGuQK0sqQg34g6RZ9bXivKygS4KSxnwnXX/gZY68HGsnpxw7M6kZXu@IIoajDkIsrDyvkvrXN0lFbMNCC0mygiqUwr0Lb8@cwbB0ueue6lv64Va5Vndz14eep5qhxMJk0c8Thb8KmQhqfDp7NQzK8W0ZfreJmk2de8kOXqZr25dRqir2WqixBRHFqA24xf1wBmAYpyKnM@q65BjFlRJZbpyu4AtgO57zjaLduDeZnMZJQmLC8TlzqMHyVZKYvz0djTvbbGiMXalWItzTn9UXOW6bVIqDUjT1mhrISHOY8LUT1fFunlnOc4dhyf3SxQcosMwtABu0gupDOsWc7T3CW21NlYOmedG@kvmrsNjwC1Py5DUbhE4bFnz9gTfWuHylA@aYnkMVQbGSWl2MHVegVZWSzcNs1wB3dXzTbOFiNMIeh6pdY5MA6dfvmM7K3rJ4dP71pXbA8nXp9x9zMEuDLLY6Vtow3OlUtqxO3Bzh21TR9julzIMk8M6kHDsQ63jOeFcOOo6AZcIgopwkLy2bWJOisEdwNJASmSOqyM6Ao8Oh7vd4qtzcjR@ji@Oh17e9ysoCgfcrZwj0YX4UUwHhx5DzJPyuUUvativi@IRo6MlqJwfAdKCj5b4BsyAvXNx6yR4f9oboArYueUiPFYfcaiIDp5E80IWy5y/UWRw8HUWYiyJLJ5hBoybjJMifWgFuoBJWbckyiW7zS2Zjm8z4zKM3SyJ2NaPNOMZiwQwAI96L0yGOa9yG3/KESl2g6yERoGTW9wxQ37tEkkX/81zxGHjn5g6um1xsSYxqKEkZwPa48hymO76lB8Q@VMhAj@HTv0GUtuMoFcqIiIeYnxeB4lgq54lPj/TFRgg17J9UBMA@fSGegLd01ntH0oMcwGuCfteoqSTY6ebtuGmvotWr2R7FYJFahUQcHxvMeXqCuRvCtBFGozdeoUzXBwy5rmlPWoZ55cN7Mdw7rw1Wernfo4eXpHFDCB9gGi76OYi1wkKm0/w534eJ9g5E04pfi/0xL//4YtGh9KLnx@EJIe/4GQe5uwigDjuVTl4aOeQdUXlf8fyjkiAl9@x1CC2qE4v09WURFNVZX5Cw9htK3iz2g2QPywp3c9Sp4cH3vb15OBc5E4g1o7qNWMWrewUg/l2TFGZvby2DOD2Lp/COuh/PkMlDSaVbPZtud@zFLVANzD4tbztv/podLOOPjTzpHzeRFRZX2XLpecvvw9mpOlPmEzvQnziKILj39wbfJPYoltLMaqY3wGa7IZT6gqTAUrEVQIPGa4fz1HtGKK952NEPQRRgV2pBVdUKqSZAY@38E8g6uk4meoV6DOUsllqnpGYV@9UeECKyQY@hT5fC50ZxAsjK6QNxCdFRvkz5KYTvxW7k1@jwVHAodp4shaXOtufH3BIsxzHIIWrDbXTCUOEyqC0MwKjrsQR9dUQ6MCQUVSTHnIslJJGgqoNke7ui5jrtIPdYxnUYo2tySEf0WSYyVj7/D9TC4I/FsZb9g8ggfS/Log8YOu/H8sNtAzZDAElICkv7L30ikwD1NJZO8xgMYxQX1z9KTL4W9pPKcJC8s5aiNs4RglF7B73WBNSw03CYSUdELvsJS/Zsqz8Wat0gwNPc9NHmYiX5ZSaaukd9Ax4AgYBcrV1@B8R63PcF@Wp8jWJYsK8s1NBJuQV2nKD7SS6gy62eTk475iF/MC61yeW1XO1CgcjvDPVLMXJ@PecQ4dSdVfH0PO@Yl/k/Os2hMsljb@R6GCpCHbnd6e0Gklx2h8sDP7UsHXcqlmd9wzEyjF9NZD6F6AeFtEc@nuAFRX7Zlqqvu7BBgr6X1HnypIihP/2Bs/rhlWF1jN/T7GXbY9/XGFkT4XNDP3GnpoT/fAs214onYs8l9teWBA125c4LQvEmbpMsOwqcebwh5r1N6noWFnLyEQ2u0ngXIqq67qrJxBq3AHMjUvIE7@7AVFjNRzT702F5SLyzhNKfhcNUZjkVJc1QuFCa0N2LbUyRY4x0PWPP6C74pma50OBt7dRUJ7JFbVSxg24kg7kNYYF8mktZbUK4kxQdvhJGRR6Vnr7HqVnKft4@G9G40e9L3GrNjjKgu4p77R/AEeuobtYfLycUxU/dvD4tUjWdA6sofF2SNVUXtTm8euy/3q6XSrE0RnhtcNhQppJxjYfdEwRDg8ZCu91fXIucNYD/NGQO9u8iBj2gjbjOnYHQ69O6dLPNpdFNVmafYge03065202kSb9bPSp7tKQiyTpK8wq7VlQtI491uJNqc2DTBsWzzIQe99nXtNDQbxvbRayw6xOuzKcC8bs/F3PG0tpyg4Cv9kvPUeDBzzcuL/xI1eJXQUtFiNdAMymtYjOjSm3tK8nkG4Ny3RkK7H3vBh72A90yK0ZVC7lSjKWLaTs30P9UgcNa0I@Hjeet7OxQ/EiN48@989VNZUqCY397132OeTbkqT2JN97xf@N9ZP76qfTkeVpOPR6fhXB75zXjvOtgIHVmBAc9f2rd/LBYg@k3kpPG83ktqzxr4ZxPimEn5oDQuqB1pv@BrP0oF@wrH61UjNCmqOHGpX1kqJFY8Jn5@/cem7W40e5t2iWLsc4nv@aOyp35i6DMyQqt6va1scmzeMNYoSQeHQjxpu@8crvxGQTNXc0@Yxx0JT8yFhMbnPsBIFhQzTUkIMbAxu/avvDltW8dVs@zWlsZ@U1XfT7Gy4eLbMVu1SeEdHNnQ/14PtAf2CMPlxSCdsIXJx@GMSQGSMZaT3j/8C)

I spent all day working on this, so hopefully  it holds up for at least 20 minutes...

Comment: [no](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233257/78850)

Answer (score 2):

## Javastack, score 8, round 12, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/233262#233262) by exedraj

```
kdhmujvf
```

No more alphabetical order for you, sunshine!

> Probably the last one, unless an unintended crack is found.

[Up-to-date copy of the interpreter](https://tio.run/##rVn/b9NIFv/5@lcMFYttYtwv0JOWbkEsWp1YHacVcLc6pTkyiSeNqWMbe5wmLeFf5z5vZmyPHafpSVcJ4pl57837/sX@wpe8mOZRJp8laSh@xEIyEYuFSGTBLtjdAcOfw8PQeTl0uT/x2MUrzgZs4p@OfH0Yp1fRlCc1BACePLHOeZYJ@3QYBMHE56MGYhLJDv6kdZikUh3i6Dv3T6yTNLewvllYUxHFOHrP5Tyg5wZrOueE9FHmUXIVzPJ08RY7byF8G2aKHcDxi1caFNcHUwP5RrpeAx1Gy0jBGkYmR7xhBIeL1Jb@@3cXAJ4/@clWQZiWk9jcxweWkGGZxVCvxBnTKhhyUt5JAyK@ljy29HBxYSliFqdKSUT3Gf/JQlMnYK/BrFirkec8nhnco9MGM0qmuXKRyip8cGKfhmKludXqGNqCRlLkShrChDMxcoe2PF/SKLG0GdDatdmKRXIl54axQK98VuMv@Hqi1aUuUD6Qw8HSBTZ@YcfBmX9cw9q2gUmaSxZlLKMsXjfHjLOncHzW9nzLOR9ZdlNnbfe0/TPjkXU2bMdDlmYVyWFLM1l6Iyy0ydOn3GIny0Un0rgP5Rr3nXj2DdiSWoHTNCnSWARgGDd@@9a@Ea4V5nDBxjUHLffEeS5F5WBHL5oT0jhcjMsqDLUJGtXTuuYCrte201PGvTaxRZQs@KqRbgtBrfmkcPkz5KkBcyev@Gv@cuJZrqPBDbvD9q10p/Em6Mq@@6rjr2/ynK8pIVyLdeG2gGECLq1kyWr1B/qMPLmxGfZiPq2Shz9VKNPAbLuJuGEfxNVvq8yd@M6V4/nAfl4hF0gNslFIc5M6aIVMQYYSdbw@tUxYlJU@cG1Y4lZ35a8BtRqsLRMUNzyro1opAg9wqQZCzqM8rDzhubWP8tJyoOYItSeKiCtTF7Rifz7zRsGCZ6772V/VgrVytbsaPD/1PJUbxuPGqXiczflESEPT4ZNpKGZX8@jLdbxI0uxrXshyebNa3zoN0tcy1RmJMA6tg9uMX9cHzDooyonM@dRSPnzO8jKxSJd2RagM@iaOseU42jKbg1mZTGWUJiwvE5cqjh8lWSmLi@HI07W3hojFypViJc0@/VGxlum1SKhUI25ZoRSFxYzHhajWn4v084zn2HYcn93MkYKLDMzQBrtMLqVzXpOcpblLZKnSsXTGOjfSXzRzGxoBakFchqJwCcNjT56wR/rWDpbBfNRiyWPIPjJKSrEFq@UKsrKYu22c8y3YbTHbMBu0NIWg65VYF4A4dPr5M7y3rh8fPr5rXbE5HHt9yt1NEMeVWh7KbRtscKFMUgNuDrbuqHX6ENXlQpZ5YkAPGoq1u2U8L4QbR0XX4RJRSBEWkk@vjddZLrjtSOqQPKlDyrCujofHo91GsaUZOloex1e7I2@HmdUpMoiczt2j4WV4GYwGR95e4km5mKCWVcR3OdHQkdFCFI7vQEjBp3M8ISKQ4nz0Hhn@j2bmcEnknBI@HqvfWBSEJ2@iKUHLea4fFDoMTJWGMEtCm0XIIaMmwhRbe6VQC6SYUU@gWLbT0Jrk@X1qVJahnR0R06KZZtRzAQEa6AHv5cEQ7wVu20cBKtG2gA3TUGh6w6hqflwnkq9@y3P4oaMXTK1eaki0bSxKGPG5X3o0VR7bFof8GyJnIoTzb@mhT1lynQnEQoVExEu0y7MoEXTFg9j/Z6IcG/iKrz0@DZjPzkBfuK06I@2@wDAT4Y6w60lKNjrKuq0bquu3qPaGs1vFVKBCBQnH8x6eoq5E8rYEUqjV1MlT1NPBLCtqVVbDnv5y1fR6DOPDV58tt/Lj@PEdYUAF2gbwvg9iJnKRqLD9BHPi512CFjjhFOL/Tkv8/zumavwovvD7Xkha/gMu9yZhFQLadanSwwfdk6oHFf/vyxk8Ag9/oC9B7lCU3yXLqIgmKsv8ykMobaPoM@oN4D/s8V2PkCfHx97m5XjgXCbOoJYOYjXd1i201IN5dowWmj0/9kwvturvw3owfz4DJnVnVXu26bkf7VTVEPeQuPW8zX96sLQxDv6yteV8mkeUWd@miwWnh79HM9LUR0yqN2EekXdh@SfXKv8oFpjOYow@xmbQJpvyhLLCRLASTgXHY4b61wt4K7p631kLQT9hVGBmWtIFpUpJpuHzHfQzuEoqegZ7CewslVymqmYU9tVr5S7QQoKmT6HPZkJXBsHC6ApxA9ZZsUb8LIjo2G/F3viPWHAEcJgmjqzZte7G4zMWoZ/jYLRgtbqmKnCYUB6EYlZw3AU/uqYcGhVwKuJiwkOWlYrTUEC0GcrVdRlzFX7IYzyLUpS5BQH8K5IcIxp7i@czOafj38t4zWYRLJDm1wWxH3T5/3O@hpwhgyIgBDh9zd5Jp0A/TCmRvUMDGsd06putR10Kf0vjGXVYGNaRG6ELxwg5h97rAmtKarhOwKSkHXqnpew1VZaN1ysVZijoeW7iMBP5opRKWsW9g4oBQ0ApEK6@BvtbYn2C@bI8RbQuWFSQbW4i6ISsSl1@oIVUe5DNRicb9yW7mBeY6PLcynImR2FziH8mmz07GfW2c6hIKv/6aHIuTvybnGfVnGCRtOE/COUkDdp29/aIdis@hqODrd6XEr7mSxW7456eQAmmpx4C9wL42zyaSXfrQFXVnq6mur@LgLaS3n/0iYKgOPGPvdHDimF1gVXc7yPcJdtTH5do6XNBPXOvos/t7h5wtg5P1IxF9qs1DwjI2vUL7PZ5wjRdZGg2dXtT2G2Nmvv0adiZS@gI5fajQDqVVVV1ls6glbgDmZp3ECd/9YIiRui5p16bCtLF5zhNyflc1UZjkFJU1TuFMY0NmLbUzgYwx@esWf6CZ4WzsXYHA@/uMqE5EqPqZyg24gg7oNYQl8m4NZbUI4lRQdvgxGRRyVnL7HoVn6ft7fN7Jxrd6HuNWjHHVRpwT30j@R4aOoftIPL8YURU/ttB4sUDSdA4soPE2QNFUXNTm8a2yf1qdbrRAaIjw@u6QgW05QzsPm84hzvs05We6nr43CKsm3nDoHc33kuYJsI2Ydp2z8@9O6eLPNweFNVkaeYge0z065m0mkSb8bOSpztKgi0TpC/Qq7V5QtA492uJJqc2DiBsXeyloOe@zr0mBwP5XlwtZQdZbXZ5uJeMmfg7lraGUyQcBX8y2nh7Hce8nPg/UaNXCR0BLVJDXYCMpHWLDomptjSvZ@DuTUk0qKuRd77fOhjPNAttHtRsJYoylu3gbN9DNRJbTSkCPNYbz9u6eI@P6Mmz/91DpU0FamJz13uHXTbphjSxPd71fuF/I/34rvqUOqw4HQ1PR68d2M556Tib6jiwHAOSu7Zt/V4qAPSZzEvhedue1O41dvUgxjYV8@dWs6BqoPWGr7EsbegVttVXJNUrmPfNubiK0CDn59qotXhiyWPC5BevXHp2qybEvGUUK5dDEM8fjjz19alLwLSr6kW81sqxeddYgyhmFAx94XDbn7X8hlVSWnNPm8YMo01Nh5hFDz/FcBQUMkxLCTYwO7j19@Atsqyi2yZbiJpgpSGs@S7wKw1OslbgvmnvdiiPZgrSnxaHGnPDmGerwUqMCu7oyD7dTfVgc0CfJ8Y/qo8r7JAfssNDZj5q/BgH0Aj6P1Lrj/8C), with ES2020 stuff removed

Comment: [frick you](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233262/78850)

Answer (score 2):

## Javastack, score 9, round 13, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233266/100664) by exedraj

```
kdsmujvfb
```

No more constants for you  (except numbers and strings, so not really, but whatever)

> > Probably the last one, unless an unintended crack is found.

[Up-to-date copy of the interpreter](https://tio.run/##rVn/b9NIFv/5@lcMFYttYtwv0JOWbkEsWp1YHacVcLc6pTkyiSeNqWMbe5wmLeFf5z5vZmyPHafpSVcJ4pl57837/sX@wpe8mOZRJp8laSh@xEIyEYuFSGTBLtjdAcOfw8PQeTl0uT/x2MUrzgZs4p@OfH0Yp1fRlCc1BACePLHOeZYJ@3QYBMHE56MGYhLJDv6kdZikUh3i6Dv3T6yTNLewvllYUxHFOHrP5Tyg5wZrOueE9FHmUXIVzPJ08RY7byF8G2aKHcDxi1caFNcHUwP5RrpeAx1Gy0jBGkYmR7xhBIeL1Jb@@3cXAJ4/@clWQZiWk9jcxweWkGGZxVCvxBnTKhhyUt5JAyK@ljy29HBxYSliFqdKSUT3Gf/JQlMnYK/BrFirkec8nhnco9MGM0qmuXKRyip8cGKfhmKludXqGNqCRlLkShrChDMxcoe2PF/SKLG0GdDatdmKRXIl54axQK98VuMv@Hqi1aUuUD6Qw8HSBTZ@YcfBmX9cw9q2gUmaSxZlLKMsXjfHjLOncHzW9nzLOR9ZdlNnbfe0/TPjkXU2bMdDlmYVyWFLM1l6Iyy0ydOn3GIny0Un0rgP5Rr3nXj2DdiSWoHTNCnSWARgGDd@@9a@Ea4V5nDBxjUHLffEeS5F5WBHL5oT0jhcjMsqDLUJGtXTuuYCrte201PGvTaxRZQs@KqRbgtBrfmkcPkz5KkBcyev@Gv@cuJZrqPBDbvD9q10p/Em6Mq@@6rjr2/ynK8pIVyLdeG2gGECLq1kyWr1B/qMPLmxGfZiPq2Shz9VKNPAbLuJuGEfxNVvq8yd@M6V4/nAfl4hF0gNslFIc5M6aIVMQYYSdbw@tUxYlJU@cG1Y4lZ35a8BtRqsLRMUNzyro1opAg9wqQZCzqM8rDzhubWP8tJyoOYItSeKiCtTF7Rifz7zRsGCZ6772V/VgrVytbsaPD/1PJUbxuPGqXiczflESEPT4ZNpKGZX8@jLdbxI0uxrXshyebNa3zoN0tcy1RmJMA6tg9uMX9cHzDooyonM@dRSPnzO8jKxSJd2RagM@iaOseU42jKbg1mZTGWUJiwvE5cqjh8lWSmLi@HI07W3hojFypViJc0@/VGxlum1SKhUI25ZoRSFxYzHhajWn4v084zn2HYcn93MkYKLDMzQBrtMLqVzXpOcpblLZKnSsXTGOjfSXzRzGxoBakFchqJwCcNjT56wR/rWDpbBfNRiyWPIPjJKSrEFq@UKsrKYu22c8y3YbTHbMBu0NIWg65VYF4A4dPr5M7y3rh8fPr5rXbE5HHt9yt1NEMeVWh7KbRtscKFMUgNuDrbuqHX6ENXlQpZ5YkAPGoq1u2U8L4QbR0XX4RJRSBEWkk@vjddZLrjtSOqQPKlDyrCujofHo91GsaUZOloex1e7I2@HmdUpMoiczt2j4WV4GYwGR95e4km5mKCWVcR3OdHQkdFCFI7vQEjBp3M8ISKQ4nz0Hhn@j2bmcEnknBI@HqvfWBSEJ2@iKUHLea4fFDoMTJWGMEtCm0XIIaMmwhRbe6VQC6SYUU@gWLbT0Jrk@X1qVJahnR0R06KZZtRzAQEa6AHv5cEQ7wVu20cBKtG2gA3TUGh6w6hqflwnkq9@y3P4oaMXTK1eaki0bSxKGPG5X3o0VR7bFof8GyJnIoTzb@mhT1lynQnEQoVExEu0y7MoEXTFg9j/Z6IcG/iKrz0@DZjPzkBfuK06I@2@wDAT4Y6w60lKNjrKuq0bquu3qPaGs1vFVKBCBQnH8x6eoq5E8rYEUqjV1MlT1NPBLCtqVVbDnv5y1fR6DOPDV58tt/Lj@PEdYUAF2gbwvg9iJnKRqLD9BHPi512CFjjhFOL/Tkv8/zumavwovvD7Xkha/gMu9yZhFQLadanSwwfdk6oHFf/vyxk8Ag9/oC9B7lCU3yXLqIgmKsv8ykMobaPoM@oN4D/s8V2PkCfHx97m5XjgXCbOoJYOYjXd1i201IN5dowWmj0/9kwvturvw3owfz4DJnVnVXu26bkf7VTVEPeQuPW8zX96sLQxDv6yteV8mkeUWd@miwWnh79HM9LUR0yqN2EekXdh@SfXKv8oFpjOYow@xmbQJpvyhLLCRLASTgXHY4b61wt4K7p631kLQT9hVGBmWtIFpUpJpuHzHfQzuEoqegZ7CewslVymqmYU9tVr5S7QQoKmT6HPZkJXBsHC6ApxA9ZZsUb8LIjo2G/F3viPWHAEcJgmjqzZte7G4zMWoZ/jYLRgtbqmKnCYUB6EYlZw3AU/uqYcGhVwKuJiwkOWlYrTUEC0GcrVdRlzFX7IYzyLUpS5BQH8K5IcIxp7i@czOafj38t4zWYRLJDm1wWxH3T5/3O@hpwhgyIgBDh9zd5Jp0A/TCmRvUMDGsd06putR10Kf0vjGXVYGNaRG6ELxwg5h97rAmtKarhOwKSkHXqnpew1VZaN1ysVZijoeW7iMBP5opRKWsW9g4oBQ0ApEK6@BvtbYn2C@bI8RbQuWFSQbW4i6ISsSl1@oIVUe5DNRicb9yW7mBeY6PLcynImR2FziH8mmz07GfW2c6hIKv/6aHIuTvybnGfVnGCRtOE/COUkDdp29/aIdis@hqODrd6XEr7mSxW7456eQAmmpx4C9wL42zyaSXfrQFXVnq6mur@LgLaS3n/0iYKgOPGPvdHDimF1gVXc7yPcJdtTH5do6XNBPXOvos/t7h5wtg5P1IxF9qs1DwjI2vUL7PZ5wjRdZGg2dXtT2G2Nmvv0adiZS@gI5fajQDqVVVV1ls6glbgDmZp3ECd/9YIiRui5p16bCtLF5zhNyflc1UZjkFJU1TuFMY0NmLbUzgYwx@esWf6CZ4WzsXYHA@/uMqE5EqPqZyg24gg7oNYQl8m4NZbUI4lRQdvgxGRRyVnL7HoVn6ft7fN7Jxrd6HuNWjHHVRpwT30j@R4aOoftIPL8YURU/ttB4sUDSdA4soPE2QNFUXNTm8a2yf1qdbrRAaIjw@u6QgW05QzsPm84hzvs05We6nr43CKsm3nDoHc33kuYJsI2Ydp2z8@9O6eLPNweFNVkaeYge0z065m0mkSb8bOSpztKgi0TpC/Qq7V5QtA492uJJqc2DiBsXeyloOe@zr0mBwP5XlwtZQdZbXZ5uJeMmfg7lraGUyQcBX8y2nh7Hce8nPg/UaNXCR0BLVJDXYCMpHWLDomptjSvZ@DuTUk0qKuRd77fOhjPNAttHtRsJYoylu3gbN9DNRJbTSkCPNYbz9u6eI@P6Mmz/91DpU0FamJz13uHXTbphjSxPd71fuF/I/34rvqUOqw4HQ1PR68d2M556Tib6jiwHAOSu7Zt/V4qAPSZzEvhedue1O41dvUgxjYV8@dWs6BqoPWGr7EsbegVttVXJNUrmPfNubiK0CDn59qotXhiyWPC5BevXHp2qybEvGUUK5dDEM8fjjz19alLwLSr6kW81sqxeddYgyhmFAx94XDbn7X8hlVSWnNPm8YMo01Nh5hFDz/FcBQUMkxLCTYwO7j19@Atsqyi2yZbiJpgpSGs@S7wKw1OslbgvmnvdiiPZgrSnxaHGnPDmGerwUqMCu7oyD7dTfVgc0CfJ8Y/qo8r7JAfssNDZj5q/BgH0Aj6P1Lrj/8C), with ES2020 stuff removed

I admit defeat.

My basic idea for rounds 11-13 was that you could use `replace` to concatenate two values with something like `"string1" "string2" "xy" swap "y" swap replace swap "x" swap replace`, replacing the `x` with `string1` and the `y` with `string2`.

exedraj managed to get around this in round 11 because I had put the result in alphabetical order, so chars could just be removed from the `ascii` constant. This was exploited more in round 12, so I created this one and replaced `ascii` with `char`. However, this was exploited even easier.

exedraj's trick was to `wrap` the stack, stringify, and remove commas. I couldn't bypass this because even if I removed `w`, they could use `pair pair pair pair pair` etc for effectively the same result, and I needed all the chars in `pair`.

So, that's it for now.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233266/78850

Answer (score 2):

## Vyxal, score 250, [cracked properly by Aaroneous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236409/101522)

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijmnopqrtuvwxyz{|}~¡¢£¤¥¦§¨«¬¯°±²µ¶¹»¼½¾×Þßæð÷øĊċėĠġİĿŀŻżƈƒƛǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔȦȧȮȯɖɽɾʀʁΠβελτḂḃḊḋḞḟḢḣḭṀṁṄṅṖṗṘṙṠṡṪṫẆẇẊẋẎẏ‛„‟†‡•…‹›⁋⁰⁺⁼⁽₀₁₂₄₅₆₇₈₌₍€₴℅⅛←↑→↓↔↲↳↵⇧⇩∆∇∑√∞∧∨∩∪∴∵∷≈≠≤≥≬⊍⋎⋏⌈⌊⌐□⟇⟑⟨⟩꘍ꜝ
```

Frick you with your bullcrap inf. That stops now. No more inf. (at least, not easily).

**Edit**: It took us a while, but we finally got there. Aaron got my intended solution 100%.

Comment: [...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236409/101522)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), score 20

```
[+`'"cv-0123456789*]
```

Good luck! This could be quite easy or quite hard.

Comment: [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236967/104752)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), Score: 2, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207578/46076)

Not too difficult, but I don't think this can be made harder in Befunge.

```
=,
```

My solution:

> `4b*:d0p'<1+1k @`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207578/46076)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, Score: 30, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207671/9365)

Outputs to `STDOUT`. Perl has so many ways to generate chars so I've probably missed a few alternative cracks, but here goes...

```perl
"'/0123456789<CMFQSV\^cmpqsv|~
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207671#207671). Indeed I'm sure TIMTOWTDI.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, Score: 2 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207658#207658))

Output (X):

```
.
```

(a dot and a newline)

Never golfed before, but saw this and couldn't resist trying; probably will be cracked within the hour, considering it's not really that complicated. My intended solution output to standard error.

Comment: Welcome to the site! [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207658/81278), although it probably wasn't what you were intending.

Comment: For reference, there was a previous Java answer (now removed) by @user that used the Unicode character escaping trick -- you're probably going to have to include numbers, backslash, or 'u' in the answer in order to prevent this. Also, the newline doesn't make it any harder, since in Java you can just remove all newlines without affecting anything.

Comment: Never knew about that Unicode trick, should've looked up whether something like that was possible before posting. The newline was more a side-effect of the way I did it than actually intended to make it difficult.

You're correct, that's pretty different from my solution. Am I allowed to repost/edit with a modified version that patches previous cracks?

Comment: I think you can repost a modified version

Comment: As the OP for the question I back up user's claim.  You are free to post a modified version. Other's (including me) have already done that.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), score 26 [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207664/53748)

```python
[2517630984, '\\`"a_put']
```

The same as the output of **[this program](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EIdrI1NDczNjA0sJER0E9JkEpMb6gtEQ99v9/AA)**.

---

This may well get cracked fairly quickly so apologies in advance if I am not around promptly to acknowledge it!

Comment: This can probably be cracked via the unicode tricks used in the most-upvoted robbers answer.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate In Python 2?

Comment: I haven't tried and do not know when that "feature" was introduced, so I may be wrong.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/ - introduced in 3.0

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207664/48931)

Comment: @Sisyphus - Nice I almost added `=` and `*` to the output, but you went the whole hog anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), Score: 35, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207688/9365)

```
"'/0123456789<CMPQSTVY\^`cmpqstvy|~
```

Foiled in my last attempt I'll try another more restrictive set...

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207688#207688)

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Nice work! I've got one last attempt to share but will have to be a much higher score!

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (Browser), Score: 34. [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207712#207712)

`ABDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ1234567890`

Shouldn't be too hard compared to the other ones.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've slightly edited your answer to fit the standard format used around here. Good luck, and hope you don't get cracked!

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207712/81278)

Answer (score 1):

## Java, score 2 [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207710/95792)

```
yC\
```

This is supposed to be printed to stdout. The `y` doesn't let you use `System.out.println`, the `\` is so you don't use Unicode escapes, and the `C` is so you don't use reflection. This isn't super hard - I found it with my first Google search to make an answer to this question.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207710/81278)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (Browser), Score: 27 [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207717#207717)

`ABDEFGINOPQTUVYZ234567890tf[`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207717/78410)

Comment: If you're intending to submit a third cop answer with "ABDEFGINOPGTUVYZ234567890tf[evalsic", please do so as a separate answer.

Comment: ok. sure (stuff to fill the required characters)

Comment: Brony? Greetings (My username is formerly TwilightSparkle)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, score 6, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207725/78410)

```
(\SuC)
```

Alright, added 3 more characters. Same concept as before, but harder this time.

My solution:

> []["fill"]["constr"+[[][0]+[]][0][0]+"ctor"]`a${[]["fill"]["constr"+[[][0]+[]][0][0]+"ctor"]`a${"ret"+[[][0]+[]][0][0]+"rn "+[[][0]+[]][0][0]+"nescape"}````console.log%28"%28%5c%5c%53%75%43%29"%29`}```

Comment: [Cracked (in two ways)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207725/78410)

Answer (score 1):

## Part 2: [PicoLisp](https://picolisp.com), score: 18 [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/207867#207867)

```
Segmentation fault
```

or (similar):

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

(output to STDERR)

A bit harder than my previous answer. . .

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1713394) be considered a crack? The output shown there is correct (assuming it's been reproduced accurately), but running on [TIO](https://tio.run/##K8hMzs/JLC74/19DXcNQwUhTwUzz/38A) produces leading and trailing garbage.

Comment: @Dingus Almost, but that has spaces (it [seems to work](https://jdoodle.com/ia/55) ). If it produces a `Segmentation fault` it's fine (with or without garbage) because if you run it as `pil file.l` it won't create garbage. If in doubt, see if you can install picolisp.

Comment: Ah yeah right... I completely overlooked the spaces! Segfaults without them too, though.

Comment: The output I get from pil for a space-free version of the code is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Not sure this is valid. Even if you allow the `(core dumped)` bit, my code contains both `(` and `)`...

Comment: @Dingus Well, I know a solution without `(`,`)`, or ` `.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear, I meant not sure *my solution* is valid. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Dingus based on the crack for Wezl's other cop, `[[0]]` works, I don't want to post this myself, since it's basically just your suggestion, but [try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8hMzs/JLC74/z862iA29v9/AA "PicoLisp – Try It Online"). Is this valid Wezl?

Comment: @DomHastings Yes, that's perfect (not *exactly* what I had in mind, but shorter). Don't be afraid to post it as a crack, It isn't very similar.

Comment: @DomHastings Feel free to post yours. I was going to answer as CW anyway - mine is literally the first Google hit for `picolisp segmentation fault`, so I don't deserve too much credit.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207867/9365)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When picolisp segfaults on my machine, it doesn't print anything, it just segfaults. If you're running it from a shell, _the shell_ may print a message (depending on how it's configured, the locale, etc.), but this message does not come from the program. If the intended solution was to make it segfault, this is invalid for the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), Score: 9, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207861/92901)

```ruby
.'"?%([:<
```

My code outputs with no trailing newline and works for Ruby 1.8.7 onwards. By design, string creation is difficult.

**Edit:** I've posted a [new version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/208876/92901) hardened against the weaknesses found by @DomHastings and @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'. Because my code is almost unchanged I'll hold off on revealing it.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207861/9365) although I imagine this wasn't your intention...

Comment: @DomHastings Most definitely not! But isn't that Ruby + Bash?

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, I guess. Thought I was pushing it a little...

Comment: Using a shell escape works on Ruby on any POSIX platform, and the challenge allows cracks that only work on a specific implementation. So it's legit. Cc @DomHastings Dom's solution is a bit iffy because it requires bash, not just any POSIX platform, so it's a constraint on the presence of an external tool and not just a choice of implementation.

Comment: If you push an updated challenge that forbids backquote, be sure to also arrange to forbid `putc` which prints character by their numerical value.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I originally banned all digits when I was writing this challenge, but removed that restriction (forgetting about `putc`) at the last minute. I'll post a tightened version.

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, score: 17 - [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209449/87986)

```
0123456789abcdefo
```

I'm going to ban you from using numbers, too! What can you do now?!

Comment: That's just rude and mildly inconvenient. :P

Comment: @Lyxal So can you crack it? (It's not hard to anyone familiar with ><>.)

Comment: [It was extremely inconvenient, but cracked lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209449/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## ><>, score: 19

```
0123456789abcdeflol
```

I could've made it 18 but just for the `lol`s

Comment: [once again, cracked lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209452/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, Score: 1 [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/209516#209516)

```
?
```

No command line flags were used.

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209516/9365)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP7, score: 15 ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209789/76153))

```
funtim(){}_=/\~
```

Comment: [Cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209789/9365)

Answer (score 1):

## [Setanta](https://try-setanta.ie/), score 3, [cracked by Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/210385#210385)

Probably an easy one.

```
N I
```

Here's my solution:

```
n:=go_téacs(go_uimh("!"))[0]sp:=go_téacs(gníomh(a){})[1]i:=go_teacs(eas@mata(1000))[0]scríobh(n+sp+i)
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210385/92901)

Answer (score 1):

## [AlphaBeta](https://github.com/TryItOnline/alphabeta), score: 12, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214825/92901)

```
abcdefghijkl
```

I think this will get cracked quick, but I can't come up with anything else for AlphaBeta.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/214825/92901)

Answer (score 1):

## ARM Assembly (GAS, Linux, no libc), score: 7, safe

Textual assembly, not machine code.

```
bpsBPS.
```

This makes it so you can't use `bx`, `bl` `blx`, `push`, `pop`, `svc`, `swi`, `str`, `stm`, `syscall`, `mrs`, or any assembler directives. Good luck trying to run a syscall or switch to Thumb.

You can assume your code is placed under this exact header, so don't worry about declaring the function.

```
        .text
        .arch armv5te
        .arm
        .globl _start
_start:
```

Should be pretty easy for those who are familiar with ARM's assembler.

[My solution](https://gist.github.com/easyaspi314/3afcce27a97938dab9e91c687f0a7125) I can't get code blocks to work properly in spoilers, so here's a GitHub gist.

Comment: Code blocks in spoilers can be made by prepending the first line of code with `>!<pre><code>`, prepending all subsequent lines with `>!`, and appending `</code></pre>` to the last. Example: if your code was `a\nb\nc\nd\ne` (with `\n` being a newline, of course; I can't put newlines in comments so this is the closest equivalent), you would type `>!<pre><code>a\n>!b\n>!c\n>!d\n>!e</code></pre>` (once again, with `\n` being a newline).

Answer (score 1):

## [x86 Assembly (gcc, Linux)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), score: 8, safe

Here is one for you x86 programmers.

Textual assembly, 32-bit x86 Linux.

```
RrL%ljJ.
```

Your dilemma:

- You can't use any assembler directives because `.` is banned.

  - You are stuck in AT&T syntax
  - You can't hand-encode instructions with `.byte`, `.asciz`, etc.
- Because you lack `%`, it is impossible to use anything that refers to registers.
- You have libc, but since you can't use `CALL`, `JMP`, `Jcc`, `LOOP` or `RET`, it is impossible to use.
- You can still `INT $0x80`, but since you can't refer to registers, it is impossible to set up.

If you didn't already hate AT&T syntax, you definitely will now.

The header to define the function is provided for you, as well as a template on TIO.

```python
        # String to print (w/o quotes):
        #    "RrL%ljJ."
        # 32-bit Linux, glhf
        # theb  $est(%syntax),%ever
        .att_syntax prefix
        .globl main
main:
```

[TIO template](https://tio.run/##TY5BDoIwFET3nOIHJYGEYgI7jmBY6QFMSz6lprTafhQub8VohFlMJvNmMdx7HISemWzbAD/t4ExOGQlk4bYEgvR5sHAfLaHP6mjdLYpPrkn09VjEm74qmVAEjTLjlIPUfbeB1KMA2KOnNPGzIT5leYIPdP9NwYkuX7QcwE5NK5LaCg0DVyb6WB1CeLWd5tIHNlTlGw)

I actually wanted this to be cracked so I can post an eviler one, but whatever.

My solution: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVVRb5swEH7vrziRRCMbYQmla5T8glV92h6jqTJwgFuCGTYL@fPLzsCAEJpM2ikyGH@@u@/us8OkxL2XHBeR75@gsQl8VzlPI1ACMnpRYB4@C/hZCIVyvrnrcGTGt/x5lrw@2Ubv@72z8LiCZ54WpQVREoe9RRWjBzBFqcyZPKaKlXNrhr8wbzE2U@qlXqIEMORltxQlwktgz3h6p4fNKStkDFN3Wz/DT6vmbd0863k4NoqMbTW96cqp0ewmKtzUXpel8@D6j86DQ2vSa2I9ultfnmwewrLNuFohm7p/C4BEy5RH@XLIucL5JZJINEifkFQvUFiqEeC6dRkQMME0UvEIbNXCPB1ZBaLoeZvAVygkVvAQPPSZnnH1QYKMRa4wt6EhDb4okgBYIgUcRP5mn8UKoTOKJTMwU5HNr2G8f8BIfhsTDDETkIr5b32x7sC1gEprwdoCGj@2P/jR@aZuw5lv@gLUfgFaokfIMeJS9cQ6tJo5l1CkexHwkGMAnjq0eC2luivOusZXMjApo@4sUY7nfNl5TrodHvG7xreznWbcY04JjnFv/Ko4R1Ic3yMJQMBKcznEmGMlXJpQRTIMLiNdCzOosu7gwMGN3Tcc/NfumtB47bQRb0ufRUufM0ufoiYA6Ve/cb3A39u@gzYh0JlUw2BKwy0NVu2@oiIsuTIDkSqf5XSphJvBJdDdWI3TZfllXUvO6LmV3riojcS4vFiWpXsuTOP1qYP58r0TYtC/hY0pnY7Tbz9MWCRPi/298wc)

Answer (score 1):

## LUA 5.1, Score: 22, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218715/92901)

### Output

`0123456789 "#$&'*+-/\a`

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218715/92901)

Answer (score 1):

## Lua 5.1, Score: 35 [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218862/90587)

### Output

```
 !"#$&'*+-./:;<=>?@GaLl\`0123456789
```

Comment: I count only 35 characters. Has SE gobbled an unprintable?

Comment: Nope, you're right, its my bad. *fixed*

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218862/92901)

Answer (score 1):

Gforth, 3 bytes

(That's a space, followed by a tab, followed by a newline)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218812/94093) using a vertical tab.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), Score: 35, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218880/95671)

```
p
-
;
16.0112.01568.03136.021952.0
```

Note that there should be a trailing newline (technically it's impossible to do it without the trailing newline).

This should be relatively easy to crack...

As it's been cracked, here's my implementation - feel free to try to solve this a different way and teach yourself the language!

> `` 7|s[+]`b*~,b*~*b*b*~b=+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++,++++++++++++++, ``

There is an online interpreter available [here](https://tio.run/##7T1rd9u2kt/1KxBqE4u2JIty0qRKnGeTsznnbtuTZO/9oCgtJUISbyhS4SOOu9789e4MHiQAgpQUJ9tt9/reOhYeA2BmMC8MoO1lvk7is9@7ZHA8IIskCOPVhBT5cnAPSzqO43SepdTPaUCSmLxZF@RJsSLeGRndm9y@Nzm7S8aj8ajTeewXACmdkB/8OKRR5/FHmmZhEk@INxwNzxgg@MF/8oQEyaRD4If9CugcQC6LeJFDhxukqql@bfz3lPhlIwIwYMBk4@fhwo@iS5LlSQotYuKnqX9Jwphs6CZJL6EoIJvkIyX5mpJtEsY5TbE7fozpp5x89KOCVoPQKKMADVa8oXGePSJJChWXc0r@WWQ5iZNcq30wGJCLdbhYkwUOvsiJn5kwSI9BDnNSZGKOq2Xkrx65Ai34@0MRLt6TbZqsUn@TKeh5Ef72262nxW@/Xd14OV2dvPLm2c2z6Wg@mr8bzVY378CfHv75dOaNRiTMWAdsTwbEj2C1MSDpI40uJxqs7HXmvfay8c9nKlCvAjougbJpXCDoNY2ihFwkaRSwwqupd/5hdmOQnTzMpqsHNz9PR@fbD7PVIHs4@3zubcliTRfvM8R3RgEDSyDMtsgR1DYNN5Ss83ybTU5PgfPoKomWQ8Da4j39tFj78YoOF8nm9ENBM6R5dnrn7nfe3dMwG@Rr@BUXmzlNB/6AQRLTGX2YTbezETAYhVGh2eSwIb4b3z0bn4abbcRIB9DzFBh7sPEX6zAWowCp80PBjs9GpxmDO4DeA0Fn0gN@ohNytUWU/PjTG@BxBC6q@2ROFz4yDXIrR92KAkNt/TSDHXmxpsDnPjA79EbOpJttfumyWT69Nb9VLJd@lNwiwDmr0WK8OMserjz273R@e35nNp7fgf/dBqqPvxhjY@/e@N7t06TIYXaDOR/yS/@tuH5Oc9yonEs4qTkzUZAxV8vRfeC85UxjvGXJd7ArJQCJwMukkDu0YALDDwKUd7Afl9huObKJHePXVQajjU6Ax2CkB8efcTSUD1cvxw9q5YQMHhKyhAGTNPQj0kuiYMKBDAQU1hS6zD4/WCF84gphwH69AMiM5lwYcPJvUAgBBSisbIkiDznjCiRMuFpz6bT2P6KQuSRXRxlnBdh2uPwLP8b@UR4CF3JwWV@KpFsot3zYpcBaPsyY9EBcXYRRZMjZBVMGlaBF8cq4EZgRGDe/3IIIBdkPegVUCcnWSREFMNf6TEAmLJIYuJ3GCHHtp8EACRKIlV6E@RpnJ5AA@Eu5CM5RmCYxCn3EQwhSNsPZV21dsSzylo2KP/STj5tvQt7e2iYgmZO3t8Zv1UFxIZc0uzXuEwpoua1DhBKGjBVIUjJ1oKHTJ9DU4cD4x9szNhxs4@cTpAsqJPgvTgDiwgfEwAZKgR9AM5IeHa6G5G3sIv98KBAK6rWNn4K47Dn9IxcgAEKRZ0H34JpjnJKQnzGj8AUQoIgjmmUMrUFSzCPGEZthufB3gHNeEfSrXRBBV9jusLuQ6PAv0Gp@SVLkKSB2jp@LDH@/GntIKhA7JA3BCFgyjgNhgKOaE4d9x9blODnIB8e5wt4D2Af8c0eaALih4CegS848PaSBqyi9VZTMYc@gbFM/S/2fqYUp3QJPqiVcGD3Jn8eBWpwn25@Wr1GWqaVoOfgrqhYJM0EtipJk@ywpyuKuUg4gU238RZGmoD2eJZsNsNXLOKCfTFjG1Ba8aWY2@1uY5bZ2z5LtpbkIGjzBLakVU9hiULxSC8H6eAHWh7ZgYID8KchgfdGi5XgnCWzT34GE7H24fZOoJTQOXgjg5vzCWNbYpiKGqOGqPoEXlnobZBXNWp9tSIHxbbrBgEbOycBTK7RpQO2UCwvLGrByOutf@/8z0kV9jrYBbtko3IBIh/0NAmmI@3gpaKgtFgZvQqvQQsoKX/hg6FZ1BgHrDTjNq8U34QdacHXcLbeXXiR2Ylko7Xr5WexpHGk0I8dEGrGVBCibyl1WzUrZS0qh3ElQ9GMiLEGxP7SFyj2jFSr7y1g9@6XIK6h@kwp/RCWMHJbjIEjiI9T0cQDynqZpAhqFU/bCxptHR0eVCXGFQvW@JLJX/jUesh/58cf7ZJqjfYmGEiyq4K4M02rc4UHdxnHF3DHA5KISp1x9b/xPyGnomDA3K5sxhwkN3W2RrXlPZl32pekBZaCI@tJcuJLsuwxTtHykBu1XngTXjfk6TYrVmhf33CF5uRQ6OETDxrkCDc3Wg3YKWijMisqkGRVyp0Sf1JD8hCAuwoz2UY0z2MpeWNpmxnxPYZP7wnQVQ2NrVrWh4CwH3KQA7c41GA6MKn@Dqj0PcXK9cEiJx7qwtmkBQC7CBXXRuMy2dIGW5cLH@Y2wiEPKAONItxAJiYqPA0MO8TzxKQfNHbk6j3DmYlbxOTOOhwAv8he05xCn7zi8OZeBskW2jcK859yHSuFEhygaeCPYfQYrhssekELiSKj8sla0wCoJ@MpxcQ@fn4NRoTSv7WZBd6VBZfvBNmzpWR9Na1t@ECszm3szK5aUpVgnz0RCr5qIq9WmNC/SuI4cJCFyGiKw6qtDhlFZExj16O3bI2Pc2vKrD9U63r51@hKjfc@tAejU0arLMC76OEeIf8BM33pM@nXRpRgwwy9TPFuwbpkPAVuxdBvKnmNV7ubpZTVw02IEiW4p9EDsUfDs27Cnwa68B7roOT4M4JATtJd7CMatI0ZOlcnCrOdOHd/R2Qkt520@aeyJgDtmhTf0t1tQrz3Wym1YOza07qeIxiqnIWd4bXup@iA3gznrGpbqGFIGdJuHsiPKhqStn2WSoVTLKaukjTeZzEQl@s5I5hRDFgwBZXtXWXpZOA1niumDH2u7WkethgEudpkUytmWB7y5NsHBp6iQRvYEc8SgSAnTG9XHEX@cEM9KnqqvPmlpUUANOHSKgccm3efd3FpzYYDYuoihXH2crind@oS3LhEsO/bLQVxDU3RR2clKbpsMlVomCXkt0lk2nJBuduFv2WcwWECnRmEMYibypefGemvU6zKUFdLg7QlY1Zq6Jn67JUOWJW39OUumyYbpXhJutglYtFuaLn9ZCEsWhJ8whN9gE2GIcsNXqei52t6u8AEmWQRutMWWfkCQ@0ssK1xWn3I2tUBQONkG/6TGZVIJWRrfZLaghdur9mKZD8XyT8gdiwbj/OX8LMKoiNYAVdCQ/BAGLMwB/IExC/gTZP6nEINmMTeIHjl1uT1Pqf9eXYXCaSzsyHUH8BoG7oHLwBrkGq8v/gUO0@1Tmi80s0dRkMqCoEJ1Dm6gfrRaCo4z/Cd4OWprRa4yXawRwG5jdGTYxdjLS9z7agBmm2RZOI8oeDwoLZyRNz67fee7u/e@//zr41vvHg2dLrmFezilGXMMfDBHQVoyywQNUh6cq4R0THEvJtASHILSn@AYfseib4@YRyGrOKJL/a@7aNxz81kRDyeRRrHv6tiOE1gtSntopS7SNRWiGFRqXuyj840YHyvaTE0BZzrwUMOwTid6JwWY2rpuhXKrsFfi4xgJ4NaFgfILaa3uc7HKg2JfloCRFhkq1THKKs3k95m/vKi0XukDvGM@ANQraOet4Xelet/pBnXlcJdOso5xm0dejvlovzEfWccc7xx0XB9VDo2j3DCcgJoJhVMcWqaoT3UZJX6OAHVmrDNe1QWFQNXN3W1lmVM3/RdfD4PYmn@ut8dpCIabCi6bWdSZAuRXOxDTaTK7PbZ3E2O6lgHBS0C8o9nKUDTp8rOujHXn0Q0ZBtO5psHLMIQQB7rbz4B23BDF@fIP7l7eg2aLGFYYwOmzgxlBfoM9pYj@IVygBPovDbZz4kz8IOjrhQNnkhXzHDWdUXPsTMQJ06VRc@pMgvBjGFCj/MKZsFPlf@ChslH3ypnIE4k@6SLSR@wHLEE8@xSnXzz@EoQrHsNhR1A97xyW3ifjc3640Sdn52wLuGTAjqLnNEouGKkCmvthBJSeg4YGgYqGKh58MICZPqEMFo4RL2OeK2cC@tQofOBMBMf9kFzERuXDsvI/t0bVzzAGzX/mtUbdFrqlsTnSDWeCytIoXTgTfr5mlE9xDWBZ/S1JzKFnzgRUnaXiJpA1CYooMcr/DWCBtW2UprgCES5lutyoP3cm1RZ@/qEAmWm0@EWiJ/g7hg1fxq@53LA2znFBSGQZfDbq@4g0APYMbLMn5lx84G@M9L6MwzJ2bw7wRLT5CSx2nzfo8tPPpCzBHA9MElmydBGYzoLF2BJ9@zobQCTWfmob7zXiL6KL/AW4DCwObTSYS9K@SX6uzEGj0VOx7Cdx8ApsNHujUDR6Cbhe1Wo/OJMPRZgLK9uofCn2wksM3hh1S2CkT3RR5LSBJgFIA0z7qY6Fah4E/vy3YoazCIMqrNgHF4wpB1z0Eym7TxxXyGKt8RQ/zNxKcZreJiefmWeEPmgYZyHmCZC//wcIDzwG54eW4LStQFY84v1BtYW8Jg/ZSXkBS0MXNYaZFQwaH7jLAurMvFUyh5IUW@sZTjg4i48AtAEJh3TIDvh9oOOCndCKWDLmOQlXBdpixdHyiAXgUaLxfCNuU1P0/VFmCl@rHI7ZiQbJSvwxIumGY/uB3M6zwfrh347Twpazwcazum93PKidzNaPxUozUdXCjpzOBCQS0VGrWTFaFdozaGcpxkP9lK0cT9s/jRGBF8wV4WEBC46mxsJnbt1V36fbtGnomYznzxyLlRvQCr81L@jbDi2HlS7fqCHw3RIN4bjFkIjZoWs/5@Q7YbhNtr2BEmiXTCNOTHmOEjRizMMLXYsnUj@E1ripFvZsQ2I94FdFRzWoM/WEQNuNXwlmyx@HB9WaA2sdDbKNuBbG@Ga7zOR7Y9tb2Lft@L051mUfzyrOLHHD6@1Gd//t1GnCS2OvxlDjF4Qbv0XI0U4KG0Z2bmdd0IiJBqA2yC6lo3SwkLJvpYnbvkdqosziDwsJ5hoRdV6MHjCQvGHjWMRCVwhRsTutQepGcE0ytyZprRRqXaV1OGPJ5QEHWJk0zRsm78F/Yd8qtmWEQLU1LEcqImWEp2oqZuaA8IFJiJHZyp0BMAn5UNCC6mttyv9B@7Gy6HtVBEtyozwWxBq02cnax@QLGkuzM3BcM24pfH8F2nKDclvCESdBdf@/z1P7wzJ@g/ERltZRzAdL1aLjdMNQAbaEDlnIXP9MHvqQ32iasIh21Z5FEsoePFAgdHRAF@EGs33TBB2AwG2DI2MTApDIy1KyRDFBE8UMU3PUB1@BirzBjnK0C0ipnekiok4wbu/oxuUmlyaQp5pAGyQSkwLQAKO1rjQv9E5jrRPSYY9OZ1onHom0dKsIz2YDhEA6nI90z8NI4oSRRENT1BvZITIEqh5Lk44l30K3qBjmgQfX0sCIklVZOReQoawOve@NXPeA2Zx6o@Pj3vzEG4gFwfyOa2UdgSGxBXZjRwRFR5hnLP42HAptasbJvS3ToylVAKBPBmxfzhRS8nV@VWLWUGfPSNH6sO1oIRKpENua/o9rqeKUXCJ1WUGf34fhCW8f/TT05bkWxz631rqYOR6TdyzNPq1YSIjHf68u1jjKJpInC2X/R7v73zAAWCiuduqTfzT1GtW7rC3zNE8erdCPEeiJ57oWvPqBRKjINSwT8MqASUZYFjpQDiWkUsfRwkLcrJnoXWtoZzjBna5CrvPz5u2hGaKKyNCbIHmqxclAuVih/MgmyoSLshhZiavlnk3beqvWJaxvs@zB7mUP2LJrlOURf7F0/oFP7lTysCjlUSl1@pgFOlbXPBKs3ydlF6O5SJQR7RNM3Wzv4OuJ8dfD0um5mK@BJft@0jtqKT42/J4K/GpaUhy0SM7ChsfnJWJFdXgYbtVe@6K3pc9XxfDxl2L4eA8MH6scrGCZxbgFikXCrzDXcKJ9JVsRDOmc@gGR9/VkjFU9Ue8ycBpF8E@OL7w/1dRP7Hu59duhsAnGttN9S5HdZLhRUxry6BZqZ5rit6he85hXby8TUBS7vpvhtUbresRdXZY/LlHUhpq9ARm8eQ3UGBZUhaddVomJp4rtytNBFUl4jznTLjIXWxsObO0YU7AMh6wp3aPRXsAkJQEIFv/992aCkqjT1GM9IcG8pGEY2rr/XE@B2DGJxok0Z0eYE7J7@Ao18CC3nR4BtNiPItjy69Fk1ECSwb4k@f7769Nk1EKSwaEkgQnV6VAdjFtlh3G939jgKlqrcUSGhLs7xFNxQxprsosZvFldSpkSyMYYTX2bRfgX3WKsUkHcdrayX0vQicXbqHJOCcohgvBsU0VQkfFLNVAXxrS8t8JTKTsiFnaDoFrG9ECOMrwsHy5AvYr8SoGY5z@9ID1@bgo6mF0Dxn78fQr1gQF2LchtuxbaYHHYbjLUTyBwnfwQXl2pcqM5q2kbyZdWvthbC7W66zzGppGG38DgpoxI@9A2DxaKG4JQRQZEZ1CG4bSI@eWMo0weh5cdQkEvvtIkVjQuUIFixoa5IdGQkpl6PXau/c7lN6RCHMHHM/ePNMXs7XBZPaRxyO3SOhrbrtMeANmSDGk/DN91vtx0PK3deWyaTEfJZq2GV6PL5mGmBZLb7XZVfaJJBEwmYLf6ZZoVN/jnKT4FkbPorZJZ0GlMRlPjGHXtIYZUWLiuE1h4nxRxHkbcPo4SdjNdTKXWXhzJtWW0s2RM6xnwXlnubQ13aFwtJ6/h8pegax03fy3kSElQ7m92xYPM/YwL8ywvlktFCYLYxxCbSJ3B8HmC9yhhtTYltQf/18@nXds9hr/Utrjege3BrGE5wN3Z@k@xg/4keLQasc0FPA2Mp4CqRkKZN2Y1EdgrA@x@Mqtmlg7eMdbsXfKur7Rhr2/xV33QEmI3kplZuAz5BfCa7WQ3hm1PabTrb6vKb3hVw3IXYm@D/OsaBbty3TTjRh5k45sreIq9x@Uus4uEd0hny6kz7EP1wFhY0@o9I5mA/6uj3uKzD6bvlnYddt5eX932@BWP@cU5pm5Je9r9Kpzk5z9qkp@VSdauUNSm@fiPmuZjZZrytoXrGnfxq9s/X3OGIE2F81PzTd2m5LEv0e2p9FhUw0VXPo0ZjOrZmteW7rUvOVAMWNvYFKa@PfdKt@wq94XVMRW3oTb3bnlSmFIj66lrvGqgDcHyhmxOym5ToBVdmIRQMUZ7U56M4H69rXHw4GRgvLbQkDZa@ogGKZpbSwI30c7QAJUCaF9hnzhvY8et7S@dWJWEv2bCoE7/axph59cEcB0l8tfEw5foqb8mJg5Uhf@3kNCqTP9EevTaiGjPZm/u@i/9@9X07x@8o/XpXxPWt1LxL@TjAs163kgdYZc5Dzp/511kVbV/BagzlwUFMvV44iY5cw/L/tiVnagBH7cmrDX380adNinS1nG0fzoktJfHHbZcQrw2y/FfZmhjUVNORxwoB5yB8ma5mf2wG8YeURV7RGNHNKSZgnSzfY1v8jTkO@xOGGl87grB2khSH7HMxtidytI@Uv0UUL/rbN1UvEl1D9N@QK2/1qq@OClyvyoWYgObl6gP2s9sBycpGfVFNC9OSHk8vCubuG2PjsiOTCtLKlvLZW9lUTuPukn7NC1MZs0Ks7QrtzI/R1Vvm6t3Hfws68pDbv6ocvUADirkCVlG4fY0xfcn8c3GeRifrkHa99it8ff4jQQX@C4ry7wAKmXU7eOVgmSD7@zIV6O98XfQkz0Dzorx5K9PFj7N/JRk63CZy7eVq2vvKm@o9NYyENizgYJZoPAL8xgYFEui1nXyF3bkKyzWNd9LMSMU0urNm1wUJTW59jaAikjiezIVT7wHsGTXPCh75Cii8Spfq5xvy14DGL/wd0ez6lV1ge15kufJxpIRTfyxrU/5dQ/AeEnMKgM5oYEQKOVdE5m8yM//YWreUG8yMupHQ/I8yngvruvVsaW4go9HmVQy1fDsZVM5P9rnYHGe7EwPZjPAhmJ1@OBKEEx42lEfX3Bjb0v1yX58ZHsIe6@HjnQB3Cm/i4CRwXj7F4Z/ojxrwxOSymf/tNdd1P5aa2YPWh/w05/hqZ7Te4J7rYSnR9rljHRzht2l0Z4kVaZT204N4o@/omzRk21vlWoif1qOakCqz36s3pET32uAj4eNuQZVl6LoSOtSuOYO88WamEdnWGW88dyQ9lah2/5qJ4OiPtDJR3Rtl06VavvZnzbjUf2OrzVrbtdSTWOGbw/dn9ZQOWrD4@hfeNTwaHXF7Q/BlYB1SfP/ApcNS27HqXyu0Hh/R@TjFzGYWiE@2d1RhAXm31cGt8jLu1xEqHXQOMKnR4X9dTI4Pr3ZJ69ePX/B1Az10wi/PCqgiDgfr4Vu/E@nG3y6VPyBLwzwq5iLJCo28WmaXPSJDwBBZp6CN4zDFJvaV1k0qKuaxmk2dbpi2hwZncYX2@SDY6YmaEh3rMNQXoGs3tzVfzUnx1qeNzJSQa0u0Q382fnVFQYS27MahHOmPaR0iDfRMPABrpCpScvXlPe/EaA7rrb0U@0NKBXV7D4ce7tOfsELf2MURQkzKLCsehfXlpTJbD2WtUHx6yPYF/WwNBB8rRK/eIfdKiXlpbQq6UmBNhbgHingAiCLDRbjjDIPBEtLaDEN5ZUjhCqySbiIa3FToKfuqZjdZHaZxTjf4ytSrvOdMrve1VRDuZ7TF7cc5fLLu6Gm6DBSyhpZtfSH@KpEDFE8p9pwX0BpLoInjkNs91U7O@LRrbPCoLgxs5ZJma2VizftbiNvL7Wk@WZ5w1FmQ0/9kET1v/X31xruDYjv0dA3Kr40lsToyTHd1MaNrddEvsL7wsbKK/vEQA4@s9Dl3wSG3/LIgh6PKlyIZ@b2CkbUA5giMzzfEX9QNjTiRO/2v3iJwgxINN6kqB@yderCXnmIr67EmnLeGmfYkMU79m7fvX3v7Lvbd2sqp7oMyR78q89h76CxReypiK/7z0kUvLEH2ZUH3TVns/o0a3evD5eY@3yHRIMXXftqhwNuau28inXI3A6Zn3WOLZJ1nznsM3btLt@BV9O@FZ2sObj1ELfOs7WXeeUFXvW6dBkSw6/90@8AkymaUyLaVl7/ZV4Is5zw24Zidssdb9uIb77N8LX1mbgRq1yNw3LxWg0G6NgXivJ4HaIKc3lZC5uUFV8SCjLW36D1xpVVbqT8yvu9psVd7rruSp5OsGd6sLc6ZzYt/kWTSoyRBQrxuw112ah8LUcHX956xr@9yHGct79fkRtkOSJL9nzSfXI8Hnr3yeDsd/YVm0pj@ed0gpZGh38loSwEZf67N/4f) - all you need to do is replace what's in the "code" section and hit run (I would recommend minimising the header and footer as well). Do not modify the interpreter code (i.e. don't touch the Python code in the header and footer).

Good luck!

## Edit

I'm deciding to give out a small hint - try playing around with functions without arguments! Some functions have default values

Comment: @EasyasPi I screwed up markdown, thanks for pointing this out. I'll edit it real quick

Comment: [I assume this is a loophole, right?](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6vrFCcl1nAVZlfWuScn5KqYKugpKQU8x9I5BcppFakJmsofZg7ZS0QrwfiZUC8Gog3aiRnFGmYmJjo65togwhNbZAAUES7zkQTVdCEKBVaJrpEqMLgaptgtQxNBI8BmFwKTdPGFMDiamLN1yXgXl2sLiDVC4RDGXvAkxxymkqa@UXAtAVKX/8B). (Interpreter code snipped because bitly hates me) 

Comment: @EasyasPi yes, that is a loophole... I guess I should sanitise my inputs in the next update! Definitely a creative answer though!

Comment: @EasyasPi it looks like your answer still uses `-` though

Comment: Nah, I am just closing the block quote you put in the online interpreter and executing Python code  and I updated the link btw

Comment: I count only 35 bytes (including the trailing newline). Are there unprintable characters hiding in there?

Comment: @Dingus you're right, it's 35 bytes. I just took the byte count from TIO for the actual program by accident.... take that as your hint for a possible solution I guess!

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218880/92901) (48 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

## Lua 5.1, Score: 50 [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218967/92901)

### Output

```
     !"#$%&'*+-./0123456789:;<=>?@G\^`ajklmpqvxyz{|}
```

Thats a TAB and SPACE at the beginning and a new line at the end.
My code to produce that is 19542 bytes long in just 1 line. Thats my last try, cause once you come behind this you can come behind everything in LUA in this Thread.

Have fun :-)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218967/92901). Only 5152 bytes so I guess it's not your intended solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [YaBASIC](http://www.yabasic.de), Score:13 [Cracked by Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220021/92901)

**X:** The string to crack:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
A
a
-
```

The language may be Basic, but is the solution?

**Y:** The language - YaBASIC:

```
print "Can you crack it?"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/v6AoM69EQck5MU@hMr9UIbkoMTlbIbPEXun/fwA)

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/220021/92901).

Comment: @Dingus - OK, you got it pretty quick! That's a good solution actually. Give me a sec and I'll post a harder version for you if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dis](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dis), Score: 1, [cracked by Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/231693#231693)

```
{
```

I have never thought of constructing the  program when I posted this.

PS. Rule clarification.

- Output exactly a character whose codepoint is 123 in decimal integer.
- Do not output else.
- Then terminate the program.
- <s>No Dis implementation whose `{` command does `putchar(codepoint of (a%256))` rather than `putchar(codepoint of a)`; if your implementation is so, reguster A must be exactly 123 when `{` is executed.</s>  deleted as reference implementation, implemented in C, uses `putchar(char)` and `char` stores eight octets (maybe not on some machines).

### Intended solution

> `*|||*__>*__>_||^___________________________*!**}}*!`
>
>  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lRZrU@JI8Ht@RRsRAgghgN5idqhz0d21ylUL9GrvBFNjMkDKkHCZRHCB3@715AFB3LvbVCWZ7un3a8aifPy6v6c@2q7Kx5K0D5bNq2zyWJ163J7bfFKFnhf6JquYnsUAd5hlMQvObA62GzB/6jP8VpHzNAzGnl@F2ylln@nsB3MF9tI2mctZFTqdGsKIueN0xMQWaFXosqlDTQayAjd3t/Dn9V0Xzi56cNO9/tI9/QZfz7vnUJRhZgfjSOnU90Y@nUT89Sqcz5kZBgyCMe7xMXMc4KZvT4OIoIHWjFnKA37o8ipcuNMwACSnzoy@cPDZ36HtM0sHgacunF9/BnsIL14IlucWAphRF@VJnAVQYaEUTih/glqtXpfYfOr5AVx2jNPLS9KRFhIABC9TBiMWmJ47hHx@jTK9yYS6lrSCtmqxZ9UN0dp6O68lRImwm9Pbr0TOKQk5VKZrYWKrmFuIX/lkFS9OKis5tePmunfx/fJPo3Pd7Z53bomWbtxdXXw3erdnpF6rNaR7kHOLT6e9r8Yf593exfWVkAGDfD7y0IMo9zFU/hRT/7VLzCahQzH0fByRetMAlzPPt/jUsYN8njo25VAZQSG30Mpy7nd5VSAF8S/k81d3l5edb2fkJBKvCFWWzsf2MNCjNQi6BMHMsQe5fawCAprQrOxBhCvcOIxyBiG@LpsxP66AQlFr5zE3z9QBeQ@G1OFMXi7/H1dkTkQ3X3Is9AJX5@qLqnP8/FALkRE/YPC@uN5d77lRBuRLpGERXnmoBQUFGFefceY/Y7X61HZsdwT4YRy8Ydx43DdPskUOPGo93BzaLjojqJEYxoxaaPYjc7yZFPNFBUODjx8LhsFc48wovCq1IpSWy2XJMNriNZbLB0nRjk9gNsa8PTNfOv7tQ6um1RvNo51VUTJ@/khKs4HC90ql1aq095qolIpyZKrPAwhm3to5GHoezgigj94zk6QJmwhrRcVPfZwhQzjg/b6LcY9dkWEp9vDZx96cIA/wKc4Ijg1iMqyyy888IQh8qGCK@kH/uT/s@1DIsIr2YW6QiPATfJTSZH1CU6Sq3D8UB6Wiqo4SlKqoi2SJT@5xs77aLB9TAausYkw0epGAQ8/BDp5p6/2Rz6ZQXYNZe7h6/1B6aC8XK2NPGaiVurre6JfUZhZ8UFvNDdhWjzObS1WrZzYXCDY24ArBow1oqK0MtKc2MqSKWtHUjWd09gSVZ4xr6AaktrY6VyOkomWCFSUV5NCd0MAco3@KvJSxNkF0hKxvCNncRmSKWGXl1Xfl2dHYHtqOGKRuQG1XnEDY47YF5pj61MQa47@kKnaFHLVqzda/Kgw8rGbPHf2S9B2JuVqGJ9JdLq@ZcLJIaaM7L9mzVfKsxxEG3HsMhzjRFelN12A/4QEgRhHDw8XDcjsFV2SqEkCYFJ5olA6HTYcL1sJ93y0NkgTHdSkVYyjJ9RwHlclQN65n1HcNLwy8oeGZAdHiAvh0/uXiKvXUJrGHUQRUtGbdQ5SYxCJr/4eer@h6MROhDimjH/fmIBMie6jEBmQJRegMYuqWQSx9C52kDRtOPqSH5qF12DmMhFqD99O22iz3QS7JW5o7hDRxCGYVWCQRp28xPuwwtprbjOb7jO0dxuM3GimJ@Qh6psRLtVFMhB00Slrr@ENjW@hyRyhOgzcBtEltO3QiH09E058@ColN/alEGtuWCK4yUYQdVH0qHjQqGZMEXG7gp/Sk/8T@n4Z98Y69b3QjmsZd@mHHqKj13njD8LwXTNsVixeSdv3oaEdCUja3vp0e0ghjBb1fM4n4d4UMQe7jc@D1XeTfTsvqHTePdtzEe150xtOPpLZjKI1DsC3XkE9aRyCuiV4wxvkH1MdbjTfdItrbUd54E@KdMP6s95Jo4b0pbbK4b41B0mu4uO72/rPhTKKYZa148NYliyjWDn61HiqpMUKVPSCbiWono1ScxGCK@1hOjE2co6DEoUyQOEQTJGICXVdKxe3zzRGXk/TCfdr9Ynw7/b5cRvO1WWsd4wUwPfni2UexmTiRZd0hjlqvaPXUS4e5o2CscMJx8hfbxFnEweN6ypJSnl@dpXtov0DqOuPUjEbxnPojvEZfwDytsrkUmR3bL@he/wE) Link to [my interpreter](https://github.com/GH-TpaeFawzen/dis.posixism/blob/main/dis.emb.posixism), with comments.
>
>  This uses that 123=11120t=1-11122t-11122t.
>  To produce 1 I had to make 00100t first by 0-01020t-01120t-01120t.
>  Then I did it `>` twice.

Comment: PS. I've just completed my program.

Comment: I don't follow the last bullet point: why does it matter how the `{` command is implemented? You say 'when `{` is executed', but `{` *can't* be executed in this challenge.

Comment: @Dingus; 1. Did I misread the specification? I couldn't see the specification that it outputs A modulo 256; or is it implicitly specified by reference implementation? 2. Outputting that character without using the character in your program is the point of my challenge.

Comment: I agree that the goal is to print `{` without using `{`, and that's the root of my question. If you can't use `{` to begin with, I don't understand the intent behind the last bullet point. Why does it matter how `{` behaves (mod 256 or not) if you can't use it?

Comment: @Dingus Deleted final bullet.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231693/92901)

Answer (score 1):

## [Javastack](https://github.com/chunkybanana/javastack), score 10, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/233193#233193) by exedraj

```
1234567890
```

Have fun ;}

My intended solution will not be posted here.

Comment: [crackèd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233193/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## [Javastack](https://github.com/chunkybanana/javastack), score 13, [Cracked again](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/233203#233203) by exedraj

```
1234567890"nq
```

Have more fun ;}

To exedraj: HR couldn't modify ><> :)

Comment: Roses are red, I did this kind of cracking comment last time, this answer is [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233203/78850), so you'll have to post a new challenge for another rhyme

Answer (score 1):

## Javastack, score 14, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233210/100664) by exedraj  - on to round 4!

```
1234567890"dqw
```

No `add`, no `duplicate`, no `double`, no `random`, no `power` - hopefully this will thoroughly bamboozle you.

Have fun!

I gave  you back `flatprint` - you're gonna  need it.

Comment: Ur a sussy baka because I [cronked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233210/78850) this

Answer (score 1):

## Javastack, score 15, [Cracked by exedraj](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/233232#233232)

```
1234567890"crsy
```

Game on, again.

[Up-to-date copy of the interpreter](https://tio.run/##rVl7b9vIEf@7/hQbIxeSEUM/Ehe46JxDGhRFDk1xSNIeClmNVuLKYkyRDLmUpTjKV09/s7sklxRluUAF2OLuzszO@0F95itezPIok8@SNBQ/YiGZiMVSJLJgl@zuiOHj8DB0Xo5c7k89dvmKswGb@udj3xwm9SHOnjyxj7JM2KejIAimPh83ENNIdvCnrcMkleoQR9@5f2adpLmF9c3CmokoxtE7LhcBPTdYswUnpA8yj5LrYJ6nyzfYeQO52zAz7ACOg3AwMxCvpes1UGG0ihSMYWB6whsGcLhMbam/f3cB4PnTn2zRw7ScxtU9A0u4sMziaMYlzpgWfcRJaWcNiPhS8tiS//LSUsA8TpVyiO4z/pOFpk7AXoNZsVYjL3g8N7gn5w1mlMxy5RWVNfjgzD4NxVpzq9UxsgWNpMiVNIQJ/2HkBm15PqdRYmkzoLVrsxWL5FouKqPolc9q/CXfTLW61AXK9jkcK11i4xd2Glz4pzWsbRuYpLlkWcYyyuJNc8w4ewpfZzWI5Y@PLJO1ndH2xoxH1tmo7f1ZmlXURi19ZOmtsNCmT59yi4ksF5244j5Flk0ZLi61umZpUqSxCOL0Gjd9@9a@CY4U5nC4xhEHLWfEeS5F5U4nL5oT0i8cissq2LTCG0XTuuYCjta2ylPGvTaxZZQs@bqRagdBrfm0cPkzJKIBc6ev@K/85dSzHEWDG3ZH7VvpTuM73rh193XHO1/nOd9gHdyITeG2gKF6Lq1syKaB3iN/bWyEvZjPqhThzxToLDDbr@PYhSt4/vMKvkDMSzsE1EYrBgqyhagD8KllpaKsRMYNYTkTrrv2N4BaDzaWlotbntVhqmTFA7ymgZCLKA8rYz@39lEiWj7SHKF@RBFxZRK81t3PF944WPLMdT/5a5z0JF13PXh@7nkq2CeTxm94nC34VEhD0@HTWSjm14vo8028TNLsS17IcnW73nx1GqQvZapTDGEc08HR9mheJjMZpQnLy8SlrO5HSVbK4nI09nRpqyFisXalWEuzTx@qhTK9EQlVQkQNK5QMWMx5XIhq/alIP815jm3H8dntAumuyGBj2mBXyZV0hjXJeZq7RJaqCkvnrHMjfaK529AIkHfjMhSFSxgee/KEPdK3drAM5qMWSx5D7MsoKcUOrJYryMpi4bZxhjuwu2K2YbboGApB1yuxLgFx7PTzZ3hvXT85fnzXumJ7PPH6lLufII4rtTyU2zbY4FKZpAbcHu3cUev0IarLhSzzxIAeNRRrd8t4Xgg3joquwyWikCIsJJ/dGK@zXHDXkdQheVKHlGFdHY9Ox/uNYkszcrQ8jq92x94eM6tTBLecLdyT0VV4FYwHJ95B4km5nKKSVMT3OdHIkdFSFI7vQEjBZws8ISKQfXzU@Qz/o7k5XBE5p4SPx@o7FgXhydtoRtBykesHhQ4DU54nzJLQ5tFKOOMmwhRbB6VQC99xxj2BYtlOQ2uSw/vUqCxDO3sipkUzzai/AQI00APey4Mh3gvcto8CVKLtABumodD0Flfcsg@bRPL1X/McfujoBVOrlxoSfRKLEkZ8HpYerYzHdsUh/4bImQjh/Dt66FOW3GQCsVAhEfESrek8SgRd8SD2/5koxwa@4uuATwPmkzPQF@6qzkh7KDDMwLUn7HqSko2OimvrhkruVxRiw9lXxVSgQgUJx/MenqKuRfKmBFKo1dTJU9RRwSxr6iLWo57ubt10Wgyt@hefrXby4@TxHWFABdoG8L73Yi5ykaiw/Qhz4uttggY04RTi/05L/P8NQyu@FF/4fickLf8Bl3udsAoBTbJU6eG97gjVg4r/d@UcHoGH39EyIHcoym@TVVREU5Vl/sJDKG2r6DPqDeA/7PFdj5Bnp6fe9uVk4FwlzqCWDmI1jdBXaKkH8@IUDSx7fuqZNmnd3yL1YP58AUxqnKrOadtzv8Ocqi3tIfHV87b/6cHSxjj6086W83ERUWZ9ky6XnB7@Hs1JUx8wFd6GeUTeheUfXKv8g1hGszTG4GFsBm2yGU8oK0wFK@FUcDxmqH@5hLeip/adjRD0FUYFJpYVXVCqlITRM1VL9DO4Sip6BnsF7CyVXKaqZhT21RvlLtBCgqZPoc/nQlcGwcLoGnED1lmxQfwsiejEb8Xe5PdYcARwmCaOrNm17sbjMxahn@NgtGC1umYqcJhQHoRiVnDcBT@6oRwaFXAq4mLKQ5aVitNQQLQ5ytVNGXMVfshjPItSlLklAfwrkhwDEnuD5wu5oOPfynjD5hEskOY3BbEfdPn/Y7GBnCGDIiAEOP2VvZVOgX6YUiJ7iwY0junUN1uPuhT@lsZz6rAwGCM3QheOEXIBvdcF1pTUcJOASUk79MpI2WumLBtv1irMUNDz3MRhJvJlKZW0insHFQOGgFIgXH0N9nfE@gjzZXmKaF2yqCDb3EbQCVmVuvxAC6n2IJuNTjbuS3YxLzBs5bmV5UyOwuYIfyabPTsb97ZzqEgq//poci7P/NucZ9WcYJG04d8L5SQN2m739oh2Kz5G46Od3pcSvuZLFbvTnp5ACaanHgL3AvjbIppLd@dAVdWerqa6v4uAtpLeOvSJgqA480@98cOKYXWBVdzvI9wl21MfV2jpc0E9c6@ih3Z3Dzhbh2dqxiL71ZoHBGTt@gV2@zxhli4zNJu6vSnstkbNffo07MwldIRy@0EgncqqqjorZ9BK3IFMdYlwz/7sBUWM0HPPvTYVpItPcZqS87mqjcYgpaiqcX9CYwOmLbWzBczpkDXLX/CscLbW7mDg3V0lNEdiVP0ExUYcYQfUGuIqmbTGknokMSpoG5yYLCo5a5ldr@LzvL09vHei0Y2@16gVc1ylAffcN5IfoKFz2B4izx9GROW/PSRePJAEjSN7SFw8UBQ1N7Vp7Jrcr1bnWx0gOjK8ritUQDvOwO7zhiHc4ZCu9FTXw@cOYd3MGwa9u8lBwjQRtgnTtjscendOF3m0OyiqydLMQfaY6NczaTWJNuNnJU93lARbJkhfoFdr84Sgce7XEk1ObRxA2Lo4SEHPfZ17TQ4G8r24WsoOstrs8nAvGTPxdyxtDadIOAr@bLz1DjqOeTnxf6JGrxI6AlqkRroAGUnrFh0SU21pXs/A3ZuSaFDXY2942DoYzzQLbR7UbCWKMpbt4GzfQzUSW00pAjzWW8/bufiAj@jJs//dQ6VNBWpic997h3026YY0sT3Z937hfyP9@K76pXJUcToenY9/dWA756XjbKvjwHIMSO7atvV7qQDQZzIvheftelK719jXgxjbVMwPrWZB1UDrDV9jWdrQK2yr33BUr6D6yKE2ZS2UWPGY4PnlK3p0q87DvFoUa5eDe3r738U03al6V66VcGpeLdYg6m4FQ781uO3fkPyGM9KRPxp76ielDo05JpmaDrh00bLPMAsFhQzTUoINjAquaWnAa5csq@hqsv0yUr9PYuq7qWk2VDybZytpKbiTE/t0P9Wj7RH9dDD5cYzRBIOnGi/YQuTi@MckAOdoy0j8H/8F)

Comment: [yesn't](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233232/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## Javastack, score 16, [ingeniously  cracked by exedraj for the eighth time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/233236#233236)

```
1234567890gbsort
```

You thought the last one was hard...

[Up-to-date copy of the interpreter](https://tio.run/##rVl7b9vIEf@7/hQbIxeSEUM/Ehe4@JxDGhRFDk1xSNIeClm1VuLKYkyRDLmUJTvKV09/s7sklxRluUAF2OLuzszO@0F94UteTPMoky@SNBQ/YiGZiMVCJLJgF@z@gOHj8DB0Xg9d7k88dvGGswGb@KcjXx/G6XU05UkNAYBnz6xznmXCPh0GQTDx@aiBmESygz9pHSapVIc4@s79E@skzS2sbxbWVEQxjj5wOQ/oucGazjkhfZJ5lFwHszxdvMPOOwjfhpliB3AchIOpgXgrXa@BCqNlpGAMA5Mj3jCAw0VqS/39uwsAz5/8ZIsepuUkru4ZWMKFZRZDrRJnTIs@5KS0kwZEfC15bMl/cWEpYBanSjlE9wX/yUJTJ2CvwaxYq5HnPJ4Z3KPTBjNKprlyjcoafHBin4ZipbnV6hjagkZS5EoawoQTMXKDtjxf0iixtBnQ2rXZikVyLeeVUfTKZzX@gq8nWl3qAmX7HI6VLrDxCzsOzvzjGta2DUzSXLIoYxll8bo5Zpw9h8OztsdbTvnEsps6a7ul7ZcZj6yzYTsOsjSrSA5bmsnSW2GhTZ4/5xY7WS46EcZ9ijGbMpxdasVN06RIYxGAUdz07Vv7JrhUmMP1GpcctNwS57kUlWMdvWpOSNNwLS6rsNOqb1RO65oLuFzbPs8Z99rEFlGy4KtGqi0EteaTwuUvkJcGzJ284b/y1xPPchkNbtgdtm@lO40XeaPW3dcdP32b53yNdXAj1oXbAobqubSSI5sEeo88t7ER9mI@rZKFP1Wg08Bsv41jF67g@S8r@ALRL@1gUButaCjIFqIOxeeWlYqyEhk3hOVUuO7KXwNqNVhbWi5ueVYHrJIVD/CaBkLOozysjP3S2kfFaPlIc4RyEkXElUn1Wnc/n3mjYMEz173yVzjpSb/uavDy1PNU2I/Hjd/wOJvziZCGpsMn01DMrufRl5t4kaTZ17yQ5fJ2tb5zGqSvZaqTDWEcWgd3Gb@pDxgdHGwOZmUylVGasLxMXEr8fpRkpSwuhiNPl8AaIhYrV4qVNPv0oZop0xuRUMVEOLFCCYfFjMeFqNZXRXo14zm2Hcdnt3NkxCKD8WmDXSaX0jmvSc7S3CWyVHhYOmOdG@kTzdyGRoDUHJehKFzC8NizZ@yJvrWDZTCftFjyGJKCjJJSbMFquYKsLOZuG@d8C3ZbzDbMBp1FIeh6JdYFIA6dfv4M763rx4dP71tXbA7HXp9ydxPEcaWWx3LbBhtcKJPUgJuDrTtqnT5GdbmQZZ4Y0IOGYu1uGc8L4cZR0XW4RBRShIXk0xvjdZYLbjuSOiRP6pAyrKvj4fFot1FsaYaOlsfx1e7I22FmdYqol9O5ezS8DC@D0eDI20s8KRcTlJiK@C4nGjoyWojC8R0IKfh0jidEBNKSj1Ygw/9oZg6XRM4p4eOx@o5FQXjyNpoStJzn@kGhw8BUAAizJLRZtBTOqIkwxdZeKdTCd5xRT6BYttPQmuT5Q2pUlqGdHRHToplm1AIBARroAe/lwRDvBW7bRwEq0baADdNQaHqLK27Zp3Ui@eqveQ4/dPSCqdVrDYkuikUJIz73S48ex2Pb4pB/Q@RMhHD@LT30KUuuM4FYqJCIeInudRYlgq54FPv/TJRjA1/xtcenAXPlDPSF26oz0u4LDDOY7Qi7nqRko6MU27qhWnyHCm04u1NMBSpUkHA87/Ep6lok70oghVpNnTxFrRbMsqL2YjXsaftWTQvG0M1/9dlyKz@On94TBlSgbQDv@yhmIheJCtvPMCe@3ifoTBNOIf7vtMT/3zDc4kvxhe8PQtLyH3C5twmrENA9S5UePupWUT2o@P9QzuARePgdvQRyh6L8PllGRTRRWeYvPITSNoo@o94A/sOe3vcIeXJ87G1ejwfOZeIMaukgVtMh3UFLPZhnx@hs2ctjz/RPq/7eqQfz5zNgUkdVtVSbnvvRAlX9ag@JO8/b/KcHSxvj4E9bW87neUSZ9V26WHB6@Hs0I019wuB4G@YReReWf3Ct8k9igWEpxkRibAZtsilPKCtMBCvhVHA8Zqh/vYC3otn2nbUQ9BVGBUaZJV1QqpSE6TRVS/QzuEoqegZ7CewslVymqmYU9tVr5S7QQoKmT6HPZkJXBsHC6BpxA9ZZsUb8LIjo2G/F3vj3WHAEcJgmjqzZte7G4wsWoZ/jYLRgtbqmKnCYUB6EYlZw3AU/uqEcGhVwKuJiwkOWlYrTUEC0GcrVTRlzFX7IYzyLUpS5BQH8K5IckxN7h@czOafj38p4zWYRLJDmNwWxH3T5/2O@hpwhgyIgBDj9lb2XToF@mFIie48GNI7p1DdbT7oU/pbGM@qwMDsjN0IXjhFyDr3XBdaU1HCdgElJO/RqSdlrqiwbr1cqzFDQ89zEYSbyRSmVtIp7BxUDhoBSIFx9Dfa3xPoM82V5imhdsKgg29xG0AlZlbr8QAup9iCbjU427kt2MS8wheW5leVMjsLmEH8mm704GfW2c6hIKv/6aHIuTvzbnGfVnGCRtOE/CuUkDdp29/aEdis@hqODrd6XEr7mSxW7456eQAmmpx4C9wL42zyaSXfrQFXVnq6mur@LgLaSXkf0iYKgOPGPvdHjimF1gVXcHyLcJdtTH5do6XNBPXOvos/t7h5wtg5P1IxF9qs1DwjI2vUL7PZ5wjRdZGg2dXtT2G2Nmvv0adiZS@gI5faTQDqVVVV1ls6glbgDmeoS4Z782QuKGKHnnnptKkgXV3GakvO5qo3GIKWoqvcAYxobMG2pnQ1gjs9Zs/wFzwpnY@0OBt79ZUJzJEbVKyg24gg7oNYQl8m4NZbUI4lRQdvgxGRRyVnL7HoVn6ft7fMHJxrd6HuNWjHHVRpwT30j@R4aOoftIPLycURU/ttB4tUjSdA4soPE2SNFUXNTm8a2yf1qdbrRAaIjw@u6QgW05QzsIW84hzvs05We6nr43CKsm3nDoHc/3kuYJsI2Ydp2z8@9e6eLPNweFNVkaeYge0z065m0mkSb8bOSpztKgi0TpK/Qq7V5QtA4D2uJJqc2DiBsXeyloOe@zr0mBwP5QVwtZQdZbXZ5eJCMmfg7lraGUyQcBX8y2nh7Hce8nPg/UaNXCR0BLVJDXYCMpHWLDomptjSvZ@DuTUk0qKuRd77fOhjPNAttHtRsJYoylu3gbN9DNRJbTSkCPNYbz9u6eI@P6Mmz/91DpU0FamJz13uHXTbphjSxPd71fuF/I/30vvpFc1hxOhqejn51YDvnteNsquPAcgxI7tq29XupANBnMi@F5217UrvX2NWDGNtUzJ9bzYKqgdYbvsaytKFX2FY/7qheQfWR59qUtVBiyWOC5xdvXHp2q9bDvFsUK5eDfc8fjjz1U1CXgGlS1StzrYtj84axBlEsKBj6LcJt/8bkNwySqpp72jRmGGhqOsQsOvcpRqKgkGFaSrCBicE1nQ047pJlFV1Ntl9SavtJWH039c6GimfzbOUuBXd0ZJ/upnqwOaBfEMY/DmmHzUUuDn@MA7CMtozk/vFf)

Comment: dah, you got me, I just can't do it...is what I'd being saying if this wasn't already [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233236/78850) ;p

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), score: 38, safe.

No modules.

```
"#'$&;)+!,-./%07*245@6|89<>31:?\]^_`}~
```

I think this is still an easy problem.

### Hint

- Try making integers with allowed characters.
- Then pass them to some functions.
- Finally concatenate them with something.

### Solution

> There can be some solutions; one is `print chr length for qw x XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX x`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1ZTRDYAgDERXeUu4C/9GxcQoEhLdvo4godRGvu9ej7aQprwNIimve2GMmW3alxKZj8x5cRNeT4WkSlOtoyNL7aUrFZuQDe3ApGPYDaLZhyldexXNFmsA6roOmTWpccnbbufLkHjN039TCX/G2z9j13/CuXrgFnkA) [How to generate the solution](https://tio.run/##RYtJDoIwAEX3nOKLSkWtiPMUh1u4wIFgtQYCWKs0cbh6BWNi/uLlT@GVa50cQFeIQSVuLugdT0MKkFyeF@fGz0IQp@U8DAAZP0esVnEptZGKcyyP5tosip@BabxIfqr9M5AvEXCBiMUnyXFMBC4ZFEgxC3xZgAU8gTJslDFXsCykTERQWptlUrGmdqPUpC2n2h7WO73@cvAcjWfzrjtZeJvtbv96fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Javastack, score 1, [Anticlimactically cracked by exedraj](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233245/100664)

```
a
```

So simply complex...

[Up-to-date copy of the interpreter](https://tio.run/##rVnrbtvIFf5dP8XEyIZkxNCXxAU2WmeRBkWRRVMskrSLQlatkTiyGFMkQw5lyY7y6ul3ZobkkKJsF6iBROKcy5z7hfrCV7yY5VEmXyRpKH7EQjIRi6VIZMHO2d0Bw5/Dw9B5PXK5P/XY@RvOBmzqn459DYzTq2jGkxoDCM@eWXCeZcKGjoIgmPp83GBMI9mhn7aASSoVEKDv3D@xIGluUX2zqGYiigH6wOUioO8N1WzBieiTzKPkKpjn6fIdTt5B@TbODCfA4@dvNCquD2YG8610vQY7jFaRwjWCTI94IwiAy9TW/vt3FwieP/3JNkGYltPY3McHlpJhmcUwrwSMaROMOBnvpEERX0seW3Y4P7cMMY9TZSTi@4L/ZJEpCMRrKCvRauIFj@eG9ui0oYySWa5CpPIKH5zY0FCstbTaHCNb0UiKXGlDlAgmRuHQ1udLGiWWNQN6dm2xYpFcyYURLNBPPqvpl3wz1eZSF6gYyBFg6RIHv7Dj4Mw/rnFt38AlzSXLMpZRFm8aMOPsOQKftSPfCs4nlt8UrB2ednxmPLJgo3Y@ZGlWsRy1LJOlN8Iimz5/zi1xslx0Mo37MK4J36ln34AjqQ04S5MijUUAgXHjt2/tGxFaYY4QbEJz0ApPwHMpqgA7etVAyOIIMS6rNNQuaExPz7UUCL22n54z7rWZLaNkydeNdjsE6plPC5e/QJ0aMHf6hv/KX089K3Q0uhF31L6V7jTRBFvZd1914vVtnvMNFYRrsSncFjJcwKVVLFlt/kDDKJIbn@Es5rOqePgzRTILzPHbOHYRGp7/ssIvUA1kY4OGuQK0sqQg34g6RZ9bXivKygS4KSxnwnXX/gZY68HGsnpxw7M6kZXu@IIoajDkIsrDyvkvrXN0lFbMNCC0mygiqUwr0Lb8@cwbB0ueue6lv64Va5Vndz14eep5qhxMJk0c8Thb8KmQhqfDp7NQzK8W0ZfreJmk2de8kOXqZr25dRqir2WqixBRHFqA24xf1wBmAYpyKnM@q65BjFlRJZbpyu4AtgO57zjaLduDeZnMZJQmLC8TlzqMHyVZKYvz0djTvbbGiMXalWItzTn9UXOW6bVIqDUjT1mhrISHOY8LUT1fFunlnOc4dhyf3SxQcosMwtABu0gupDOsWc7T3CW21NlYOmedG@kvmrsNjwC1Py5DUbhE4bFnz9gTfWuHylA@aYnkMVQbGSWl2MHVegVZWSzcNs1wB3dXzTbOFiNMIeh6pdY5MA6dfvmM7K3rJ4dP71pXbA8nXp9x9zMEuDLLY6Vtow3OlUtqxO3Bzh21TR9julzIMk8M6kHDsQ63jOeFcOOo6AZcIgopwkLy2bWJOisEdwNJASmSOqyM6Ao8Oh7vd4qtzcjR@ji@Oh17e9ysoCgfcrZwj0YX4UUwHhx5DzJPyuUUvativi@IRo6MlqJwfAdKCj5b4BsyAvXNx6yR4f9oboArYueUiPFYfcaiIDp5E80IWy5y/UWRw8HUWYiyJLJ5hBoybjJMifWgFuoBJWbckyiW7zS2Zjm8z4zKM3SyJ2NaPNOMZiwQwAI96L0yGOa9yG3/KESl2g6yERoGTW9wxQ37tEkkX/81zxGHjn5g6um1xsSYxqKEkZwPa48hymO76lB8Q@VMhAj@HTv0GUtuMoFcqIiIeYnxeB4lgq54lPj/TFRgg17J9UBMA@fSGegLd01ntH0oMcwGuCfteoqSTY6ebtuGmvotWr2R7FYJFahUQcHxvMeXqCuRvCtBFGozdeoUzXBwy5rmlPWoZ55cN7Mdw7rw1Wernfo4eXpHFDCB9gGi76OYi1wkKm0/w534eJ9g5E04pfi/0xL//4YtGh9KLnx@EJIe/4GQe5uwigDjuVTl4aOeQdUXlf8fyjkiAl9@x1CC2qE4v09WURFNVZX5Cw9htK3iz2g2QPywp3c9Sp4cH3vb15OBc5E4g1o7qNWMWrewUg/l2TFGZvby2DOD2Lp/COuh/PkMlDSaVbPZtud@zFLVANzD4tbztv/podLOOPjTzpHzeRFRZX2XLpecvvw9mpOlPmEzvQnziKILj39wbfJPYoltLMaqY3wGa7IZT6gqTAUrEVQIPGa4fz1HtGKK952NEPQRRgV2pBVdUKqSZAY@38E8g6uk4meoV6DOUsllqnpGYV@9UeECKyQY@hT5fC50ZxAsjK6QNxCdFRvkz5KYTvxW7k1@jwVHAodp4shaXOtufH3BIsxzHIIWrDbXTCUOEyqC0MwKjrsQR9dUQ6MCQUVSTHnIslJJGgqoNke7ui5jrtIPdYxnUYo2tySEf0WSYyVj7/D9TC4I/FsZb9g8ggfS/Log8YOu/H8sNtAzZDAElICkv7L30ikwD1NJZO8xgMYxQX1z9KTL4W9pPKcJC8s5aiNs4RglF7B73WBNSw03CYSUdELvsJS/Zsqz8Wat0gwNPc9NHmYiX5ZSaaukd9Ax4AgYBcrV1@B8R63PcF@Wp8jWJYsK8s1NBJuQV2nKD7SS6gy62eTk475iF/MC61yeW1XO1CgcjvDPVLMXJ@PecQ4dSdVfH0PO@Yl/k/Os2hMsljb@R6GCpCHbnd6e0Gklx2h8sDP7UsHXcqlmd9wzEyjF9NZD6F6AeFtEc@nuAFRX7Zlqqvu7BBgr6X1HnypIihP/2Bs/rhlWF1jN/T7GXbY9/XGFkT4XNDP3GnpoT/fAs214onYs8l9teWBA125c4LQvEmbpMsOwqcebwh5r1N6noWFnLyEQ2u0ngXIqq67qrJxBq3AHMjUvIE7@7AVFjNRzT702F5SLyzhNKfhcNUZjkVJc1QuFCa0N2LbUyRY4x0PWPP6C74pma50OBt7dRUJ7JFbVSxg24kg7kNYYF8mktZbUK4kxQdvhJGRR6Vnr7HqVnKft4@G9G40e9L3GrNjjKgu4p77R/AEeuobtYfLycUxU/dvD4tUjWdA6sofF2SNVUXtTm8euy/3q6XSrE0RnhtcNhQppJxjYfdEwRDg8ZCu91fXIucNYD/NGQO9u8iBj2gjbjOnYHQ69O6dLPNpdFNVmafYge03065202kSb9bPSp7tKQiyTpK8wq7VlQtI491uJNqc2DTBsWzzIQe99nXtNDQbxvbRayw6xOuzKcC8bs/F3PG0tpyg4Cv9kvPUeDBzzcuL/xI1eJXQUtFiNdAMymtYjOjSm3tK8nkG4Ny3RkK7H3vBh72A90yK0ZVC7lSjKWLaTs30P9UgcNa0I@Hjeet7OxQ/EiN48@989VNZUqCY397132OeTbkqT2JN97xf@N9ZP76qfTkeVpOPR6fhXB75zXjvOtgIHVmBAc9f2rd/LBYg@k3kpPG83ktqzxr4ZxPimEn5oDQuqB1pv@BrP0oF@wrH61UjNCmqOHGpX1kqJFY8Jn5@/cem7W40e5t2iWLsc4nv@aOyp35i6DMyQqt6va1scmzeMNYoSQeHQjxpu@8crvxGQTNXc0@Yxx0JT8yFhMbnPsBIFhQzTUkIMbAxu/avvDltW8dVs@zWlsZ@U1XfT7Gy4eLbMVu1SeEdHNnQ/14PtAf2CMPlxSCdsIXJx@GMSQGSMZaT3j/8C)

I forgot how many ways JS has to get a NaN.

Comment: wow. that was [anticlimatic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233245/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## Javastack, score 8, round 11, [Cracked by exedraj](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233261/100664)

```
dfhjkmuv
```

Probably the last one, unless an unintended crack is found.

[Up-to-date copy of the interpreter](https://tio.run/##rVn/b9NIFv/5@lcMFYttYtwv0JOWbkEsWp1YHacVcLc6pTkyiSeNqWMbe5wmLeFf5z5vZmyPHafpSVcJ4pl57837/sX@wpe8mOZRJp8laSh@xEIyEYuFSGTBLtjdAcOfw8PQeTl0uT/x2MUrzgZs4p@OfH0Yp1fRlCc1BACePLHOeZYJ@3QYBMHE56MGYhLJDv6kdZikUh3i6Dv3T6yTNLewvllYUxHFOHrP5Tyg5wZrOueE9FHmUXIVzPJ08RY7byF8G2aKHcDxi1caFNcHUwP5RrpeAx1Gy0jBGkYmR7xhBIeL1Jb@@3cXAJ4/@clWQZiWk9jcxweWkGGZxVCvxBnTKhhyUt5JAyK@ljy29HBxYSliFqdKSUT3Gf/JQlMnYK/BrFirkec8nhnco9MGM0qmuXKRyip8cGKfhmKludXqGNqCRlLkShrChDMxcoe2PF/SKLG0GdDatdmKRXIl54axQK98VuMv@Hqi1aUuUD6Qw8HSBTZ@YcfBmX9cw9q2gUmaSxZlLKMsXjfHjLOncHzW9nzLOR9ZdlNnbfe0/TPjkXU2bMdDlmYVyWFLM1l6Iyy0ydOn3GIny0Un0rgP5Rr3nXj2DdiSWoHTNCnSWARgGDd@@9a@Ea4V5nDBxjUHLffEeS5F5WBHL5oT0jhcjMsqDLUJGtXTuuYCrte201PGvTaxRZQs@KqRbgtBrfmkcPkz5KkBcyev@Gv@cuJZrqPBDbvD9q10p/Em6Mq@@6rjr2/ynK8pIVyLdeG2gGECLq1kyWr1B/qMPLmxGfZiPq2Shz9VKNPAbLuJuGEfxNVvq8yd@M6V4/nAfl4hF0gNslFIc5M6aIVMQYYSdbw@tUxYlJU@cG1Y4lZ35a8BtRqsLRMUNzyro1opAg9wqQZCzqM8rDzhubWP8tJyoOYItSeKiCtTF7Rifz7zRsGCZ6772V/VgrVytbsaPD/1PJUbxuPGqXiczflESEPT4ZNpKGZX8@jLdbxI0uxrXshyebNa3zoN0tcy1RmJMA6tg9uMX9cHzDooyonM@dRSPnzO8jKxSJd2RagM@iaOseU42jKbg1mZTGWUJiwvE5cqjh8lWSmLi@HI07W3hojFypViJc0@/VGxlum1SKhUI25ZoRSFxYzHhajWn4v084zn2HYcn93MkYKLDMzQBrtMLqVzXpOcpblLZKnSsXTGOjfSXzRzGxoBakFchqJwCcNjT56wR/rWDpbBfNRiyWPIPjJKSrEFq@UKsrKYu22c8y3YbTHbMBu0NIWg65VYF4A4dPr5M7y3rh8fPr5rXbE5HHt9yt1NEMeVWh7KbRtscKFMUgNuDrbuqHX6ENXlQpZ5YkAPGoq1u2U8L4QbR0XX4RJRSBEWkk@vjddZLrjtSOqQPKlDyrCujofHo91GsaUZOloex1e7I2@HmdUpMoiczt2j4WV4GYwGR95e4km5mKCWVcR3OdHQkdFCFI7vQEjBp3M8ISKQ4nz0Hhn@j2bmcEnknBI@HqvfWBSEJ2@iKUHLea4fFDoMTJWGMEtCm0XIIaMmwhRbe6VQC6SYUU@gWLbT0Jrk@X1qVJahnR0R06KZZtRzAQEa6AHv5cEQ7wVu20cBKtG2gA3TUGh6w6hqflwnkq9@y3P4oaMXTK1eaki0bSxKGPG5X3o0VR7bFof8GyJnIoTzb@mhT1lynQnEQoVExEu0y7MoEXTFg9j/Z6IcG/iKrz0@DZjPzkBfuK06I@2@wDAT4Y6w60lKNjrKuq0bquu3qPaGs1vFVKBCBQnH8x6eoq5E8rYEUqjV1MlT1NPBLCtqVVbDnv5y1fR6DOPDV58tt/Lj@PEdYUAF2gbwvg9iJnKRqLD9BHPi512CFjjhFOL/Tkv8/zumavwovvD7Xkha/gMu9yZhFQLadanSwwfdk6oHFf/vyxk8Ag9/oC9B7lCU3yXLqIgmKsv8ykMobaPoM@oN4D/s8V2PkCfHx97m5XjgXCbOoJYOYjXd1i201IN5dowWmj0/9kwvturvw3owfz4DJnVnVXu26bkf7VTVEPeQuPW8zX96sLQxDv6yteV8mkeUWd@miwWnh79HM9LUR0yqN2EekXdh@SfXKv8oFpjOYow@xmbQJpvyhLLCRLASTgXHY4b61wt4K7p631kLQT9hVGBmWtIFpUpJpuHzHfQzuEoqegZ7CewslVymqmYU9tVr5S7QQoKmT6HPZkJXBsHC6ApxA9ZZsUb8LIjo2G/F3viPWHAEcJgmjqzZte7G4zMWoZ/jYLRgtbqmKnCYUB6EYlZw3AU/uqYcGhVwKuJiwkOWlYrTUEC0GcrVdRlzFX7IYzyLUpS5BQH8K5IcIxp7i@czOafj38t4zWYRLJDm1wWxH3T5/3O@hpwhgyIgBDh9zd5Jp0A/TCmRvUMDGsd06putR10Kf0vjGXVYGNaRG6ELxwg5h97rAmtKarhOwKSkHXqnpew1VZaN1ysVZijoeW7iMBP5opRKWsW9g4oBQ0ApEK6@BvtbYn2C@bI8RbQuWFSQbW4i6ISsSl1@oIVUe5DNRicb9yW7mBeY6PLcynImR2FziH8mmz07GfW2c6hIKv/6aHIuTvybnGfVnGCRtOE/COUkDdp29/aIdis@hqODrd6XEr7mSxW7456eQAmmpx4C9wL42zyaSXfrQFXVnq6mur@LgLaS3n/0iYKgOPGPvdHDimF1gVXc7yPcJdtTH5do6XNBPXOvos/t7h5wtg5P1IxF9qs1DwjI2vUL7PZ5wjRdZGg2dXtT2G2Nmvv0adiZS@gI5fajQDqVVVV1ls6glbgDmZp3ECd/9YIiRui5p16bCtLF5zhNyflc1UZjkFJU1TuFMY0NmLbUzgYwx@esWf6CZ4WzsXYHA@/uMqE5EqPqZyg24gg7oNYQl8m4NZbUI4lRQdvgxGRRyVnL7HoVn6ft7fN7Jxrd6HuNWjHHVRpwT30j@R4aOoftIPL8YURU/ttB4sUDSdA4soPE2QNFUXNTm8a2yf1qdbrRAaIjw@u6QgW05QzsPm84hzvs05We6nr43CKsm3nDoHc33kuYJsI2Ydp2z8@9O6eLPNweFNVkaeYge0z065m0mkSb8bOSpztKgi0TpC/Qq7V5QtA492uJJqc2DiBsXeyloOe@zr0mBwP5XlwtZQdZbXZ5uJeMmfg7lraGUyQcBX8y2nh7Hce8nPg/UaNXCR0BLVJDXYCMpHWLDomptjSvZ@DuTUk0qKuRd77fOhjPNAttHtRsJYoylu3gbN9DNRJbTSkCPNYbz9u6eI@P6Mmz/91DpU0FamJz13uHXTbphjSxPd71fuF/I/34rvqUOqw4HQ1PR68d2M556Tib6jiwHAOSu7Zt/V4qAPSZzEvhedue1O41dvUgxjYV8@dWs6BqoPWGr7EsbegVttVXJNUrmPfNubiK0CDn59qotXhiyWPC5BevXHp2qybEvGUUK5dDEM8fjjz19alLwLSr6kW81sqxeddYgyhmFAx94XDbn7X8hlVSWnNPm8YMo01Nh5hFDz/FcBQUMkxLCTYwO7j19@Atsqyi2yZbiJpgpSGs@S7wKw1OslbgvmnvdiiPZgrSnxaHGnPDmGerwUqMCu7oyD7dTfVgc0CfJ8Y/qo8r7JAfssNDZj5q/BgH0Aj6P1Lrj/8C), with ES2020 stuff removed

Comment: [well the cracks start coming and they don't stop coming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233261/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `O`, score 51, [Cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235671/100664)

```
,₴…‹›⟇+*/-d↵EǍ½ƒɖ1234567890ø∆e₈₇∞₆₄JpiẎȯhtḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C
```

Only *slightly* evil :}

Comment: [probably not what you were expecting lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235671/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `O`, score 57

```
,₴…‹›⟇+*/-d↵EǍ½ƒɖ1234567890ø∆e₈₇∞₆₄JpiẎȯhtḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İN⇩
```

Take 2.

Comment: [haha no](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235684/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CLC-INTERCAL), score: 7, safe.

For clarification here is a sequence of seven octets to output in hex:

```
52 45 41 44 4f 55 54
```

[Try it online!](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

### The answer

Here is `od -t x1 -v` of source:

```
0000000 c4 d6 5e f1 4c 60 7b f7 c4 d6 5e f1 e2 e4 c2 7b
0000020 f1 4c 60 7b f1 c4 d6 5e f1 e2 e4 c2 7b f2 4c 60
0000040 7b f3 f6 f8 c4 d6 5e f1 e2 e4 c2 7b f3 4c 60 7b
0000060 f3 f7 f5 c4 d6 5e f1 e2 e4 c2 7b f4 4c 60 7b f1
0000100 f3 f6 f9 c4 d6 5e f1 e2 e4 c2 7b f5 4c 60 7b f1
0000120 f3 f5 f4 c4 d6 5e f1 e2 e4 c2 7b f6 4c 60 7b f5
0000140 f6 f6 c4 d6 5e f1 e2 e4 c2 7b f7 4c 60 7b f2 f5
0000160 f3 c4 d6 d9 c5 c1 c4 d6 e4 e3 5e f1
0000174
```

It's:

```
DO;1<-#7DO;1SUB#1<-#1DO;1SUB#2<-#368DO;1SUB#3<-#375DO;1SUB#4<-#1369DO;1SUB#5<-#1354DO;1SUB#6<-#566DO;1SUB#7<-#253DOREADOUT;1
```

in EBCDIC.

You may need compiler option `-e`, as character set guessing does not work.

#### See also

[My answer on Restricted mini challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235638/100411)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `O`, score 59, [Cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/235706#235706)

```
,₴…‹›⟇+*/-d↵EǍ½ƒɖ1234567890ø∆e₈₇∞₆₄JpiẎȯhtḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İN⇩Ż÷
```

Third time's the charm...

Comment: [got'em](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235706/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `O`, score 63, [Cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/235708#235708)

```
,₴…‹›⟇+*/-d↵EǍ½ƒɖ1234567890ø∆e₈₇∞₆₄JpiẎȯhtḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İN⇩Ż÷«»`;
```

One more time...

Comment: [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235708/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `O`, score 72, [Cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/235714#235714)

```
,₴…‹›⟇+*/-d↵EǍ½ƒɖ1234567890ø∆e₈₇∞₆₄JpiẎȯhtḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İN⇩Ż÷«»`;¥£¾¼⅛%→←"
```

One more time...

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235714/78850

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `O`, score 76

```
,₴…‹›⟇+*/-d↵EǍ½ƒɖ1234567890ø∆e₈₇∞₆₄JpiẎȯhtḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İN⇩Ż÷«»`;¥£¾¼⅛%→←"ẋ¤ȦF
```

This is difficult...

Comment: crack'd https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235725/78850

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `O`, score 81, [Cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/235733#235733)

```
,₴…‹›⟇+*/-d↵EǍ½ƒɖ1234567890ø∆e₈₇∞₆₄JpiẎȯhtḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İN⇩Ż÷«»`;¥£¾¼⅛%→←"ẋ¤ȦFȧ⌐m⊍g
```

This is difficult...

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235733/78850 get gamed on

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `O`, score 90, [Cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/235739#235739)

```
,₴…‹›⟇+*/-d↵EǍ½ƒɖ1234567890ø∆e₈₇∞₆₄JpiẎȯhtḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İN⇩Ż÷«»`;¥£¾¼⅛%→←"ẋ¤ȦFȧ⌐m⊍g≬\ṡ∷‡⁽⟨|⟩
```

This is difficult...

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235739/78850

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](http://github.com/lyxal/vyxal) `O`, score 105, [Cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/235754#235754)

```
,₴…‹›⟇+*/-d↵EǍ½ƒɖ1234567890ø∆e₈₇∞₆₄JpiẎȯhtḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İN⇩Ż÷«»`;¥£¾¼⅛%→←"ẋ¤ȦFȧ⌐m⊍g≬\ṡ∷‡⁽⟨|⟩‟„$∇_yǏṘRq꘍₍₌Π⁺
```

Just when you thought it wasn't hard enough already...

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235754/78850

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](http://github.com/lyxal/vyxal) `O`, score 125, [Cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/207560/print-x-without-x-robbers-thread/235755#235755)

```
,₴…‹›⟇+*/-d↵EǍ½ƒɖ1234567890ø∆e₈₇∞₆₄JpiẎȯhtḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İN⇩Ż÷«»`;¥£¾¼⅛%→←"ẋ¤ȦFȧ⌐m⊍g≬\ṡ∷‡⁽⟨|⟩‟„$∇_yǏṘRq꘍₍₌Π⁺ʀ↑↓G↲↳⋏⋎Ṅ⁋ð×‛√²⌈⌊:ḊD
```

The last one, for now.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235755/78850

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), score 159, [cracked by Aaron](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235769/101522)

```
,₴…‹›⟇+*/-d↵EǍ½ƒɖ1234567890ø∆e₈₇∞₆₄JpiẎȯhtḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İN⇩Ż÷«»`;¥£¾¼⅛%→←"ẋ¤ȦFȧ⌐m⊍g≬\ṡ∷‡⁽⟨|⟩‟„$∇_yǏRq꘍₍₌Π⁺βτʀʁɾɽ¨żẏ?¹⁰²ǔǓǒǑǐǎꜝ₂₃₅&ẇŀl↑↓∴∵O¢ṙṗṖ¦†AVG↲↳⋏⋎Ṅ⁋×λ√⌈⌊:ḊD
```

My turn.

Comment: [ez](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235769/101522)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), score 220, cracked by [EmanresuA](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235780/100664)

```
,₴…‹›⟇+*/-d↵EǍ½ƒɖ1234567890ø∆e₈₇∞₆₄JpiẎȯhtḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İN⇩Ż÷«»`;¥£¾¼⅛%→←"ẋ¤ȦFȧ⌐m⊍g≬\ṡ∷‡⁽⟨|⟩‟„$∇_yǏRq꘍₍₌Π⁺βτʀʁɾɽ¨żẏ?¹⁰²ǔǓǒǑǐǎꜝ₂₃₅&ẇŀl↑↓∴∵O¢ṙṗṖ¦†AVG↲↳⋏⋎Ṅ⁋×λ√⌈⌊:ḊDabcjnsvwxzBHIKMQSTUWXYZ)}]([{<>ḂĊḞĠĿṀȮṠẆẊ℅@°•ß€↔æƈ ¯±≠⁼≥≤=ḃ∩∪
```

More.

Comment: [You've been cracked, you've been cracked, yes you've probably been cracked, you've been cracked, you've been cracked, have a nice day.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235780/100664)

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal `D`, score 233, [cracked by aaroneous Miller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236087/78850)

```
ḟṙIcKġ₴…‹›+*/-d↵Ǎ½ƒɖø∆₈₇∞₆₄JiẎȯht42069ḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İNeVERgȮṄnaGḭ⟇ėyOU⊍p⇩Ż÷«»⌐m≬\ṡ∷‡⁽⟨|⟩‟„$∇_Ǐq꘍₍₌Π⁺βτʀʁɾɽ¨żẏ?¹⁰²ǔǓǒǑǐǎꜝ₂₃₅&ẇŀl↑↓∴∵¢`;¥£¾F¼⅛%→←"ẋ¤Ḋε€ṗṖ¦†ḃL¶ðZṘ↲↳⋏⋎⁋×λ√⌈⌊:Dbjwxz,BHMQSTXY)}]([{<>ḂĊḞĿṀṠẆẊ℅@°•ß↔æƈ§≈µ¯±≠⁼≥≤=∩s∪ĠṁȦ'ċḋṅ13578ȧ
```

lol

Comment: [lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236087/101522)[get](https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ)[crak'd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236087/101522)

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal `D`, score 239, [cracked by Aaron](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236110/101522)

```
ḟṙIcKġ₴…‹›+*/-d↵Ǎ½ƒɖø∆₈₇∞₆₄JiẎȯht42069ḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İNeVERgȮṄnaGḭ⟇ėyOU⊍p⇩Ż÷«»⌐m≬\ṡ∷‡⁽⟨|⟩‟„$∇_Ǐq꘍₍₌Π⁺βτʀʁɾɽ¨żẏ?¹⁰²ǔǓǒǑǐǎꜝ₂₃₅&ẇŀl↑↓∴∵¢`;¥£¾F¼⅛%→←"ẋ¤Ḋε€ṗṖ¦†ḃL¶ðZṘ↲↳⋏⋎⁋×λ√⌈⌊:Dbjwxz,BHMQSTXY)}]([{<>ḂĊḞĿṀṠẆẊ℅@°•ß↔æƈ§≈µ¯±≠⁼≥≤=∩s∪ĠṁȦ'ċḋṅ13578ȧ∧⟑∨^rA
```

No logic. No range. No Any.

Comment: [No problem.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236110/101522)

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal `D`, score 244, [cracked by Aaroneous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236163/101522)

```
ḟṙIcKġ₴…‹›+*/-d↵Ǎ½ƒɖø∆₈₇∞₆₄JiẎȯht42069ḢṪḣṫ¡Þ₀₁C!¬⇧İNeVERgȮṄnaGḭ⟇ėyOU⊍p⇩Ż÷«»⌐m≬\ṡ∷‡⁽⟨|⟩‟„$∇_Ǐq꘍₍₌Π⁺βτʀʁɾɽ¨żẏ?¹⁰²ǔǓǒǑǐǎꜝ₂₃₅&ẇŀl↑↓∴∵¢`;¥£¾F¼⅛%→←"ẋ¤Ḋε€ṗṖ¦†ḃL¶ðZṘ↲↳⋏⋎⁋×λ√⌈⌊:Dbjwxz,BHMQSTXY)}]([{<>ḂĊḞĿṀṠẆẊ℅@°•ß↔æƈ§≈µ¯±≠⁼≥≤=∩s∪ĠṁȦ'ċḋṅ13578ȧ∧⟑∨^rA□f.∑W
```

It's so sad that the last answer died of sigma.

Comment: [No problem.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236163/101522)

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal `so`, score 248, cracked by [EmanresuA](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236209/78850)

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./023456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLNOQRSTUVXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijlmnpqrtuvwxyz{|}~¡¢£¤¥¦§¨«¬¯°±²µ¶¹»¼½¾×Þßæð÷øĊċėĠġİĿŀŻżƈƒƛǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔȦȧȮȯɖɽɾʀʁΠβελτḂḃḊḋḞḟḢḣḭṀṁṄṅṖṗṘṙṠṡṪṫẆẇẊẋẎẏ‛„‟†‡•…‹›⁋⁰⁺⁼⁽₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₌₍€₴℅⅛←↑→↓↔↲↳↵⇧⇩∆∇∑√∞∧∨∩∪∴∵∷≈≠≤≥≬⊍⋎⋏⌈⌊⌐□⟇⟑⟨⟩꘍ꜝ
```

The final challenge.

Comment: [Cracker'sd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236209/100664)

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal `so`, score 249, cracked by [aaroneous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236222/101522)

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLNOQRSTUVXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijlmnpqrtuvwxyz{|}~¡¢£¤¥¦§¨«¬¯°±²µ¶¹»¼½¾×Þßæð÷øĊċėĠġİĿŀŻżƈƒƛǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔȦȧȮȯɖɽɾʀʁΠβελτḂḃḊḋḞḟḢḣḭṀṁṄṅṖṗṘṙṠṡṪṫẆẇẊẋẎẏ‛„‟†‡•…‹›⁋⁰⁺⁼⁽₀₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₌₍€₴℅⅛←↑→↓↔↲↳↵⇧⇩∆∇∑√∞∧∨∩∪∴∵∷≈≠≤≥≬⊍⋎⋏⌈⌊⌐□⟇⟑⟨⟩꘍ꜝ
```

We partake in a mild amount of tomfoolery.

Comment: [as well as bamboozlement](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236222/101522)

Answer (score 1):

## Vyxal `so`, score 249, [fricking gosh dang cracked by aaron](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236282/101522)

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijmnpoqrtuvwxyz{|}~¡¢£¤¥¦§¨«¬¯°±²µ¶¹»¼½¾×Þßæð÷øĊċėĠġİĿŀŻżƈƒƛǍǎǏǐǑǒǓǔȦȧȮȯɖɽɾʀʁΠβελτḂḃḊḋḞḟḢḣḭṀṁṄṅṖṗṘṙṠṡṪṫẆẇẊẋẎẏ‛„‟†‡•…‹›⁋⁰⁺⁼⁽₀₁₂₃₄₅₇₈₌₍€₴℅⅛←↑→↓↔↲↳↵⇧⇩∆∇∑√∞∧∨∩∪∴∵∷≈≠≤≥≬⊍⋎⋏⌈⌊⌐□⟇⟑⟨⟩꘍ꜝ
```

Commit utter frick.

Comment: I have commited [UTTER FRICK] : [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236282/101522)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck)

###### Level: baby

---

Should be pretty straight forward (literally), but I think it's still interesting

```
,-<>[]
```

###### Why I think it's interesting:

> The fact that you can print any string with only two different characters in brainfuck is quite interesting in my opinion

Comment: cracked [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248895/73593) :)

Answer (score 1):

## [!@#$%^&*()_+](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/ecndpcaalrlp), Score: 2

```
^+
```

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242192/92901)

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, score: 53

```
BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz⍙3
```

I don't know how long this will last

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/218197/95792).

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), Score: 47, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207728/81203)

```
abdfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
{ <-> , ~, &}[(*@)[]]
```

Fixed.

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207728/36445)

Answer (score 0):

## QBasic 1.1, score: 2, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207792/16766)

```
Cc
```

I'm specifying QBasic 1.1 in order to exclude QB64 with its extra features. You can run it at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack).

Comment: Cracked: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207792/94694

Answer (score 0):

## QBasic 1.1, score: 3, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207800/16766)

```
C,c
```

`POKE` should be impossible now.

You can run QBasic 1.1 at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack).

---

My solution:

> ```
>  DIM outstr AS STRING * 3
>  outstr = MKS$(908.6916)
>  PRINT outstr
> ```

Comment: Cracked: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207800/94694

Answer (score 0):

## Javastack, score 16, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233234/100664) by exedraj

```
1234567890"crsyo
```

My my, you are going to *enjoy* this one...

[Up-to-date copy of the interpreter](https://tio.run/##rVl7b9vIEf@7/hQbIxeSEUM/Ehe4@JxDGhRFDk1xSNIeClm1VuLKYkyRDLmUJTvKV09/s7sklxRluUAF2OLuzszO@0F94UteTPMoky@SNBQ/YiGZiMVCJLJgF@z@gOHj8DB0Xg9d7k88dvGGswGb@KcjXx/G6XU05UkNAYBnz6xznmXCPh0GQTDx@aiBmESygz9pHSapVIc4@s79E@skzS2sbxbWVEQxjj5wOQ/oucGazjkhfZJ5lFwHszxdvMPOOwjfhpliB3AchIOpgXgrXa@BCqNlpGAMA5Mj3jCAw0VqS/39uwsAz5/8ZIsepuUkru4ZWMKFZRZDrRJnTIs@5KS0kwZEfC15bMl/cWEpYBanSjlE9wX/yUJTJ2CvwaxYq5HnPJ4Z3KPTBjNKprlyjcoafHBin4ZipbnV6hjagkZS5EoawoQTMXKDtjxf0iixtBnQ2rXZikVyLeeVUfTKZzX@gq8nWl3qAmX7HI6VLrDxCzsOzvzjGta2DUzSXLIoYxll8bo5Zpw9h8OztsdbTvnEsps6a7ul7ZcZj6yzYTsOsjSrSA5bmsnSW2GhTZ4/5xY7WS46EcZ9ijGbMpxdasVN06RIYxGAUdz07Vv7JrhUmMP1GpcctNwS57kUlWMdvWpOSNNwLS6rsNOqb1RO65oLuFzbPs8Z99rEFlGy4KtGqi0EteaTwuUvkJcGzJ284b/y1xPPchkNbtgdtm@lO40XeaPW3dcdP32b53yNdXAj1oXbAobqubSSI5sEeo88t7ER9mI@rZKFP1Wg08Bsv41jF67g@S8r@ALRL@1gUButaCjIFqIOxeeWlYqyEhk3hOVUuO7KXwNqNVhbWi5ueVYHrJIVD/CaBkLOozysjP3S2kfFaPlIc4RyEkXElUn1Wnc/n3mjYMEz173yVzjpSb/uavDy1PNU2I/Hjd/wOJvziZCGpsMn01DMrufRl5t4kaTZ17yQ5fJ2tb5zGqSvZaqTDWEcWgd3Gb@pDxgdHGwOZmUylVGasLxMXEr8fpRkpSwuhiNPl8AaIhYrV4qVNPv0oZop0xuRUMVEOLFCCYfFjMeFqNZXRXo14zm2Hcdnt3NkxCKD8WmDXSaX0jmvSc7S3CWyVHhYOmOdG@kTzdyGRoDUHJehKFzC8NizZ@yJvrWDZTCftFjyGJKCjJJSbMFquYKsLOZuG@d8C3ZbzDbMBp1FIeh6JdYFIA6dfv4M763rx4dP71tXbA7HXp9ydxPEcaWWx3LbBhtcKJPUgJuDrTtqnT5GdbmQZZ4Y0IOGYu1uGc8L4cZR0XW4RBRShIXk0xvjdZYLbjuSOiRP6pAyrKvj4fFot1FsaYaOlsfx1e7I22FmdYqol9O5ezS8DC@D0eDI20s8KRcTlJiK@C4nGjoyWojC8R0IKfh0jidEBNKSj1Ygw/9oZg6XRM4p4eOx@o5FQXjyNpoStJzn@kGhw8BUAAizJLRZtBTOqIkwxdZeKdTCd5xRT6BYttPQmuT5Q2pUlqGdHRHToplm1AIBARroAe/lwRDvBW7bRwEq0baADdNQaHqLK27Zp3Ui@eqveQ4/dPSCqdVrDYkuikUJIz73S48ex2Pb4pB/Q@RMhHD@LT30KUuuM4FYqJCIeInudRYlgq54FPv/TJRjA1/xtcenAXPlDPSF26oz0u4LDDOY7Qi7nqRko6MU27qhWnyHCm04u1NMBSpUkHA87/Ep6lok70oghVpNnTxFrRbMsqL2YjXsaftWTQvG0M1/9dlyKz@On94TBlSgbQDv@yhmIheJCtvPMCe@3ifoTBNOIf7vtMT/3zDc4kvxhe8PQtLyH3C5twmrENA9S5UePupWUT2o@P9QzuARePgdvQRyh6L8PllGRTRRWeYvPITSNoo@o94A/sOe3vcIeXJ87G1ejwfOZeIMaukgVtMh3UFLPZhnx@hs2ctjz/RPq/7eqQfz5zNgUkdVtVSbnvvRAlX9ag@JO8/b/KcHSxvj4E9bW87neUSZ9V26WHB6@Hs0I019wuB4G@YReReWf3Ct8k9igWEpxkRibAZtsilPKCtMBCvhVHA8Zqh/vYC3otn2nbUQ9BVGBUaZJV1QqpSE6TRVS/QzuEoqegZ7CewslVymqmYU9tVr5S7QQoKmT6HPZkJXBsHC6BpxA9ZZsUb8LIjo2G/F3vj3WHAEcJgmjqzZte7G4wsWoZ/jYLRgtbqmKnCYUB6EYlZw3AU/uqEcGhVwKuJiwkOWlYrTUEC0GcrVTRlzFX7IYzyLUpS5BQH8K5IckxN7h@czOafj38p4zWYRLJDmNwWxH3T5/2O@hpwhgyIgBDj9lb2XToF@mFIie48GNI7p1DdbT7oU/pbGM@qwMDsjN0IXjhFyDr3XBdaU1HCdgElJO/RqSdlrqiwbr1cqzFDQ89zEYSbyRSmVtIp7BxUDhoBSIFx9Dfa3xPoM82V5imhdsKgg29xG0AlZlbr8QAup9iCbjU427kt2MS8wheW5leVMjsLmEH8mm704GfW2c6hIKv/6aHIuTvzbnGfVnGCRtOE/CuUkDdp29/aEdis@hqODrd6XEr7mSxW7456eQAmmpx4C9wL42zyaSXfrQFXVnq6mur@LgLaSXkf0iYKgOPGPvdHjimF1gVXcHyLcJdtTH5do6XNBPXOvos/t7h5wtg5P1IxF9qs1DwjI2vUL7PZ5wjRdZGg2dXtT2G2Nmvv0adiZS@gI5faTQDqVVVV1ls6glbgDmeoS4Z782QuKGKHnnnptKkgXV3GakvO5qo3GIKWoqvcAYxobMG2pnQ1gjs9Zs/wFzwpnY@0OBt79ZUJzJEbVKyg24gg7oNYQl8m4NZbUI4lRQdvgxGRRyVnL7HoVn6ft7fMHJxrd6HuNWjHHVRpwT30j@R4aOoftIPLycURU/ttB4tUjSdA4soPE2SNFUXNTm8a2yf1qdbrRAaIjw@u6QgW05QzsIW84hzvs05We6nr43CKsm3nDoHc/3kuYJsI2Ydp2z8@9e6eLPNweFNVkaeYge0z065m0mkSb8bOSpztKgi0TpK/Qq7V5QtA4D2uJJqc2DiBsXeyloOe@zr0mBwP5QVwtZQdZbXZ5eJCMmfg7lraGUyQcBX8y2nh7Hce8nPg/UaNXCR0BLVJDXYCMpHWLDomptjSvZ@DuTUk0qKuRd77fOhjPNAttHtRsJYoylu3gbN9DNRJbTSkCPNYbz9u6eI@P6Mmz/91DpU0FamJz13uHXTbphjSxPd71fuF/I/30vvpFc1hxOhqejn51YDvnteNsquPAcgxI7tq29XupANBnMi@F5217UrvX2NWDGNtUzJ9bzYKqgdYbvsaytKFX2FY/7qheQfWR59qUtVBiyWOC5xdvXHp2q9bDvFsUK5eDfc8fjjz1U1CXgGlS1StzrYtj84axBlEsKBj6LcJt/8bkNwySqpp72jRmGGhqOsQsOvcpRqKgkGFaSrCBicE1nQ047pJlFV1Ntl9SavtJWH039c6GimfzbOUuBXd0ZJ/upnqwOaBfEMY/DmmHzUUuDn@MA7CMtozk/vFf)

Mistakes were made, but this will now work (sorry)

Comment: @downvoter why?

Comment: [diddly darn croaked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233234/78850)