# Lexicographically self-comparing code

Tags: code-golf, quine

This is a [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) challenge related to [Write the shortest self-identifying program (a quine variant)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11370/84844)

Write a function or a full program that compares lexicographically its source code and input, that is, output three distinct values of your choice telling if `input` / `source code` is *Bigger*, *Equal* or *Less* than `source code` / `input`.

## Specifications

> A [Lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order?wprov=sfla1) is a *generalization of the alphabetical order of dictionaries to sequences of elements of an ordered set [Wikipedia].*

In short it works just like dictionaries:
To determine if string *A* is greater than a string *B*

- we compare the order of each first character (from the left).
  The string with bigger order element is greater.
- If first character of each are equal we compare the second and so on.
- If one string ends then that string is smaller.
- If *A = B* they are equal.

The ordered set is the natural character encoding of the language you choose and your submission has to work correctly with it.
For example UTF or ASCII.

## Examples

We use *Less, Eq and Greater* as output and ASCII as alphabet for clarity and simplicity.

source: "A"
input : "B"
output : Greater (input <=> source)

source: "a_X"
input : "A_x"
output : Greater (source <=> input)

source: "A,X"
input : "A,x"
output : Less (source <=> input)

source: "#!*"
input : " "
output : Greater (source <=> input)

source: "x!y"
input : "x!y"
output : Eq (source <=> input)

## Rules

- Standard [quine](/questions/tagged/quine) rules apply and specifically reading your own source code is not allowed.
- 0-length answers are disallowed.
- input: a sequence of characters in any convenient format (string, list or array of characters, codepoints).
  You can handle empty input but it is not required.
- output:
  Three distinct values of your choice meaning less equal and greater.
  You are free to choose to tell if input is <=> than source or if source is <=> than input, just be consistent and specify it.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), all usual rules apply.

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24665/84844)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>92</s> 90 bytes

```
'->T;f=\\(a,b=paste(sQuote(T),T))(a>=b)+(a>b)' ->T;f=\(a,b=paste(sQuote(T),T))(a>=b)+(a>b)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMFN68y8sszizKScVI3gymK94tSSnPzkRCAvObEkNT2_qFLBVkHJxzne0cdHSUcBIgcSclbS1FxaWpKma3EzSl3XLsQ6zTYmRiNRJ8m2ILG4JFWjOLA0H0iFaOqEaGpqJNrZJmlqA6kkTXUFqGpiFENteJGmoZSYlKykyQVkkGcbUaqTchKBiObWIFkAZqorqYNFlKD-XbAAQgMA)

Outputs `2` if the input is greater than the code, `1` if they're equal and `0` otherwise.

Simple modification of [@Dominic van Essen's `R` quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/209032/55372).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>32</s>  22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-10 thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334)! (Using `M` (-8) and using a full program (-2)).

```
“Ṿ;,ɠØJiⱮⱮM”Ṿ;,ɠØJiⱮⱮM
```

Expects the code using characters from the [code-page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) from STDIN and prints `2` if equal to the code, `0` if less, or `1` if more.

* without the deprecated, but supported, alternative characters of `ụ` and `ṿ`, or the newline alternative to `¶`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO/dZ65xccHiGV@ajjeuAyPdRw1xMQVLUAgA)**

#### How?

```
“Ṿ;,ɠØJiⱮⱮM”Ṿ;,ɠØJiⱮⱮM - Main Link: no arguments
“Ṿ;,ɠØJiⱮⱮM”           - "Ṿ;,ɠØJiⱮⱮM"
            Ṿ          - unevaluate -> "“Ṿ;$,⁸ØJiⱮⱮṢƑ+EƊ”"
             ;         - concatenate -> the source code = "“Ṿ;,ɠØJiⱮⱮM”Ṿ;,ɠØJiⱮⱮM"
               ɠ       - read a line from STDIN = I
              ,        - pair -> [source, I]
                ØJ     - Jelly's code-page
                  iⱮⱮ  - index of each character in each of [source, I]
                     M - maximal, 1-indexed, indices:
                                            source < I -> [2]
                                            source = I -> [1,2] 
                                            source > I -> [1]
```

Comment: [`ṢƑ+EƊ` -> `M`?](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO/dZq@g8atxxeIZX5qON64DI91HDXGzC/w@3a0b@/6@urk6aPqAGHVI1kaPHF2KTI/EAqPpRw0wwOReLfZ7keMybsCYA)

Comment: ...come to think of it, if newlines aren't in the input alphabet, [a full program taking input from STDIN is 2 shorter](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5yHO/dZ65xccHiGV@ajjeuAyPdRw1xMQVLUAgA)

Comment: Very nice, will update later!

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 31 bytes

```
f=(a)->if(a<s=Str("f="f),2,s<a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboW-9NsNRI1de0y0zQSbYptg0uKNJTSbJXSNHWMdIptEjUhqm6-TiwoyKnUSFTQtVMoKMrMKwEylUAcJQWgRk1NHYVopcSkZCUdBSUQxjQ0BigWgzA2KScRiIhSSowiqBpH4gyy0cWjKBbqZVgAAQA)

Outputs `1` if the input is greater than the code, `0` if they're equal and `2` otherwise.

---

### [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), cheating, 28 bytes

```
(a)->if(a<s=Str(self),2,s<a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWezQSNXXtMtM0Em2KbYNLijSKU3PSNHWMdIptEjUhSm5eSiwoyKnUSFTQtVMoKMrMKwEylUAcJQWgPk1NHYVopcSkZCUdBSUQxmdiUk4iEBFSRUAeLO1IULuNLi75WKjPFiyA0AA)

Comment: These are both cheating IMO. Our [definition of "proper quine"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12358) requires "data that encodes both itself, and something else", which these don't have. (Not declaring this is definitely breaking the rules, but just my opinion)

Comment: @pxeger By that definition, the `self` one is indeed cheating. But in `f=(a)->if(a<s=Str("f="f),2,s<a)`, the string `"f="` encodes both itself and the `f=` at the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), <s>28</s> 26 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"34çì·‚Ð{QsË+"34çì·‚Ð{QsË+
```

-2 bytes by switching to the legacy version of 05AB1E, where double on string works

Outputs `0` if the source code is smaller; `1` if the input is smaller; and `2` if both are equal.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fydjk8PLDaw5tf9Qw6/CE6sDiw93a2MSIVwkA) or [verify a few example test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3lfyVjk8PLD685tP1Rw6zDE6oDiw93a2MT@69DtFIuxaTUtPyiVK7EtJLUIgA).

**Explanation:**

It's based on this base quine: [`"34çì·"34çì·`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fydjk8PLDaw5thzP@/wcA).

```python
"34çì·‚Ð{QsË+"  # Push string "34çì·‚Ð{QsË+"
 34ç            # Push 34, converted to a character: '"'
    ì           # Prepend it to the string: '"34çì·‚Ð{QsË+'
     ·          # Double it: '"34çì·‚Ð{QsË+"34çì·‚Ð{QsË+'
      ‚         # Pair it with the (implicit) input
       Ð        # Triplicate it
        {       # (Lexicographically) sort the pair
         Q      # Check if the top two pairs are the same
          s     # Swap to get the remaining pair
           Ë    # Check if both values are the same
            +   # Add the two checks together
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 85 bytes

```ruby
->a{z,m,w='->a{z,m,w=',',',';a<=>[z,z,m,m,m,w,w]*39.chr}';a<=>[z,z,m,m,m,w,w]*39.chr}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvxfaGtj4@rnoldcUpRZ8F/XLrG6SidXp9xWHYmpA4bWiTa2dtFVOiBBECzXKY/VMrbUS84oqsUr@R9oPleabWpZYo5CIVeBQlo01PAc9VgwtzAWWTRPPfY/AA)

#### Explanation:

Not very golfy, I know.

I could take the answer to the linked question and replace '==' with '<=>' for 29 bytes, but I wanted to try something different, and opted not to use `eval`.

There is a lot of room for improvement, but I like the way it turned out.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 42 bytes

```hs
compare$s++show s;s="compare$s++show s;s="
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPzk/tyCxKFWlWFu7OCO/XKHYuthWCavg/9zEzDwFW4WUfC6FgqLMvBIFFYU0rEpjcIgqoWhE4SWh8FKU/ucBLbMF8lOLEpNLVECG6GlgmKoJclcu0Sr/JaflJKYX/9dNLigAAA)

*compare* program Vs input.

Outputs *Ord* value :
EQ equal
GT program > input
LT otherwise

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 23 bytes

```javascript
f=s=>s<(F='f='+f)?0:F<s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxBDsIgFET3PQW7D6lC41JL3fUcJQgVg2AK6cp4daQ2aRrcTebNm4eYRZCTecWj8zeVpHchIpkj4mhImgfehRb3HDSHWpNrc@7bkAYaJ/PE5FIxtio679UsLF7c3O9ztUy8VdT68ddRq9wY7xmVpFxDCwekVylYI9XeZ6d3Q0jxAnwz/lC3oRo@kHH6Ag)

Outputs `0` if input less than source, `false` for equal, and `true` for greater than.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `D`, 14 bytes

```
`I~>∇≥+`I~>∇≥+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJEIiwiIiwiYEl+PuKIh+KJpStgSX4+4oiH4omlKyIsIiIsImBJfj7iiIfiiaUrYEl+PuKIh+KJpSsiXQ==)

prints `0` for smaller, `1` for equals and `2` for greater

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>74</s> 49 bytes

```ruby
p [*$<]*''<=><<'2'*2+?2
p [*$<]*''<=><<'2'*2+?2
2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhWkvFJlZLXd3G1s7GRt1IXctI296IC5e4ERlaAA)

<s>Note trailing newline</s>

Adapted from the typical Ruby quine. Outputs `0` if input is the same as source, and `1` or `-1` if it is different. Thanks to Jo King for suggesting the use of `[*$<]*''` to capture input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 70 bytes

```julia
(q=:(show((ARGS[] > (Q = "(q=:($(q)))|>eval")) - (ARGS[] < Q))))|>eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X6PQ1kqjOCO/XEPDMcg9ODpWwU5BI1DBVkEJLKOiUaipqVljl1qWmKOkqamgqwBTZqMQqAmX@k8tgwA)

takes input as a single command line argument, and prints `0` for *Equal*, `1` for *Greater* and `-1` for *Less*

Based on the following quine, which is explained in this [answer by Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92455/98541) (adapted for Julia 1.0):
`(q=:(print("(q=:($(q)))|>eval")))|>eval` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X6PQ1kqjoCgzr0RDCcxW0SjU1NSssUstS8xRgrP@//8PAA)

Sadly, all the spaces are neccessary, since the code is stored as an AST, and converting it to a string will put all the spaces back. Also, defining a function or using a macro don't work because of the lengthy comments that are automatically added in the AST